# Time for some more swag!

Tags: discussion, fun, time, swag, 10th-anniversary

> **UPDATE:** I just sent out emails to collect addresses from the lucky users getting these watches — be on the lookout for those, **and try to fill it in the next two weeks**! :)

On occasion of [our anniversary celebrations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival), we offered some [cheese boards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316515/208518) a while back. If you were late for that, though, no sweat! You’re just in time for another limited edition super special swag contest!

This is the bit where you go **“[It’s *about time*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6BlVRdE6BU), isn’t it?”** To which I’ll reply with “well... yes, it *is* about time! How d’you guess?!?”

So, if you want one of these with our logo on it:

[image]

...then all you need to do is something in which *time* is the centerpiece! As happened last time around, puns are encouraged, obviously.

You can:

- Build a time-machine (ok, it doesn’t *need* to be functional).
- Write a song or a poem about time (hopefully, something a bit more cheerful than [what Pink Floyd did](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwYX52BP2Sk)).
- List a few things you'd drop into [a time capsule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_capsule) — either to be used as they usually are, or... to be sent to the past with your time-machine?
- Write the story of a life-*time*.

...or anything else you can find the *time* to do... in *time* before the deadline. The top 25 entries, as calculated by net upvotes received (not aggregate score, down-voting won't help you win!) will receive this timely package. Whatever it is, you have to be able to submit it as an answer to this question. **Links to videos *are* accepted**, however they must be of your own creation and the video must remain available. If either stops being true, your submission will be removed. **Also, any code or work of art produced must *also* be of your own creation.**

So, as with the previous context, any format you can think of is allowed: text, images, crayons on newspaper, LEGO, popsicle sticks — as long as you make it temporal... or I guess intemporal or timeless stuff are also accepted...? Anyway, you get the gist!

#### The Rules

1. You can post as many entries as you want *in good faith* as long as they are in line with our [terms of service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), [acceptable use policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) and [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). This is also a reminder that all user-contributed content falls under our [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
2. Contest is open from 2018-11-27 to 2018-12-27, final entry must be received at or prior to 23:59:59 UTC on the last day. Contest will then be locked for historical reference.
3. Employees are eligible.
4. You must be a user in good standing on Meta Stack Exchange during the entirety of the contest, or your entry may be disqualified. Let's have some good, clean fun.
5. Winners will be notified via email within 10 days of the contest closing. As we will be ordering these based on demand (they're not cheap!), you'll need to allow approximately 30 days for delivery. You'll need to provide us your shipping information privately, in accordance with our [privacy policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).
6. If you win but don't care for watches, we'll give you a selection of other items of approximate value. We want you to enjoy the prize.
7. Void where contests are prohibited.

***Get to it! Time is of the essence!***

Comment: *Phew* - posted just in time!

Comment: *entry to be completed in 6-8 weeks*

Comment: *You must be a user in good standing on Meta Stack Exchange during the entirety of the contest* ... I'll let my socks do the nasty stuff then ...

Comment: @rene You could build a time machine out of socks if you _really_ wanted to.

Comment: I don't know if i have time for this...

Comment: @TimPost Requesting a name change to Time Post.

Comment: Umm... *watch* your comments, y'all!

Comment: All these puns make me wanna clock someone

Comment: Can anyone do something with [Jon Skeet's most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333)?

Comment: Time to get to work!

Comment: I don't know why this was not posted yet: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you think you can read this thread without coming across time puns, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @TimPost It went up just a shog past 9...

Comment: *Watch* your language, kiddies!

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/  time's almost up

Comment: @Chair I thought for sure that link was going to be a reference to that Abba post.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405783/why-does-man-print-gimme-gimme-gimme-at-0030

Comment: If someone has made several nice related things during the past months, could they still post their work even though the actual thing was created before the contest? Should that be declared then?

Comment: @TimPost by the way, do you have time to make a progress on [HNQ matters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/165773)?

Comment: I find these contests very nice. However, the answers shoulds be displayed ramdonly, otherwise you are privileging those who got here first and those who have already received lots of votes, since I dont think everybody would check all pages to see what was sent...=(

Comment: [No Time Toulouse!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4anNb2jS4Q)

Comment: Hey, no dissing Pink Floyd songs - that's going to be my funeral tune :)

Comment: I really don't have the time for this.

Comment: You can sort answers by activity or post date too, @carla. Not _random_, but better than the most upvoted ones being always at the top.

Comment: Clarified the post to explicitly call out for original stuff, @Mari-LouA; thought it was clear enough, but I guess making it outright explicit doesn't hurt :)

Comment: The hours on the "swag" go 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6... That's a weird watch!

Comment: _Watch_ this space!

Comment: Does the [Conway Game of Life digital clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111932/64412) qualify? It has been made quite some time ago, but still...

Comment: If it's your creation, @dim it should be fine — I'm sure you can find the _time_ to deliver it in a way that makes it obvious it was not created for the purpose of this contest... or was it? :o

Comment: So... Is the cheesy swag delayed or cancelled? or continued?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, @BlackThunder — the cheese contest had a deadline, which is up; I've since updated it to let everyone know that the address collection emails have gone out. Am I missing your point?

Comment: OK. I understood. Basically, I thought that you were not sending cheese swags.

Comment: I've given SO enough of my time already thank you 

Comment: Well not doing that again, built my Tardis drove/piloted it and saw I didn't get the watch. pffft :)

Comment: Oh no! Seems like I came a little bit too late to be placed on the first page! I could really need a clock... but where could I get one? Anyways... just if you are interested in a short youtube DIY instruction for building your own 100% functioning TIME MACHINE, be sure to check out my post at the very last page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319323/377193. Just saying... ;-)

Comment: Is [this kind of thing](//worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6941/16336) permitted? It seems highly dubious to me.

Comment: I'm expecting that this question will acquire an answer that was posted four years before the question, like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10508/4918 .

Comment: @PeterTaylor Due to the response we'll very likely be creating more winning slots and a quick glance at the entries shows me that anything that wasn't really done with any care or good faith got downvoted pretty uniformly, so I don't see any _immediate_ problem, but we will consider it when we do the next one like this. The auto-protect issue combined with it being kinda hard to get an answer noticed after the first ~20 does leave folks looking for some legit way of getting more attention to their answer without being spammy. No harm this time, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - So which answer is getting the bounty!? I saw earlier bounties that include a link to boost them a little. By the way, I hope high-effort answers get a chance here - I'm planning on submitting mine today or tomorrow.

Comment: @Kobi [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319267/152859). The author probably spent lots of time thinking how to write it properly, and it's good, hence deserves some reward IMO. I plan to start several bounties, though thinking about it, each must be more rep so it won't be very fair. As for new answer having a chance to get the prize, I don't think it's feasible at this point, but who knows, it might give you some rep if not a watch. :)

Comment: Without promoting my game too aggressively - It's a good idea to [sort the answers by recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag?answertab=active#tab-top) and review some of the latest. Thanks!

Comment: Dec 27 here: Time _'s up_ for some more swag!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh it's just about _closing time_.

Comment: Tick! Tock!  Time up yet?!?

Comment: I guess we'll get emails about our watches in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @JNat curious to know, who are the winners?

Comment: @ZachSaucier My package turned up after exactly 8 weeks, so, yes.  And that was international.

Comment: @JNat I got my watch :) and the *`Time`* is right,

Comment: Watch is really cute, better then even the image above.

Answer (score 253):

Here's a clock that will never overflow, the **Stack Overflow Binary Clock™**:

[image: Stack Overflow Clock]

This is basically a [binary clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_clock) based  on the Stack Overflow logo. This clock is ideal for all programmers, because  (a) we speak binary and (b) it uses the Stack Overflow logo.

I wrote the code myself using RxJS, since reactive programming is hot nowadays. The snippet can be found below:

```js
const { from, interval } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const extract = {
  hour: date => date.format('HH'),
  minute: date => date.format('mm'),
  second: date => date.format('ss')
};

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    map(_ => moment()),
    switchMap(getDigits),
    switchMap(getDigit),
    map(getBinary),
    switchMap(getBinaryDigits))
  .subscribe(showBar);


function getDigits(date) {
  return from(Object.entries(extract)).pipe(
    map(([type, digits]) => ({type, value: digits(date)}))
  );
}

function getDigit({type, value}) {
  return from(value.split('')).pipe(
    map((digit, index) => ({type, index, digit}))
  );
}

function getBinary({type, index, digit}) {
  const binary = parseInt(digit).toString(2);
  return {type, index, binary: '0000'.substr(binary.length) + binary};
}

function getBinaryDigits({type, index, binary}) {
  return from(binary.split('')).pipe(
    map((digit, binaryIndex) => ({type, index, digit, binaryIndex}))
  );
}

function showBar({type, index, binaryIndex, digit}) {
  const classList = document
    .getElementById(type)
    .querySelectorAll('.stack')
    .item(index)
    .querySelectorAll('.bar')
    .item(binaryIndex)
    .classList;
  digit == '0' ? classList.remove('active') : classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.part {
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.part > h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.stack {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.stack::after {
  content: '';
  border: solid 4px #BCBBBB;
  border-top: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.stack > .bar {
  background-color: #BCBBBB;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  height: 4px;
}
.stack > .bar.active {
  background-color: #F48023;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <div class="part" id="hour">
    <h1>Hour</h1>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="part" id="minute">
    <h1>Minute</h1>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="part" id="second">
    <h1>Second</h1>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="stack">
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
      <li class="bar"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I originally wrote this on Codepen, where I used SCSS in stead of regular CSS. If you're interested in that stuff, you can find it [here](https://codepen.io/g00glen00b/pen/ZmqYPx).

<sub>Disclaimer: I cannot be held responsible for any lost time caused by watching the stacks slowly fill up.</sub>

Comment: WOW, that's awsome!
Though to much effort to read.

Comment: Someone told me he thought it was weird that a binary clock converts the individual decimal digits to binary, so that's why I made a full binary version as well, which can be found [here](https://codepen.io/g00glen00b/pen/NEOdvo).

Comment: @g00glen00b This is so great! I think that the form of the clock in your post, i.e. individual decimal digits, it's called **Binary coded decimal mode** and it's how the binary clock usually looks like. The main reason is that it's much easier to convert smaller amount of bits. For the first hour digit, you need just 2 bits, for the first digits of minutes and seconds 3 bits and for all second digits 4 bits. So you can even improve it by removing unnecessary bits.

Comment: You may want to add the bases in there too `Hour<sub>24</sub>`. cool display though.

Comment: Also, it'd be **really** cool to have a slightly more malicious clock, one that each segment with just one bit too few to display the full range, so it did overflow. And, then an indicator that it was in overflow like a background change for that segment of the clock. Then we could watch our clock overflow on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Rotated version](https://codepen.io/a-stone-arachnid/pen/yQRroV)

Comment: ... and can we have this implemented as a wind-up mechanical watch, please.  (Minor feature request.)

Comment: Stack Overflow logo has 5 elements, your design has 4, it isn't Stack Overflow logo.

Comment: @raviraja Good thing I never said it is the Stack Overflow logo. With some imagination you could even argue that this clock has one bar less because the 5th bar in the logo causes the overflow, and this clock never overflows!

Comment: @astonearachnid Nice! I was thinking about rotating them myself, but then I thought it would make it more difficult to read so I discarded that idea, but it looks like I was wrong, it's readable and looks great.

Comment: LOL! I can't understand how to read the time. It will be more better if you explain that how read the time.

Comment: @BlackThunder The Wikipedia article I linked does explain that. Each "stack" is one digit, and each bar represents a bit, starting from the top. That means that in the screenshot, the stacks are 0001, 0000, 0010, 0111, 0001, 0100. In decimals, that's equal to 1, 0, 2, 7, 1, 4 or 10:27:14. Also be aware  that the clock uses 24h-format.

Comment: This clock should be included in the design of the site, this would finally be something useful to put in the left sidebar!

Comment: This. This is epic.

Comment: The original is fabulous & so is @astonearachnid's yet when I saw the original I thought, why not *show* the stacks overlflow--[with leftward logos](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JexbRv)?

Comment: @samcarter I made a userscript to put the clock in the sidebar: https://stackapps.com/q/8137/54539

Comment: @astonearachnid Oh wow! This is awesome! You finally gave me a reason not to hide the sidebar!

Comment: Someone has too much time on their hands. Nice job!

Comment: It would be even better if the stack toppled over into the next one on overflow!

Comment: It won't overflow in 2038, even? Or in 100000000?

Answer (score 162):

[image: Evan-Amos [CC0], from Wikimedia Commons]

[image]

Comment: This is SO hilarious!

Comment: Migrate to [Cooking.se].

Comment: 'Tis the season!

Comment: Clarification for non-native speakers (including me) or non-cooking aficionados: the herb in the picture is Thyme, which is pronounced similarly to 'time'.

Comment: @Glorfindel don't spoil the joke :( Isn't there a spoiler alert available for comments?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, to like and/or upvote this post, readers have to understand the point first. I'm sure that, at least in my case, I would never even recognize the herb on the picture... So without the spoiler in the comment, I guess this post would lose many potential upvotes.

Comment: this lacks parsley, sage and rosemary ... to complete the bouquet. very nice idea

Comment: @PatrickArtner : for the millenials, are we talking about Simon & Timefunkel ?^^

Comment: @OldPadawan They got a nice interpretation of it, yes Scarborough Fair is a bit older though.

Comment: @OldPadawan Pretty sure that song has been around for much more _time_ than Simon and Garfunkel's version.

Comment: @reirab : probably, but *ti i i i me is on my siiiiide..." :D

Comment: 'Tis the _seasoning_!

Comment: @Mari-LouA well, Glorfindel was a lifesaver, because I thought the picture was of marijuana (and obviously was confused about how that has anything to do with time). xD xD

Comment: @IshitaSinha #1 There's a motto that says never reveal a magician's trick. Part of the fun is knowing that not everybody gets it. Today with [Google image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZit2g6GGuOSWmxjEoEC3xWuzFakDZ9xW1mXxZhv_1WHJfKdy5cmv7lTU6kVsW3wq3nWUGtZQV5XTdjT6YE0y9rx1PNpdR3zLvrHNCIw6UOcSjRbWxI5gRZpQZYqbAv8oPQbPN-Xwr71KvWj5EY5xWWympuvVgsIh1MzaUbaXEfXEsb7nme_1GkuGrZP07c8f0D1dJnVaaA_1w-i_19t74gh2KiGW1z0jqMqAFhVepI9egJwhJqeUO_1TutA1U3hUzqhIM8W-UoZ33x9Kap8X7ibn_1UC0lcmFzycWCgapHONSSCahMKoXusvn_1jf-ML5BO5pwYhBzTG3iM3DUsnY8qRVxDab1CsAZZEQ&hl=en-IT)

Comment: #2 (really long url!) it's easy enough to find out the name of this plant/herb.

Comment: does anyone else remember ["parsely, sage, rosematry and osborne"](https://www.edgestudio.com/blogs/remembering-stan-freberg-%E2%80%9Care-we-going-go-out-that%E2%80%9D)?

Answer (score 156):

Behold: stackoverflow's famous feature countdown clock!

[image: feature countdown]

Comment: I like how you think.

Comment: That's a really funny idea! It's remarkable, comparing your success and [my efforts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319323/377193), how different success can be. Especially with your humor, it's sometimes the "smaller" things that are more engaging, than larger projects.

Answer (score 93):

I'm resurrecting the creation I made quite some *time* ago for an answer to a [PPCG post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88783/build-a-digital-clock-in-conways-game-of-life/111932#111932), as it seems quite a good fit to this celebration.

It is a digital clock design made on Conway's Game of Life (you know, with gliders and stuff).

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

You can run the simulation and get the details of the design from [here](https://copy.sh/life/?gist=f3413564b1fa9c69f2bad4b0400b8090&step=512). Take the *time* to *watch* this, it's mesmerizing.

Now, I'll tell you the big secret about it: I actually built a time machine in 2017. I used it to jump one year and a half later, and saw this post. I thought: "Boy, do I want this watch.", so I went back in 2017 and made the post on PPCG so that I could refer to it when this celebration starts.

And the best part about it: The digital clock you're seeing *is actually a part of the time machine*. The whole machine is entirely built with Game of Life, and this is the time metering component. Unfortunately, I can't disclose the whole time machine design here, the world is not ready for that (besides, the license of the GoL-emulated flux capacitor is incompatible with the CC-BY-SA license).

Comment: Very nice, but is this your own doing? If not I'm afraid just taking someone else work isn't really fair.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, of course it is. This answer on PPCG was originally made by me, and I spent quite some *time* to design it, originally. What makes you think it's not? I'm.... I'm actually offended. Damn... Usually, only my wife manages to do that. Are you my wife?

Comment: rofl... well I was too lazy to click the link and too irritated with crappy answers here. Kudos, and well done! (And sure, I'm your wife! Now I'm mad at you for not being able to tell that before! ;))

Answer (score 80):

Perhaps it would be prudent at the end of this, the Stack Overflow Decade, to look back into the mists of time to see what was seen by those who came before.

And so, I give you:

### A Visual Retrospective

With *great* thanks to [archive.org](http://archive.org).

Now, in the time before time, when the great barren chaos ocean of the Internet heaved up HTTP Response 302 - [http://www.mozquito.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20000303134737/http://www.mozquito.org:80/). stackoverflow.com began the Two Thousand Aughts as a found redirect ([capture 2000/03/01](https://web.archive.org/web/20000301035207/http://stackoverflow.com)).

Then, sometime in 2004 (it appears), the domain went to a speculator and remained for sale until 2008 rolled around and

### A Miracle Occurred

A cryptic message and the clock nearly began to tick. ([capture 2008/07/03](https://web.archive.org/web/20080703183923/http://stackoverflow.com))▼

[image: I think you should be more explicit here in step two.]

A couple of months later and *pop*, the first SO logo and site. Unfortunately, archive.org is missing the CSS and a majority of images from that time. ([capture 2008/09/15](https://web.archive.org/web/20080915103343/http://stackoverflow.com))▼

[image: SO Logo 2008/09/15]

We finally get a good shot in 2009. ([capture 2009/07/02](https://web.archive.org/web/20090702101304/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2009 SO Screenshot]

Careers appears in 2010. ([capture 2010-07-30](https://web.archive.org/web/20100730054504/http://www.stackoverflow.com:80/))▼

[image: 2010 SO Screenshot]

February 26, 2011 looks like some network connectivity issues were to be expected. Hiding behind that yellow banner is a Stack Exchange link. ([capture 2011-02-26](https://web.archive.org/web/20110226232108/http://stackoverflow.com))▼

[image: 2011 SO Screenshot]

Hello Stack Exchange, chat, meta and Server Fault. ([capture 2011-07-18](https://web.archive.org/web/20110718065316/http://stackoverflow.com))▼

[image: 2011, July SO Screenshot]

Usage of the Community Bulletin: 2012 Community Moderator Election was ending soon. ([capture 2012-06-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615000504/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2012 SO Screenshot]

In very tangentially referencing [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) form, careers 2.0 appears later in 2012.
More version = More better. ([capture 2012-11-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115001439/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2012, November SO Screenshot]

First appearance of the site introduction banner along with a sign up link on the menu bar. Chat, meta, about and faq disappear from the menu bar. ([capture 2013-06-14](https://web.archive.org/web/20130614120726/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2013 SO Screenshot]

At last: my favorite capture. The stylish, black menu bar and ombre Stack Exchange logo appears. We find tour and help appear in the menu bar as well. However the best aspect is the new **Hot Network Questions** section where someone on Stack Overflow has asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781436/why-is-this-private-member-accessible - a double entendre which must be seen in context to be believed. ([capture 2014-02-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215040636/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2014 SO Screenshot]

In early 2015 our split Question/Tags/Users/Badges button section joined the Ask Question button in aligning right. careers 2.0 finally tried to gain some cache by rebranding using the Stack Overflow name.

Edit: And, as mentioned by Armatus in the comments, note the Stack Overflow logo reduction of size and also angle of stack elements - with the highest element going to something like 55° from 80°. As a result of that investigation, I noticed that the sprite sheet for the site changed: [old](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215085129im_/http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=6) vs [new](https://web.archive.org/web/20150131230425im_/http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68). ([capture 2015-02-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20150201030204/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2015, February SO Screenshot]

[10,000,000](https://web.archive.org/web/20150831110313/https://stackoverflow.com/10m) questions! ([capture 2015-09-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20150901133800/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2015, September SO Screenshot]

Let the notifications commence! The Inbox and Recent Achivements icons arrive in the menu bar ([another sprite sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20151014084957im_/http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=d09c08f3cb07)). ([capture 2015-10-14](https://web.archive.org/web/20151014153925/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2015, October SO Screenshot]

stack overflow careers departs the menu bar to become a gray `Jobs` button. The `Unanswered` button departs. Consider that at this point we're quantifying that Stack Overflow is composed of over 4.7 million programmers. ([capture 2016-01-31](https://web.archive.org/web/20160131210702/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2016, February SO Screenshot]

The Developer Story + Documentation <sup>Beta</sup>. ([capture 2016-10-31](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031140122/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2016, October SO Screenshot]

Beginning in 2016 we were 4.7 million programmers. A year later we have grown to 6.6 million. ([capture 2017-02-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20170201004148/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2017, February SO Screenshot]

April Fools, 2017. Internet security continues to be a joke. The gray button bar is absorbed into a shaken up menu bar. Stack Exchange is conspicuously missing from the top. ([capture 2017-04-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20170401003515/http://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2017, April SO Screenshot]

So in February 2017 we were a community of 6.6 million programmers. By September, someone decided to loosen the definitions a bit and include visiting developers which tops us out at 50 million site users per month. This likely has something to do with courting business directly: "Stack Overflow Business Solutions: Looking to understand, engage, or hire developers?". Learn more why don't you!? Documentation<sup>Beta</sup> has gone and Jobs -> Developer Jobs. ([capture 2017-09-30](https://web.archive.org/web/20170930144527/https://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2017, September SO Screenshot]

We've captured the second annual Developer's Survey here and entered the modern era. ([capture 2018-01-14](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114233922/https://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2018, January SO Screenshot]

Circa the beginning of this question, Stack Overflow Teams peeks it's head out with Slack integration. The top menu is de-cluttered by the addition of a side menu - I think this is configurable as mine is shown as a hamburger menu next to the Stack Overflow logo. ([capture 2018-11-27](https://web.archive.org/web/20181127123243/https://stackoverflow.com/))▼

[image: 2018, November 27 SO Screenshot]

(and more as I have time)

Comment: 200 million dollars of development later and we got ad box on the right and they moved from a cloud to a vertical list.

Comment: Ah dangit I was thinking of putting one of these together today. +1 to you.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Please don't ignore that some of that money must've gone into reducing that overflow by 16.7% judging by the logo.

Comment: StackOverflooooooow

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: I remember making those changes. Sometimes I'd sneak in subtle CSS changes hoping no one would notice. But Meta notices.. Meta sees everything. Good times.

Comment: @EvanCarroll ... and the Winter Bash system. Don't forget the Winter Bash system, please.

Answer (score 79):

It's [closing time.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGytDsqkQY8)

[image]

Comment: "This question belongs to another time era. Seriously, go out, hang out with younger people, evolve, and stop sounding like an grumpy elderly person."

Answer (score 65):

A time machine, you say? Well how convenient. I *just so happen* to have found one of those lying around this morning... and a sea unicorn, whose friend is missing somewhere in the depths of time! Sounds like a rescue mission is in order...

[image]

In he goes. It's not going to be an easy mission.

[image]

After much waiting...

and waiting...

and whirring and clunking and POP! One by one (this is a one-narwhal time machine, of course), they're back!

[image]

Oh dear. He doesn't look happy. I think the trip left him feeling a little... green.

[image]

Both back safely! No missing body parts, fortunately... we'll have to see about their memories later.

[image]

Reunited at last!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is that allowed under CC-by-SA? ;-)

Comment: Is that a squiddle?

Comment: Certainly would be, @Randal'Thor

Comment: @ErinB It's a narwhal and an octopus :)

Comment:  Squidge & Spike.

Comment: Blub blub, blub blub blub blub? Blub blub. Blub blub, blub!

Answer (score 55):

What about an ASCII-art Big Ben?

[image]

Or, more realistically...

```
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                  | 
                                                                                                                  |
                                                                                                                 |||
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                 /:\
                                                                                                                /:::\
                                                                                                            |  /:::::\   |
                                                                                                            | /:::::::\  |
                                                                                                           |l/:::::::::\ l
                                                                                                           |/:::::::::::\l
                                                                                                           MNMNMNMNMNMNMNM
                                                                                                           WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
                                                                                                           MWMWMWMWMWMWMWM
                                                                                                          | | | | | | | | |   
                                                                                                          | | | | | | | | |   
                                                                                                          MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMl
                                                                                                          //:::::::::::::\\
                                                                                                      |  //:::::::::::::::\\    |
                                                                                                      | //:::::::::::::::::\\   l
                                                                                                      l//:::::::::::::::::::\\  Hl
                                                                                                    | //:::::::::::::::::::::\\ HH
                                                                                                    |//:::::::::::::::::::::::\\WW
                                                                                                    H||..W..W..W..W..W..W..W..W.||
                                                                                                    H||...M..M..M..M..M..M..M..M| |
                                                                                                    H||...H..H..H..H..H..H..H..H|\|
                                                                                                    H||...H..H..H..H..H..H..H..H| |
                                                                                                    H||...WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW...||H\|
                                                                                                 ///H||...........____.........||\\\
                                                                                                ||||H||...     /   |    \     .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||...   /     |      \   .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||...  /      |       \  .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||... /       |        \ .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||...|    ----o         |.|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||... \                / .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||...   \            /   .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||...     \ ______ /     .|||||
                                                                                                ||||H||........................|||||
                                                                                                ||||||M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|||||
                                                                                                ||||||H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|H|||
                                                                                                 |||||............................||
                                                                                                 ||||._._._._._._._._._._._._._._._/
                                                                                                  |/.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  \\_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_//
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  \\_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_//
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                                                                  ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
 .                                                                                                \\_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_//
   ‘   ..                                                                                         ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
           .....                                                                                  |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
            . .............. ,                                                                    |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                 ....................  . ..     .                                                 ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                 ..,   ............................ .   .                                         |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                   - ........................................                                     |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                         .........................................                                ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                               .........................................                          |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                       .......................................                    |||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                              ......................................              ||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||
                                                    ........................................______|||.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|||
                                                           .............................../,,,,\III\ |.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.|.||_
                                                                   ....................../,,,,,,,, |IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\\_
                                                                          ............./,,,,,,,,,,,,,\-------------------------------------\
                                                                                 .....<,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\
                                                                                      . \,,,,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\
                                                                                          \,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\
                                                                                            \,,,,,/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\
                                                                                              \,,,|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\
                                                                                                \,/,,,,,,,,,,,,,_________________________________/
```

(You can probably tell that very little of that was rendered by my makeshift ASCII art creator)

Comment: Ooh, did you make this yourself?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Some of it. I have a pretty bad script which I made a couple of years back, so I first threw a big ben through that and then I modified it a bit. The clock, the shadow, and the periodic what-do-you-call-thems in the middle are manually done. I was thinking of adding the script here but the algorithm is sloppy as hell and the number of violations of PEP8 are embarrassing. Also, it's really slow, which makes it highly unsuitable for this competition :P

Comment: This is pretty, but what does it have to do with Stack Overflow/Exchange?

Comment: @SOLO Come on, ASCII art is fabulous! And half of that was made with my rudimentary image processing skills (though my modifications were probably cheating but meh).

Comment: @Chair actually the cheating was with the generation. Your modifications (to whatever degree they occurred) are the only part that isn't cheating. Check out this site for real ASCII art, https://asciiart.website/index.php?art=objects/clocks

Comment: @SOLO: Only [time will tell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time_will_tell#Phrase), but it used to be a [time-honoured](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time-honoured) tradition here: *[<kbd> elements are way too intrusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen haha, I'm _well_ aware of the `<kbd>` castles and other art. (I'm not as new as the date in my profile might suggest.) But those were memes born of meta, whereas this is an entry in a Stack Exchange anniversary contest that has no apparent connection to the company or any site. For what it's worth, I had the same complaint about several of the entries in the previous contest, the cheese-themed one, as well.

Comment: I object - that's not what Big Ben looks like. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJGQh.jpg) is what it looks like (as of this year, and until ~2021, it seems).

Comment: @E.P. Well... A pedant might point out that Big Ben is actually the bell inside the Elizabeth Tower. In other words, Big Ben looks like this: https://bit.ly/2PYyiqq

Comment: @TomWright Gaah I don't like URL shorteners. My school blocks them.

Comment: @Chair Sorry about that. SO mangled Wikipedia's URL format when I tried it unshortened. If it's any consolation, it's just a picture of a big metal bell.

Comment: @Chair Use this [direct to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben#/media/File:Big_Ben_-_geograph.org.uk_-_40182.jpg) link (it first goes to the host page, then flips to the image). But either way, Tom is (W)right ... Big Ben is the bell.

Answer (score 53):

It's time for chrono-ception!

[Chronos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronos) is the God of *time* in Greek Mythology in the pre-Socratic era. Since I am also in the pre-Socratic badge era, I thought I should pay my tribute to Chronos:

[image]

For, that I used this [ASCII art](https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/convert-images-to-ascii-art/) to get a picture of Chronos itself, and then measure the time needed for C++ to display that image in the browser with the standard [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) library, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2018/11/chronosgodascii.png", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

    std::cout << "Chronos needed to show you Chronos, was " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Chronos needed to show you Chronos, was 0.53636 seconds.

[image]

PS: For Linux, you would do `::system("xdg-open https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2018/11/chronosgod.png");`, but there is no portable open function...

Easter Egg: The Linux version uses a different Chronos this time!

Comment: Very interesting :)

Comment: Glad you liked it @Nikolas, I am only wondering if chose a good image for Chronos.. I am wondering whether he has an item or a pose that will distinguish him from the rest, or not. For example, Poseidon has the Trident, Zeus the Lighting, and so on...  ⚡

Comment: As far as I have seen, [Chronos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronos)' symbols are Harvesting Scythe and Zodiac Wheel. The second one might be relevant.

Comment: @Nikolas the Zodiac Wheel seems relevant indeed! I couldn't find any good image with it, but if I have time, I will search again in the weekend, thanks!

Comment: But I've found plenty with a scythe. :D

Comment: Indeed @Nikolas, but damn it, he looks like a modern Hades! I guess people will misinterpret him, if I put an image with a scythe.. ;)

Comment: @gsamaras really nice !

Comment: @Christos chrono-ception!!

Comment: Nice one @gsamaras

Comment: @gsamaras are you from Greece ? (I am btw)...

Comment: Gogo (`!golang`) `chrono-ception`; God of time dives into the `Matrix`!

Comment: ChristosLytras I hope he timed his dive though! @Aristos yes! My name is Yorgos and the surname Samaras, which might be the most common name and surname in Greece, I believe! ;)

Comment: Did somebody say pre-Socratic?

Comment: @anaximander is your image depicting one of the founders of Western Philosophy? The angle puzzles me. .

Comment: @gsamaras [It is indeed](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3wTKXhVs_mI/VW7PalyujvI/AAAAAAAADXE/e7P884bE9XY/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/Anaximander%2B%2BAnaximandros.jpg).

Comment: The picture says Anaximandros, for the non-Greek users. "*Anaximander* was a *pre-Socratic* Greek philosopher [..] learned the teachings of his master **Thales**. He succeeded Thales [..] Anaximenes and **Pythagoras** amongst his pupils.". Thanks for the lesson @anaximander, really cool! it's amazing how these names have survived and used till today, to give their name to companies and so on . . .

Comment: Anaximander was also the first philosopher (as far as records survive) to state that the Earth floated free in space, without being supported by anything. He also suggested that the Sun might actually be very large, and only looks small because it is very far away.

Comment: Amazing @anaximander! Imagine having a *time* machine( we are in a time post), where you could have Eratosthenes (first to calculate the circumference of the Earth (if Columbus knew about his results, he would never attempt to sail to India)) and Anaximander sit together and talk about planet Earth..

Comment: That's cool, eventually, it didn't took much chronos to show Chronos :)

Comment: And I upvoted your comment in no chronos at all @VasilisG.! ;)

Comment: @gsamaras you sure did! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Well thought. Good job

Comment: Thank you @AbelMelquiadesCallejo, I was thinking about chrono library, and this contest came just in time, so I thought of the chrono-ception! Glad you liked it!

Comment: That is one heck of an interesting thought process @gsamaras... really interesting...

Comment: Glad you liked it @Rai!

Comment: Keep it up @gsamaras!

Comment: I enjoyed more this time @MenelaosKotsollaris!

Comment: Well done Giorgos!I really enjoyed this.

Comment: That was the purpose @TsakiroglouFotis, you are welcome!

Answer (score 51):

I've been *watching* responses come in that use ASCII art and thought it was about *time* to up the stakes.

Here's an ASCII rendering of the swag, with a difference...

[image: Image of an ASCII art watch]

To see the difference, you'll need to paste [the whole thing](https://gist.github.com/tdwright/763b520d4ed62426aeed0179045a7a7b) into your favourite online Brainfuck interpreter ([this one will do](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/)).

<sub>I made [the tool that does this](http://tdwright.co.uk/phpplayground/BF/) many, many [years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20080101000000*/http://tdwright.co.uk/phpplayground/BF/). I was young. It uses PHP. Please don't judge!</sub>

Comment: ----[---->+<]>++.[------->+<]>.[->+++<]>.[--->+<]>----.----.--.--------.--[--->+<]>.

Comment: `[-]>[-]<>++++++++[<++++++++>-]<++++++++.>+++++[<+++++>-]<.>++++[<++++>-]<-..>+++[<+++>-]<.>+++++++++[<--------->-]<--------.>++++[<++++>-]<+.-.>++++++++[<++++++++>-]<++++.>+++[<--->-]<---.>++++++++[<-------->-]<--------.>++++++++[<++++++++>-]<++.>+++[<+++>-]<--.>+++[<+++>-]<.++.>+++[<--->-]<---.----.---.>+++++[<+++++>-]<-.>+++++++++[<--------->-]<--------.>+++++++[<+++++++>-]<++.>++++++[<++++++>-]<---.>++++[<---->-]<---.++.>+++[<+++>-]<-.++++.>+++[<+++>-]<--.>++++[<---->-]<-.>++++[<++++>-]<---.>+++[<--->-]<---.>++[<++>-]<++.+++.>+++[<+++>-]<-.>+++++++++[<--------->-]<-----`

Comment: Upvoted this, but would be interested in seeing ASCII art where the entire image isn't just a giant code comment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think you're mistaken. Brainfuck does not interpret any characters except for `+-<>[],.`. If you use a regex to remove all characters except those from the image, you get my comment above which has identical output to running the whole image, demonstrating equivalent functionality.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right that this just hides the BF code inside BF comment characters. The original point was to do a sort of ASCII stenography. It's hard to see on a big, hi-res image like the one I've used here, but the script will actually try to put the BF characters among similar looking comment characters, so they they're less obvious.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Never mind; I thought I saw a row of `]`s but it was actually `}`s...

Answer (score 48):

I didn't have time to write a proper answer, so I just made a timely list.

### [time](/questions/tagged/time) on Stack Exchange

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time): 21111 questions
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 1334 questions
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 453 questions
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/time): 442 questions
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/time): 438 questions
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time): 434 questions
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 331 questions
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 284 questions
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 280 questions
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 240 questions
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 195 questions
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 169 questions
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 154 questions
- [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 141 questions
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 133 questions
- [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 113 questions
- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/time/info): 93 questions
- [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 81 questions
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 80 questions
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 75 questions
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 63 questions each
- [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 54 questions
- [Stack Overflow en Espanol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) and [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 35 questions each
- [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 32 questions each
- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 30 questions
- [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 27 questions
- [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 23 questions
- [elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 13 questions
- [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 12 questions
- [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time): 7 questions

Time's up! Did I miss anyone?

Comment: I'm surprised there's not more entries in Astronomy

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd you will see that the number of questions grows with time

Comment: 57 questions in Space Exploration (more than Meta!): https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time

Comment: The fact that [cooking.se] doesn't have a [tag:thyme] is highly disappointing.

Comment: Music: Practice and Theory has some time signatures, and some ragtime.

Comment: On [cs.SE], we don't just talk about time, we [_analyse_](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity+or+runtime-analysis) it.

Comment: would be useful to show percentage of questions from each site!

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/search?q=time

Comment: @chicks https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time

Comment: 1155 more Qs ... at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime

Comment: 133 on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time

Comment: @dim Oops, missed that. Added.

Comment: I'm surprised that the [Music StackExchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags) doesn't have any `time` tags at all...

Answer (score 48):

## Clock Lobster!

*(with apologies/thanks to [The B-52's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofkzvM7Skxg))*

[image: lobster 3/4 view]

A punctual crustacean alternative to the usual [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), done up in Stack Exchange shades of blue!

[image: lobster top view]

There's even a [crochet pattern](http://karabouts.typepad.com/karabouts/2010/05/little-blue-lobster-free-pattern.html) to make your own!

[image: the internet loves kitties, right]

Just like StackExchange, it's fun for programmers and non-programmers alike ;)

Comment: You never expect these B-52's references, then bam!

Comment: Who's to blame?

Answer (score 43):

<sub>Disclaimer: all puns using the word 'time' below are intended</sub>

I'm not so much of a story teller, but I'd like to share something about the history of the swag for this contest: watches. Please take some time to read it.

- Watches have been around since the 16<sup>th</sup> century. At that time they were powered by a spring which had to be winded.
- In the 1950s, electric watches came out.
- In the 1960s, the quartz watch was invented, using a quartz crystal for very precise time measurement.
- The first digital watch, the Pulsar, was developed in the 1970s.
- In 2000, IBM showed a prototype of a watch running on Linux (now we're getting somewhere)...
- In 2013, the Pebble was released, the first smartwatch to reach a large audience.
- Other companies like Apple and Samsung followed soon. Smartwatches are becoming more and more like small mobile phones nowadays.
- And in 2018, we're using smartwatches to get rid of unwanted content on Stack Exchange, anyplace, anywhere, anytime.

Here's how that looks like:

[image]

<sub>(click to play on YouTube)</sub>

How does that work, you might ask? In a nutshell: [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) is a chatbot which scans (the API version of) the [realtime Stack Exchange feed](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) to check for new/edited posts. If they match certain patterns often used by spammers, it'll report the post in various places like [chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and our central platform [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/). Another server is monitoring that platform for new spam posts and sends a [rich push notification](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/) to an app on my iPhone. That app uses the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) to cast spam flags (the same avenue as the Stack Exchange mobile app) whenever I 'reply' to that notification that it is spam.

Together with Stack Exchange's SpamRam system and [automatic flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically), systems like this provide a dramatic decrease in visibility time of spam.

<sub>(sources: Wikipedia articles on ['History of watches'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_watches), ['Smartwatch'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartwatch); [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/))</sub>

<sub>(another disclaimer: of course I'm using this only for blatantly obvious spam. I'm totally aware of the problems with false spam flags.)</sub>

Comment: Flagged as spam: unsolicited advertising for Smoke Detector.

Comment: I still think that digital watches are a pretty neat idea.

Comment: Now, I know why you're always quick to flag. :P

Comment: So if you when the watch from this contest, I get the Apple watch then, right?

Answer (score 40):

I had to use a little javascript to initiate the time, but other than that it's pure CSS.

- Click "Run code snippet" to see it in action
- Click and hold the clock to activate the time-machine.

```js
let dt = new Date();
document.querySelector("#second_hand").setAttribute("style", 
  "animation-delay:"+(dt.getSeconds() * -1)+"s"
);
document.querySelector("#minute_hand").setAttribute("style", 
  "animation-delay:"+((dt.getMinutes() * 60 + dt.getSeconds()) * -1)+"s"
);
document.querySelector("#hour_hand").setAttribute("style", 
  "animation-delay:"+(((dt.getHours() > 12 ? dt.getHours() - 12 : dt.getHours()) * 3600 + dt.getMinutes() * 60 + dt.getSeconds()) * -1)+"s"
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#face {
  width: 94vh;
  height: 94vh;
  background: #2d2928;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#2d2928 0%, #2d2928 55%, #3b393a 55.5%, #3b393a 60%, #2d2928 60.5%, #2d2928 61%, #848389 61.5%, #848389 63%, #201e1f 63.5%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: perspective(80vw) rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50vh;
  transition: transform 1s;
  border: 3vh solid #e17f1a;
  counter-reset: hour;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 4vh;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform: rotateZ(4deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background: #ece8e7;
}

#hour_hand {
  height: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  animation: rotate infinite linear 43200s;
}

#minute_hand {
  height: 35%;
  top: 15%;
  animation: rotate infinite linear 3600s;
}

#second_hand {
  height: 40%;
  top: 10%;
  animation: rotate infinite linear 60s;
}

#water {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  top: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ece8e7;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

b {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: calc(50% - 12px);
  width: 24px;
  color: #e4e8e9;
  counter-increment: hour;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

b:before {
  content: counter(hour);
}

b:nth-child(1) {transform: rotateZ(30deg);}
b:nth-child(2) {transform: rotateZ(60deg);}
b:nth-child(3) {transform: rotateZ(90deg);}
b:nth-child(4) {transform: rotateZ(120deg);}
b:nth-child(5) {transform: rotateZ(150deg);}
b:nth-child(6) {transform: rotateZ(180deg);}
b:nth-child(7) {transform: rotateZ(210deg);}
b:nth-child(8) {transform: rotateZ(240deg);}
b:nth-child(9) {transform: rotateZ(270deg);}
b:nth-child(10) {transform: rotateZ(300deg);}
b:nth-child(11) {transform: rotateZ(330deg);}

#logo {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: #e17f1a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#logo svg {
  width: 5vh;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%   { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(720deg); }
}

#face:active {
  transform: perspective(80vw) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="face">
  <b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b>
  <div id="water">WASHER RESILIENT<br/>QUARTS</div>
  <div id="logo"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon native iconLogoSEAlternativeSm" width="5vh" height="5vh" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><g><path d="M2 1h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2H0c0-1.1.9-2 2-2z" fill="#e17f1a"></path><path d="M0 10h12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2zm7 2v3l3-3z" fill="#e17f1a"></path><path fill="#e17f1a" d="M0 4h12v2H0z"></path><path fill="#e17f1a" d="M0 7h12v2H0z"></path></g></svg>MSE</div>
  <div class="hand" id="second_hand"></div>
  <div class="hand" id="minute_hand"></div>
  <div class="hand" id="hour_hand"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your clock even has problems with timezone changes, just like a real watch

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!  By timezone changes, do you mean when you travel across a timezone it does not auto-update the time?  I assumed `let dt = new Date();` would use the time for your current timezone.

Comment: Most people poll Date.getseconds every second when they make their clock, making it automatically update if the timezone or the DST changes, you only do it at the start of your code, so while other peoples watches suddenly jump to the new time, your code emulates a real watch more closely by not following the time change

Answer (score 37):

Times (and dates) are the bane of all programmers, so I decided to write a book on it:

[image]

Many thanks to Joel on this. He might not know it, but without the 'Joel minute', this would have never happened.

<sub>Generated using [O RLY Cover Generator](https://dev.to/rly)</sub>

Comment: Haha, love the *Deciphering '6-8 weeks'* and the **O RLY**

Comment: Might be nice to credit the source of these (https://dev.to/rly)

Answer (score 34):

Hi everyone! My name is Tinkeringbell (or Tink for short) and I'll be your tour guide for today! Even though some people say time-travel is impossible, as an archaeologist I have to disagree. We're not allowed to disclose exactly [how we do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO0oG.jpg), and we're not allowed to take passengers. I can, however, present to you evidence and stories from my own [paleontological and archaeological travels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBEl5.jpg) today. Does everyone have their security clearance badge? Then let's enter [the vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psz1F.jpg) and start the tour!

### 1. Hot but boring.

As you can guess, we've tried travelling back as far as possible. So far, we've never been able to go further back than the late [Hadean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadean). It was hot, molten lava *everywhere*. We had to stay in the time capsule for protection and oxygen, which was rather boring! Until of course we almost lost all functionality and the ability to return. We managed to quickly grab some samples though. Look at how pretty they turned out to be once cooled down to room temperature!

[image]

### 2. Marine Life

Yes? You're asking why we skipped the section on bacterial life? Good question. You've no doubt noticed that high-level security area we just passed. Some of the things in there will kill you. To avoid accidents and liability issues, we skip from rocks to marine life here. Here you see the sad remains of some of the animals that didn't survive the trip home. Also note the really big shark teeth: we found them stuck in our time machine after barely escaping an attack. We sadly never managed to capture the culprit. Now, if you'll continue along the path, I have some amazing aquariums to show you!

[image]

### 3. Jurassic Park!

Yeah, you didn't really think we were that stupid now, were you?  We had to go back in time multiple times to fix that timeline! Ah well, at least we were left with some good movie plots. I'm sorry to say that we don't keep real dinosaurs in these vaults. Please enjoy the gift shop, and take some time to use the toilet and restaurant services. The tour will resume in 30 minutes, when we'll move on to the ice ages to visit our prized asset: [The Siberian Unicorn](https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/b26d845f12b220e8c450a23e91271565?width=1024)

[image]

### 4. The stone age

Time flies when you're having fun, doesn't it? Let me show you one more area, let's go to the stone age. It's an area we can just about cover before closing time if we hurry up. Here you can see a model we made based on observations of the [Carnac Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnac_stones) while they were just being built. We never figured out their purpose, but we now think they may be erected to commemorate our comings and goings.

[image]

Oh no, look at the time. I'm sorry, but we really, really need to wrap this up now. I have one final surprise for all of you: A small stone dagger to remember your trip by, crafted by our resident [Neanderthals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal). Don't worry, they find they have nothing better to do these days, now that they are being fed and cared for. Do I still have everyone? Good. I hope everyone enjoyed this tour. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Nothing's cooler than dinosaurs.

Comment: @Chair apparently, [ASCII Big Ben](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318917/369802) is cooler than dinosaurs ;-)

Comment: No, nothing's cooler than dinosaurs. :P

Answer (score 32):

Time can be applied in so many ways and the intricacies of it are beyond comprehension. As such, I created a new [Area51 site proposal focused on the subject of "time"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120733/time) so that we can join together in understanding it more fully.

[image]

I added some example questions, but please help me out if you have time!

Comment: That's dedication. +1, even though I doubt the proposal will work.

Comment: Well that didn't last long.

Comment: It only works if your timeline is travelling backwards. :-p

Comment: That proposal suffered an untimely end.

Answer (score 32):

> **End of competition note:** Since the competition is coming to an end and the posts will get locked I created a [Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/8176/1265) where I
>   might add any future updates to the app. Thanks for everyone upvoting,
>   and a special extra thanks for anyone who actually installed the app!
>
> I also received the swag, here's a comparison view:
>
> [image: Android Wear and the real swag]

## Stack Overflow Wear OS Watch Face

Looks like I went ahead in time and already gotten the swag somehow:

[image: Stack Overflow Wear OS Watch Face]

Or well not exactly, but what if you're like me and only entered the competition late with not much chance to win the price? Fear not, if you have a Wear OS 2.0+ based watch you can simply download the [SO Watch Face](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.sowatchface) and share the experience of having the swag with the actual winners!

[Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g)

And it's not just the design, it actually has some nice SO specific features:

- Most watch faces have their main notch set at 12 o'clock. Not this one! Here the main notch is always pointing to the exact time where Stack Overflow's limits reset, and you can once again collect reputation, finish reviews and vote up and down as if there was no tomorrow!

  In the example above, the notch is at 1 am, as I was in Budapest / CET. In the UK it would be shown right at the top at 12am. It even works for timezones which are not based on whole hours, like the Chatham Islands.
- Two watch faces - a simpler one, and another that resembles the swag as much as possible.
- A Stack Exchange Reputation Complication, that allows you to check your (or anyone else's) reputation on any SE site. It is set to Jon Skeet's SO user ID by default. Works with all other watch faces as well.
- While the main ideas have been implemented there are still a few stuff I might add, and feel free to suggest others as well here in the comments or [on GitHub](https://github.com/sztupy/SOWatchFace/issues). They will definitely be

  [image: ready in 6-8 weeks]

  but upvoting this post might make them ready much-much sooner.

Links:

- [Source code](https://github.com/sztupy/SOWatchFace) and Download
- [Google Play listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.sowatchface)
- [Demo video of the watch in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g) (shows version 5.0)

Updates:

## v6.0 / v7.0

- From now on you have to set the Stack Exchange Network User ID, and not the site specific one.
- Given you have an account there when switching sites your Site specific user ID will always update based on your Network User ID, so you would always see your own reputation
- v7.0 includes some minor fixes to this feature as well

## v5.0

[New Demonstration Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVwtpdLeB2g

[image: V5.0-1]
[image: V5.0-2]
[image: V5.0-3]
[image: V5.0-4]

*Major changes:*

- Removed all Stack Overflow icon from the build - should be much more compliant to the Trademark guidelines
- There is a box now to select which Stack Exchange site one wishes to use and the graphics will be applied based on that site
- All graphical detail (logos) are now downloaded and added to the watch faces dynamically based on the selected Stack Exchange site
- Added a new complication that just displays the selected site's logo.

*Minor fixes:*

- Complications now update automatically if the user id is changed
- Minute hand now moves appropriately
- Second hand now only moves in whole seconds

## v4.0

Changes:

- Fixes problems with complications not updating
- Adds support to show next reputation milestone as range for complications
- Should now be available from the Play Store from the watch, just search for "Stack Overflow"

## v3.0

[image: v3.0-1]
[image: v3.0-2]

- Settings page to set up the watch face
- Two different watch face - one that resembles the SWAG, the other one a more simpler one
- Supports two complications on the watch face
- Adds a new complication that shows a specific user's SO reputation

  - Works in other watch faces as well
  - Shows Jon Skeet's reputation by default
- Please note that the privacy policy was updated to contain that the SO user ID you set might be a PII, but it's only stored locally on the watch and only transmitted to the StackExchange API

## v2.0

[image: v2.0]

- Nicer watch face resembling the swag much more
- Water resistant to 6 to 8 weeks

## v1.0

[image: v1.0]

- Initial version
- Stack Overflow logo as a background
- Displays the UTC offset so you know when the Stack Overflow counters reset

Comment: *Wear OS now ;) This is awesome! Now I just want a complication to show my rep :P

Comment: @EmC true, forgot they renamed it a year ago or so :D. Definitely planning adding some complications to the mix

Comment: I think I preferred the simplicity of the original design if you're a programmer and user you don't need reminding what the logo represents. On the other hand, the resized logo makes it look classier, more expensive looking. That is one super watch, wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: The prize for this contest should be changed to a smartwatch with this set as the default face!

Comment: @EmC complication support is done!

Comment: [Looks awesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNUhv.png)! I like the bonus feature that I can pretend to be Jon Skeet when I look at my watch now ;)

Comment: @EmC nice pic. Am I seeing it correctly that the watch face doesn't fill the available space fully (the orange circle should be at the very edge of the display)

Comment: Nope, that is at the edge of the available screen space for my watch! I guess it just has a thicker black band around the edge of the screen than yours.

Comment: The watch face looks nice, however... I am concerned that you may be violating the Stack Overflow trademark by publishing this. Please refer to the [rules on using the logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22123/178816). IANAL, you may want consider contacting a lawyer as well as requesting the permission for use from Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: I tried to adhere as much as possible to the guidelines stated in https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance Hence the application name doesn't contain anything trademarked, and the logo is used to label the site the reputation display is coming from (although you can say that some parts of the application might imply false associations). However based on the same guidelines most answers that feature the logo in a distorted way (like the current top voted answer) would be invalid as well.

Comment: However I did plan on creating a meta page to figure out what to do with the app once the contest is over

Comment: The difference between using it as a reference (as in the answer cited) and in a published app is that the published app on the google store is considered to be used "in commerce" which is where the trademark issues come into play from a legalese standpoint. From a guidelines standpoint, they even state for apparel (which is generally covered here with the watch face), "Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission." While I cannot speak for them, I assume it would go alright if asked. It just needs to be done properly.

Comment: True, but on the other side I don't wish to create a meta thread about it before the end of the competition, to avoid the meta effect that could affect the votes on this thread.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think the meta thread is required though. If you are serious about pursuing the app then just use the contact us form by clicking the contact link at the bottom of any page. They are good about responding.

Comment: I would like to say - in this case, ugh, this is too darned epic, and I wish my smartwatch did android wear just so I could use it ;)

Comment: @SztupY I did send you an email about your concerns, were you able to get it?

Answer (score 30):

### Time Overflow<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup>

Guaranteed to take you where you need to be. Remember, it isn't about being in the right place at the right time... It's about being in the right place *all* the time.

<sub>*Please use Time Overflow<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup> responsibly. Changing things can be very problematic.*</sub> [image]

A little explanation... This time machine was made to
resemble the Stack Overflow logo ( <sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub>). It uses some orange LED's, staying with the orange theme of the logo, as well as lights for the whole lightspeed nature of time travel. In theory, going faster than the speed of light should allow time travel, although one does not simply go faster than the speed of light. *Unless* you have Time Overflow<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup>!

The space age materials include some electrical ballasts, a "lux" capacitor which is basically a transformer, a heavy duty timer to handle the stress of time travel as well as to indicate where to go, and some special effects.

Build at your own risk.

Comment: Nope. If you change the future, you're changing the past of someone who's even further into the future. You could even magic out of existence the person who sent you your time machine. Oops.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - After taking some *time* to consider, perhaps it is best to simply avoid changing things.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319049/400534 Well we had different stuff for same names 

Comment: I like how the underlying pipes are bent and distorted outside the Time field.

Answer (score 29):

My favourite [quote involving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana) is

> Time flies like an arrow;
>   fruit flies like a banana

The idea is that if we can get a computer to truly understand this we have cracked artificial intelligence.

Comment: It took this well-educated, erudite human a good 10 years to understand what this quote was about. And that's only because I read about it. I honestly never parsed it as "fruit flies" "like a banana", only as "fruit" "flies like a banana". If I can't understand it, I have no expectation of computers doing so.

Comment: @AndyT it's a context thing. I think each of the halves of this sentence would be quite understandable (in the intended meaning) if read individually. Just, after “Time flies like an arrow”, the brain automatically tries to parse the second half as “_X_ flies like _Y_” too. If you'd first read the sentence the other way around, you'd probably parse it as “ ‘Fruit flies’ like ‘a banana’; ‘time-flies’ like ‘an arrow’ ”.

Answer (score 29):

Well... yes, it is about time!

[image]

Want to see a simple view, here to go:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 var $timeline_block = $('.cd-timeline-block');


 $timeline_block.each(function () {
  if ($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 0.75) {
   $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
  }
 });


 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  $timeline_block.each(function () {
   if ($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden')) {
    $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", serif;
  color: #7f8c97;
  background-color: #e9f0f5;
}

a {
  color: #acb7c0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.cd-container {
  /* this class is used to give a max-width to the element it is applied to, and center it horizontally when it reaches that max-width */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.cd-container::after {
  /* clearfix */
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #303e49;
}
header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  header {
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

#cd-timeline {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em 0;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#cd-timeline::before {
  /* this is the vertical line */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background: #d7e4ed;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #cd-timeline {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
  #cd-timeline::before {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
  }
}

.cd-timeline-block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.cd-timeline-block::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cd-timeline-block:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.cd-timeline-block:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-block {
    margin: 4em 0;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.cd-timeline-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ffffff, inset 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 3px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.cd-timeline-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
.cd-timeline-img.cd-picture {
  background: #75ce66;
}
.cd-timeline-img.cd-movie {
  background: #c03b44;
}
.cd-timeline-img.cd-location {
  background: #f0ca45;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-img.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-img.bounce-in {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-1 0.6s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-bounce-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.cd-timeline-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #d7e4ed;
}
.cd-timeline-content::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cd-timeline-content h2 {
  color: #303e49;
}
.cd-timeline-content p, .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more, .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
}
.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more, .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-timeline-content p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
  float: right;
  padding: .8em 1em;
  background: #acb7c0;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more:hover {
  background-color: #bac4cb;
}
.cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 0;
  opacity: .7;
}
.cd-timeline-content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #ffffff;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-timeline-content h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more, .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-timeline-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 1.6em;
    width: 45%;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content::before {
    top: 24px;
    left: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
    float: left;
  }
  .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 122%;
    top: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content {
    float: right;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content::before {
    top: 24px;
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
    float: right;
  }
  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
    left: auto;
    right: 122%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-content.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-content.bounce-in {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-2 0.6s;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  /* inverse bounce effect on even content blocks */
  .cssanimations .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content.bounce-in {
    -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
    -moz-animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
    animation: cd-bounce-2-inverse 0.6s;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-bounce-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes cd-bounce-2-inverse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-20px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
  <header>
   <h1>Stack Overflow’s Story</h1>
  </header>

  <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">

   <!------------------2018 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
     <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2018</h2>
     <p>10th anniversary of Stack Overflow</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>August 2018</h2>
     <p>Brand new Code of Conduct (CoC).</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>May 2018</h2>
     <p>Stack Overflow for Teams has launched.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January  2018</h2>
     <p>Thanks a Million, Jon Skeet!.</p>
     <p>Jon Skeet’s reputation on Stack Overflow passed 1,000,000</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!------------------2018 end-------------------->


   <!------------------2017 start-------------------->
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>May 2017</h2>
     <p>A popular Stack Overflow question: How to exit the Vim editor? one million eighty-two times viewed.</p>
     <p>Stack Overflow Flipped the Switch on HTTPS.</p>
     <p>Introducing Stack Overflow Trends</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>February 2017</h2>
     <p>2017 Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2017 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2016 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>October 2016</h2>
     <p>The Stack Overflow Developer Story.</p>
     <p>Salary calculator now can calculate International Salaries</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>July 2016</h2>
     <p>Introducing the Stack Overflow salary calculator.</p>
     <p>Introducing Stack Overflow Documentation (Beta).</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2016 end-------------------->


   <!------------------2015 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>May 2015</h2>
     <p>Introducing Beyond Coding: Free professional skills training for emerging devs</p>

    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>April 2015</h2>
     <p>New Design Profile Page & Activity Page.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
     <img src="./images/job_targeted.ico" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January 2015</h2>
     <p>Targeted Jobs for Stack Overflow (changed a why to showing Jobs with Developer Types, Tech Ecosystems, and Tech
      Tags).</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2015 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2014 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>November 2014</h2>
     <p>Announcing Bosun, new open source monitoring & alerting system.</p>
     <p>Stack Exchange for the iPad is here – and iOS apps now support iOS 8.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2014</h2>
     <p>Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>May 2014</h2>
     <p>Stack Exchange for iPhone.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>April 2014</h2>
     <p>Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>March 2014</h2>
     <p>Your communities list is now customizable.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January 2014</h2>
     <p>Stack Exchange for Android.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!------------------2014 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2013 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2013</h2>
     <p>Five years completed.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January 2013</h2>
     <p>Rolled out a new Quick Start guide to help new users.</p>
     <p>Announcing a new way to change your profile picture.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2013 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2012 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div> 

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>February 2012</h2>
     <p>Stack Exchange co-founder Jeff Atwood announced for leaving the company.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2012 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2011 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>November 2011</h2>
     <p>New section "Review".</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>August 2011</h2>
     <p>Introduced Community Wiki.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>July 2011</h2>
     <p>Stack Exchange Mobile friendly.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>April 2011</h2>
     <p>Inline Comment and Post Markdown Help.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!------------------2011 end-------------------->



   <!------------------2010 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>December 2010</h2>
     <p>Stack Overflow Annual Survey (first).</p>
     <p>Subscribe to Tags via Email.</p>
     <p>Re-Launching Stack Exchange Data Explorer.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>October 2010</h2>
     <p>Stack Overflow Chat Goes to Live.</p>
     <p>One million questions on stack Overflow.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2010</h2>
     <p>Global Inbox.</p>
     <p>Global Network Auto-Login.</p>
     <p>Jon Skeet reached 200K reputation.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>August 2010</h2>
     <p>New Tag Info Pages.</p>
     <p>Share Questions and Answers.</p>
     <p>New Image Upload Support.</p>
     <p>Stackexchange.com the official network hub.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>July 2010</h2>
     <p>Stack Exchange API 1.0 Imminent.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>June 2010</h2>
     <p>Introducing Area 51.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>April 2010</h2>
     <p>New 10k Feature: Inline Tagging.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January 2010</h2>
     <p>Improved Comments with @reply.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!------------------2010 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2009 start-------------------->

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>October 2009</h2>
     <p>Introducing Stack Overflow Careers (beta).</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2009</h2>
     <p>One million page views in a single day.</p>
     <p>Jon Skeet reached 100K reputation.</p>
     <p>One Year of Stack Overflow.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>August 2009</h2>
     <p>Started showing Accept rate on question.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>July 2009</h2>
     <p>Migrate Questions Between Websites.</p>
     <p>Cross-Site Account Associations.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>June 2009</h2>
     <p>Meta Stack Overflow.</p>
    </div>
   </div>


   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>May 2009</h2>
     <p>Stack Overflow Moderator Voting introduced.</p>
     <p>Linking Duplicate Questions.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>April 2009</h2>
     <p>Red Flag Introduced.</p>
     <p>Comments with Flags and Votes.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>March 2009</h2>
     <p>Started Responsible Advertising..</p>
     <p>10k Reputaion Tools Available.</p>
     <p>Edit Feature.</p>
    </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>February 2009</h2>
     <p>Question / Answer Rate Limits.</p>
     <p>Reached 100K Questions.</p>
     <p>Email Newsletter.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>January 2009</h2>
     <p>Reputation Bounty for Unanswered Questions.</p>
     <p>New Replies Notification.</p>
     <p>Accept Your Own Answers.</p>
    </div>
   </div> 

   <!------------------2009 end-------------------->

   <!------------------2008 start-------------------->


   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>December 2008</h2>
     <p>Moderator Privileges </p>
    </div>
   </div> 

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>October 2008</h2>
     <p>Ability to mark a question as a favorite.</p>
     <p>Expressing Your Tag Preferences.</p>
    </div>
   </div> 

   <div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
                    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
    </div> 
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
     <h2>September 2008</h2>
     <p>Stack Overflow’s public beta went live.</p>     
    </div>
   </div> 
   <!------------------2008 end-------------------->

  </section> 
 </body>

</html>
```

---

*Inspired by Stack Overflow Developer Story*

Answer (score 28):

With apologies to Roger Waters:

Coding away the moments that make up a dull day
Fritter and waste compile time in an offhand way.
Kicking around on a jsquery in your core code
Waiting for someone on SO to show you the way.

Tired of sitting on your laptop, staying home to watch the rep.
You are young and life is long and there are votes to use today.
And then one day you find ten k have got behind you.
No one told you when to flag, you missed the HNQ!

So you post and you post to catch up with Jon Skeet but he's jamming
Racing ahead to be posting more answers again.
The front page is the same in a relative way but you're older,
Shorter of breath and one rep closer to gold.
Every year is getting more swag, never seem to find the time.
Posts that either get downvoted, or comments moved to chat again
Hanging on in quiet comment is the English way
The time is gone, the bounty's over,
Thought I'd something more to say.

SE
SE again
I like to lurk here
When I can
When I come home
Cold and tired
It's good to mod my top sites
Beside the fire

Far away
Across the field
Tolling on the chat room bell
Calls the faithful to their knees
To validate the softly spoken chat flags

(Definitely more cheerful than the original!!!)

Comment: Needs a link to the instrumental/[Karaoke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6pgea-_5BE) version otherwise how else will the millennials know just how good this is?

Comment: @Mari-Lou As a millennial I love Pink Floyd :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Where is it?

Answer (score 28):

[image: pie chart]

---

Credits: Inspired by [this graph](http://devcv.me/2013/08/time-allocation-while-programming/) and thanks @Machavity and @Dennis Williamson for the timely improvement suggestions :)

Comment: -1 for not mentioning "Browsing Stack Overflow"

Comment: -1 for not including time for [compiling](https://xkcd.com/303/).

Comment: Complaining about how bad the last person's code was should be part of it, unless of course you only write original code, then lucky you!

Answer (score 27):

LEGO‽ Time‽ [***LEGO time lapse‽***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCNjl.jpg)

Close up of the finished product!
[image: LEGO Time]

Comment: Was gonna flag as NAA, but the *time*-lapse in your link is too good. Might want to specify that's what it is to avoid more confusion.

Comment: Great, (and timely ;) ) suggestion! Updated

Answer (score 24):

I'm having a course called *Digital Circuit Experiments* which is about programming FPGA in Verilog. So I am here ...

#### Announcing my [**FPGA Stopwatch**](https://github.com/iBug/Nexys4-DDR-stopwatch) that's built for timing!

[image]

Or watch [live <s>streaming</s> demo online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdMKlXLNvkg)!

#### Features:

- Stopwatch start/stop on switch 0
- "Hold" function to keep the numbers with switch 1
- "Show hours" with switch 2 (by default, segment displays are only lit up when required, flipping this switch up will force show up to the hour digit)
- "20x turbo boost" with switch 3 (it just replaces the internal clock)
- Reset with BTNU
- A good-looking merry-go-round-style LED animation when the stopwatch is counting!

The code is too much, but you can read more @@>>> https://github.com/iBug/Nexys4-DDR-stopwatch or [Download ZIP](https://github.com/iBug/Nexys4-DDR-stopwatch/archive/release.zip) (Created with Xilinx Vivado 2018.2) (Code licensed under the MIT License)

#### Optional accessories:

- A Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow sticker as shown in the image above :)

Comment: wow :-) nice one

Answer (score 24):

Well, considering the current season and that the theme is the passing of time, I think an Advent Calendar is most appropriate here. Run the attached snippet to see it.

```js
var today = new Date();



$(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen : false, modal : true, show : "blind", hide : "blind"
  });
  
$(".day").click(function() {
    var bypass= false;
    if ($('#bypassDateCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        bypass= true;
    }

    if (today.getMonth() === 11 || bypass ){
      var clickedId = $(this).attr('id'); 
      if (today.getDate() >= Number(clickedId) || bypass){
        $(".dialog.day"+clickedId).dialog("open");
        
        if (clickedId == 22){
          itsMonopolyDay();
        }
      }
      else {
        $(".dialog.notYet").dialog("open"); 
      }
    }
    else
    {
        $(".dialog.notEvenDecember").dialog("open");  
    }
    return false;
});

$("#zorkInput").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  
        checkAction();
    }
});

function fortuneCookie() {
  var fortunes = [
    "You will get a fortune cookie.",
    "You will vote for an answer about an advent calendar on meta.",
    "Error: 404 Fortune not found.",
    "You cannot grasp the true nature of the fortune cookie attack.",
    "This is not the fortune cookie you were looking for.",
    "One does not simply eat a fortune cookie",
    "I was a meta user like you some time ago but then I took a fortune cookie to the knee.",
    "The Parrot! Do not trust the Parrot!",
    "A WINNER IS YOU!",
    "You will start watching a show about candy colored ponies.",
    "You will find true happiness if you share this answer link with 7 friends withing one hour."    
  ];

  var randomFortune = fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
  
  alert(randomFortune);
}

function claimCookie(){
  alert("Sorry, the Stack Exchange snippets sandbox security does not allow us to set cookies on the client :P.")
}

function closeUpdateDialog() {
  
  $(".dialog.day17").dialog("close");
}

function startEndlessUpdate(){
  $(".dialog.endlessUpdate").dialog("open");
  
  var messages = [
    "Generating bugs...", 
    "Downloading MLP episodes...",
    "Configuring flux capacitor...",
    "Sealing user credentials...",
    "Removing Herobrine...",
    "Installing SharePoint...",
    "Hatching chickens eggs...",
    "Doing lame puns...",
    "Resting for a bit...",
    "Mapping dungeons...",
    "Spawing NPCs...",
    "Generating artifacts...",
    "Filling water buckets...",
    "Knitting hats...",
    "Formatting local disks...",
    "Collecting 200$ from passing start...",
    "Parsing HTML using RegEx...",
    "Summoning Cthulhu...",
    "Pinging Shog9...",
    "Asking Jon Skeet for the codez...",
    "Searching for unicorns...",
    "Asking to upvote swag contest submissions...",
    "Attempting to become the Pirate King...",
    "Catching all Pokémons...",
    "Synching clocks...",
    "Frammenting disk...",
    "Increasing ram usage...",
    "Reading some books...",
    "Loading cat pictures...",
    "Drawing red hand circles...",
    "Staring chat messages...",    
    "Collecting more hats...",
    "Configuring HDRR...",
    "Crafting Rings of Power...",
    "Waiting for planet alignment...",
    "Improving room feng-shui...",
    "Coloring picture books...",
    "Eating cotton candy...",
    "Baking cupcakes...",
    "Buying muffins...",
    "Making friends...",
    "Ranting for downvotes...",
    "Putting holes in swiss cheese...",
    "Raising the sun...",
    "Watering tomatoes...",
    "Opening worms cans...",
    "Increasing system entropy...",
    "Generating funny messages...",
    "Scolding Shadow Wizard for being uncouth...",
    "Computing question to the Life, Universe and Everything...",
    "Waiting for user to get bored...",
    "Writting letters to Princess Celestia...",
    "Learning friendship lessons...",
    "Making jokes no one will understand...",    
  ];

  setInterval(function switchUpdateMessage(){ 
    var randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    $("#updateMessage").text(randomMessage);
    return switchUpdateMessage;
  }(), 3000);
}

function checkAction() {
  $("#zorkInputLine").hide();
  
  value = $("#zorkInput").val();
  
  if (value == "offer cupcake to grue") {
    $("#zorkRoomText").text("You befriend a nearby grue by offering it the last cupcake you had. In return, the grue shows you the way to the Stack Exchange treasure room, where all the unicorn plushes are stored. THE END.");
  }
  else {
    $("#zorkRoomText").text("Sorry, I don't know how to '"+value+"'. But it doesn't matter now. A grue came and ate you. GAME OVER.");
  }
}

function itsMonopolyDay(){
  setTimeout(function foo() {
    $(".dialog.monopoly").dialog("open");
  }, 1000);
}

function showCommonRates() {
  $(".dialog.commonCrateRates").dialog("open");
}
function showRareRates() {
  $(".dialog.rareCrateRates").dialog("open");
}
function showEpicRates() {
  $(".dialog.epicCrateRates").dialog("open");
}

function showBuyPopup(rarity){
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to buy a "+rarity+ " crate?")){
    $(".dialog.dupeHat").dialog("open");
  }
  else {
  
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
  --transform: scale(0.5);
}

#calendar  {
  width: 35%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#calendar > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#calendar > div > div {
  width: 14%;
  text-align: center;
}
#calendar > div.header{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font: 12px bold;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dayRow{
  --background: green;
}

.day {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;  
  vertical-align: middle;
 background-image:  url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPSIxOCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxOCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE4IDE4IiBjbGFzcz0ic3ZnLWljb24iPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xIDEzYzAgMS4xLjkgMiAyIDJoOHYzbDMtM2gxYTIgMiAwIDAgMCAyLTJ2LTJIMXYyek0xNSAxSDNhMiAyIDAgMCAwLTIgMnYyaDE2VjNhMiAyIDAgMCAwLTItMnpNMSA2aDE2djRIMVY2eiIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bGlnaHRncmF5Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center; 
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.theLegendaryFreeHandDrawnCircleOfLegends {

background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-button-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.extraSmallText{
  font-size: 6px;
}

.goldTicket{
  background-color: gold;
}

.center{
text-align: center;
}

.song{
  font-size: small;
  font-style: italic;
}

.itemImage{
  border: 4px double white;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 52px;
}

.legendaryItem {
  background-color: black;
  border: 4px double white;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


.legendaryItem > .name{
  font-style: bold;
  color: #ff8000;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.legendaryItem > .rarity{
  font-style: italic;
  color: gold;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
.legendaryItem > .description{
  color: white;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.legendaryItem >.flavorText{
  color: yellow;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.legendaryItem > .sellingPrice{
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.smithSpeech{
  color: black;
  background: rgb(211,211,211);
  border: 2px ridge black;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.updateInfoArea {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.updateInfoArea > #updateMessage{
  font-size: small;
  font-style: italic;
}

.dialog.day18.ui-dialog-content{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Consolas";
}

.unstyledInput{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.monopolyCard{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.monopolyHeader{
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.monopolytext{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-content: center;  
  font-size: small;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "text0 price0"
    "text1 price1"
    "text2 price2"
    "text3 price3"
    "text4 price4"
    "text5 price5";
}

.monopolyFooter{
  font-size: small;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
}


.text0 { grid-area: text0; }

.crates {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.crate{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.cratePic{
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  align-self: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.crateLabel,
.cratePrice{
  font-size: small;
}

.crateLabel{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.percentageRow{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <section id="calendar">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="dayLabel">Mon</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Tue</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Wed</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Thu</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Fri</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Sat</div>
      <div class="dayLabel">Sun</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dayRow">
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div id="1" class="day">1</div>
      <div id="2" class="day">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dayRow">
      <div id="3" class="day">3</div>
      <div id="4" class="day">4</div>
      <div id="5" class="day">5</div>
      <div id="6" class="day">6</div>
      <div id="7" class="day">7</div>
      <div id="8" class="day">8</div>
      <div id="9" class="day">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dayRow">
      <div id="10" class="day">10</div>
      <div id="11" class="day">11</div>
      <div id="12" class="day">12</div>
      <div id="13" class="day">13</div>
      <div id="14" class="day">14</div>
      <div id="15" class="day">15</div>
      <div id="16" class="day">16</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dayRow">
      <div id="17" class="day">17</div>
      <div id="18" class="day">18</div>
      <div id="19" class="day">19</div>
      <div id="20" class="day">20</div>
      <div id="21" class="day">21</div>
      <div id="22" class="day">22</div>
      <div id="23" class="day">23</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dayRow">
      <div id="24" class="day">24</div>
      <div id="25" class="day">25</div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
      <div class="emptyDay"> </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Bypass the date checks: </span>
  <input id="bypassDateCheckbox" type="checkbox" style="width:20px;" checked >
</div>

<div class="dialog day1" title="Sat, Dec 1st">
  <p>Today you get a free cookie! Click <a href="#" onclick="claimCookie()">here</a> to claim it.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day2" title="Sun, Dec 2nd">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqfqL.png" />
</div>
<div class="dialog day3" title="Mon, Dec 3rd">
  <p>I had prepared some cupcakes, but I forgot today is also Twilight birthday, so she gets them instead. Sorry, try again tomorrow.</p>
  <div class="flex-row">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4SzT.png" />
   <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      If that's any comfort, they were hay-flavored.
   </div>
  <div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day4" title="Tue, Dec 4th">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpag.gif" />
</div>
<div class="dialog day5" title="Wed, Dec 5th">
  <p>Congratulation! You just won some <marquee>FREE REP</marquee>To claim it please compile <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask">this request form</a> with the required info. Your rep will be delivered in 6 to 8 time units.*</p>
<p class="extraSmallText">* Waring: may result in negative free rep in some not-null probability cases</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day6" title="Thu, Dec 6th">
  <p>Today is <a href="https://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/miners-day/">"Miners' Day</a>. To celebrate it, we are currently using your cpu to extract some <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins">Unicoins</a> from the depths of Stack Exchange salt mines. Please, stand by while we finish and do not turn out your pc.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day7" title="Fri, Dec 7th">
    <a href="https://www.google.it/maps/@40.7087193,-74.0068885,3a,75y,313.51h,79.36t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sAF1QipPkI6vTyjgKR-q5RmtXFX5hLwQJ_58ja3SrdGDC!2e10!3e11!7i13312!8i6656" target="_blank"><img style="width:100%" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj2EC.jpg" title="Nope, you won't get the chocolate bar, we alredy ate it."/></a>
    <div class="center" style="font-size: 12px">Please, click the ticket to claim it (if that doesn't work, open the link in a new tab)</div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day8" title="Sat, Dec 8th">
  <p>Today prize contained personaly identificable informations and has been removed in compliance with the new G.D.P.R European laws.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day9" title="Sun, Dec 9th" style="font-size: 13px;">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFtJZ.png" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <p>You just got a cheap bootleg plastic replica of Tim's Lost Keys. It is a shame they aren't the real ones, though.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Legends tell that someday an Hero of Light will came and claim the lost keys, putting an end to the dark reign of the <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/171199">Unjustified Downvote Lord</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day10" title="Mon, Dec 10th">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div  class="itemImage">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/62eCw.gif" style="height: 50px;"/>
    </div>  
    <div style="margin-left: 5px" class="legendaryItem">
      <h5 class="name">Ring Of The Annoying Bird</h5>
      <h6 class="rarity">Item level 9001</h6>
      <div class="description">
        <div>Binds when picked up</div>
        <div>Finger</div>
        <div style="margin-top: 5px">+75% to agro generation</div>
        <div style="color: lightgreen">Equip: Persuasion +20 (25 at level 9999)</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flavorText">"Sometimes a quick rant is the fastest way to get things done."</div>
      <div class="sellingPrice">Sell price: 10 <span style="color: gold">●</span> 18 <span style="color: silver">●</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day11" title="Tue, Dec 11th">
  <p>Today, you get free hats. Why are you here? <a href="https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/">Go hunting now!</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day12" title="Wed, Dec 12th"  style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuWpp.png'); background-size: cover;">
   <div class="flex-row" style="height: 200px">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2GtJ.png" style="height: 70px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <p class="smithSpeech">  ' , .  '   '  !         '  .                ' </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day13" title="Thu, Dec 13th">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1BVJ.png" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <p>You got a piece of moldy cheese. Only 47.577.295 lefthover cheese slices from the last swag event to ditch off now.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day14" title="Fri, Dec 14th">
  <div class="flex-row">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqahd.png" />
   <div style="padding-left: 10px" class="song">
      <p>On the first day of Christmas your true network sent to you</p>
<p>A <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell">parrot</a> in a pear tree.</p>
   </div>
  <div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day15" title="Sat, Dec 15th">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZgfP.png" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" onclick="fortuneCookie()" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px">
      <p>A fortune cookie! You should click it an see what is inside!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day16" title="Sun, Dec 16th year 214">
   <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzZMn.jpg" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" onclick="fortuneCookie()" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: 10px;">
    To the attention of ALL CITIZENS. This calendar entry is currently placed at Security Clearance ULTRAVIOLET. Reading any part of this notice without appropiate security clearance is considered treason. Please proceed directly to your nearest available Termination Booth. Thank you for your cooperation. Have a nice daycycle!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day17" title="Mon, Dec 17th">
  <p>In order to see this day calendar item, you need to update your Swag Advent Calendar app to a never version.</p>
  <div class="flex-button-row"><button onclick="startEndlessUpdate()">Update</button><a href="#" onclick="closeUpdateDialog()">Remind me later</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day18" title="Tue, Dec 18th">
  <div style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <p id="zorkRoomText">> You find yourself in a room, staring at an advent calendar. On a nearby table there is a lantern. The rest of the room is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue. What do you do?</p>
    <p id="zorkInputLine">> <input id="zorkInput" type="text" class="unstyledInput" />
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="dialog day19" title="Wed, Dec 19th">  
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FietH.png" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: small;">
      <p>Today Stack Exchange is giving away free fried chicken nuggets! Get them while they last!</p>
      <p>... wait... Chicken nuggets? <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken">They wouldn't dare!!! BALPHAAAAAAAA!!!!!!</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day20" title="Thu, Dec 20th">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv1Vp.png" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: small; padding-top: 10px;">
      <p>Otay oinjay ethay Tacksay Exchangay abalcay, askay otay ethay arrotpey inay ethay averntay</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day21" title="Fri, Dec 21st">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnVLT.jpg" style="width: 100%"/>
  <p>Today it is Dalek Day, so instead of the usual joke you get a nice collection of Daleks. Please choose your favorite one, we have all flavors from strawberry to liquirice.</p>
</div>
<div class="dialog day22" title="Sat, Dec 22th">
  <div class="monopolyCard">
    <h4 class="monopolyHeader">Park Palace</h4>
    <div class="monopolytext">
      <div class="grid-area: text0">RENT</div><div style="grid-area: price0">$35</div>
      <div style="grid-area: text1">With 1 House</div><div style="grid-area: price1">$175</div>
      <div style="grid-area: text2">With 2 House</div><div style="grid-area: price2">$500</div>
      <div style="grid-area: text3">With 3 House</div><div style="grid-area: price3">$1100</div>
      <div style="grid-area: text4">With 4 House</div><div style="grid-area: price4">$1300</div>
      <div style="grid-area: text5">With Hotel</div><div style="grid-area: price5">$1500</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="monopolyFooter">If a player owns ALL the lots of any Color-Group, the rent is Doubled on Unimproved Lots in that group. </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day23" title="Sun, Dec 23st">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BO78.gif" style="height: 60px; padding-top: 20px;" />
    <div style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: small; padding-top: 10px;">
      <p>You got a sprite swap mod! Now you can play as JNat in any Nes game!.</p>
      <p>The mod is so advanced that it doesn't require any installation either: just boot up the game of your choice, concentrate and here you go:P</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day24" title="mon, Dec 24th">
  <h5 style="margin: 0; text-align: center; background-color: blue; color: white;">
    <div>Complete your hat collection!</div>
    <div>Buy an Hat Crate now!</div>
  </h5>
  <div class="crates">
    <div class="crate">
      <img class="cratePic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J4Bh.png" onclick="showBuyPopup('Common')"/>
      <span class="crateLabel">Common <a href="#" onclick="showCommonRates()">(?)</a></span>
      <span class="cratePrice">$10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="crate">
      <img class="cratePic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWyRp.png" onclick="showBuyPopup('Rare')" />
      <span class="crateLabel">Rare <a href="#" onclick="showRareRates()">(?)</a></span>
      <span class="cratePrice">$75</span>
    </div>
    <div class="crate">
      <img class="cratePic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jAxe.png" onclick="showBuyPopup('Epic')"/>
      <span class="crateLabel">Epic <a href="#" onclick="showEpicRates()">(?)</a></span>
      <span class="cratePrice">$200</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dialog day25" title="Tue, Dec 25th">
  <p>Today is the last day... So instead of a joke you will get something different.</p>
  <p>I don't know if you, reader, actually celebrate Christmas or any other special event in this period. But I had to chose a day to end this, so... forgive me if this date has no meaning in your country.</p>
  
  <p>Either way... have a nice day! It was fun till it lasted, I hope I was able to make you smile even for a little. <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6ZaCY0sToo">Till next time!</a></p>
</div>

<div class="dialog notEvenDecember" title="A message from Yoda">
  <p>The path to December long is. Patience have you must.</p>
</div>

<div class="dialog notYet" title="A cheater is You">
  <p>Thou are not future enough to use this. Yet.</p>
</div>

<div class="dialog endlessUpdate" title="Wasting your time...">
  <p>The application is currently updating. Please do not turn off your connection or disconnect your pc.</p>
  <div class="updateInfoArea">
    <div id="updateMessage">foobar</div>
    <div style="width: 100%"><progress style="width: 100%"></progress></div>
  <div>
</div>

<div class="dialog commonCrateRates" title="Common Crate % Rates">
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Common Hat</div><div>95%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Rare Hat</div><div>4.5%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Epic Hat</div><div>0.5%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Unique Hat</div><div>0%</div></div>
</div>

<div class="dialog rareCrateRates" title="Rare Crate % Rates">
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Common Hat</div><div>20%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Rare Hat</div><div>70%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Epic Hat</div><div>9%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Unique Hat</div><div>1%</div></div>
</div>

<div class="dialog epicCrateRates" title="Epic Crate % Rates">
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Common Hat</div><div>0%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Rare Hat</div><div>25%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Epic Hat</div><div>50%</div></div>
  <div class="percentageRow"><div>Unique Hat</div><div>25%</div></div>
</div>

<div class="dialog dupeHat" title="A loser is you">
  <p>Oh, no, what a shame. You got a common hat you already had. But you can still buy another one and hope you'll have more luck next time...</p>
</div>

<div class="dialog monopoly" title="Danger! Somecactus set us up the hotel!">
  <p>Oh, no! You landed on Stack Palace! And Grace had an hotel built there, too! You now own Stack Exchange 1500 unicorn dollars! Let's hope you get some by the end of this...</p>
</div>
```

---

**Note**: As expected from a real advent calendar, you will be able to open only cells up to the current date. Also, please notice that you should wait till Dec, 1st to be able to open the first "window". You could also cheat and look at the code, if you want to ruin your fun...

---

And since some asked me in the chat, let's add some explanations too:

Dec, 1st:

> Giving out free cookies is a common internet meme. The joke here is that I was planning to give out an actual javascript cookie instead.

Dec, 2nd:

> Free hand circles are a meme on the Meta site. This year Winter Bash event even features a Free Hand Circle hat!

Dec, 3rd:

> Just an MLP based joke, since many fans of the show consider this day Twilight birthday (that based on the airing date of an old episode of the show).

Dec, 4th

> A simple joke based on the original Super Mario Bros Nes game. At the end of each world, a Toad would tell you that "The princess is in another castle". As expected, it quickly became a meme.

Dec, 5th

> One of the lames jokes. Not only I use the forbidden  tag, I also claim that to get free rep points... you will have to post a question on the site. And the free votes may be negative, too.

Dec, 6th

> Just a reference to miners day, and the recent trends of malware using the victim CPU/GPU to mine cryptocurrencies.

Dec, 7th

> A reference to Charlie and the Chocolate Factory, with Shog9 playing the role of Willy Wonka. The virtual tour idea came to me after remembering some user on chat posting the link to the SE Google Maps Office Tour some years ago.

Dec, 8th

> Just a reference to the recent [GDPR compliance mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310321/brace-yourselves-the-gdpr-is-coming).

Dec, 9th

> Another reference to a Meta meme, this time to Tim's lost keys. [See here to find out more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/171199).

Dec, 10th

> A vague reference to the "twitter incident" that happened in October.

Dec, 11th

> Just a lame "Winter Bash has started" advertisement.

Dec, 12th

> A reference to the Ultima games and Smith the talking horse, a recurring character in the series. As the Ultima wiki writes about Smith:
>  *"The "useless hint" joke came about because Smith was supposed to give a vital clue in Ultima IV, but the programmers forgot to add it into his conversation tree. When designing Ultima V, they decided to put Smith back in the game and, as a joke, had him give the hint he was supposed to provide in Ultima IV. Following this, it became a running gag in the series to make Smith one game out-of-sync.*
>  Because of this, I though it would be funny to have him give out an hint about how to get one secret hat **from last year Winter Bash event**.

Dec, 13th

> About 6-8 time units before this contest was made, another contest [involving cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese) took place. This is a joke about the staff still trying to dispose all the cheese they got during said contest.

Dec, 14th

> A reference to a [popular Christmas song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song)). The original line from the song is:
>  *On the first day of Christmas my true love sent to me / A partridge in a pear tree.*
>  So, since one of the local Tavern chat room users/moderators is known for having a parrot avatar...

Dec, 15th

> Just a fortune cookie random message generator. It actually has about ten different messages. Originally planned to have some animation too, but that was dropped due to time and the limitations of the SE snippet tool.

Dec, 16th

> A reference to the tabletop game [Paranoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoia_(role-playing_game)). The date for the day is a reference to the game too, since in the Paranoia setting the year is **always** 214...

Dec, 17th

> An endless update joke, because we all know that updates often seem to require *too much time to apply*. As an added bonus, the fake update process displays a lot of joke messages, again randomly selected. I suggest watching the update screen for a while, just to see a few of the available messages.

Dec, 18th

> A reference to old text-based adventure games, and specifically to [Zork grue](http://zork.wikia.com/wiki/Grue) monsters. Also a reference to the "[You Cannot Get Ye Flask](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouCantGetYeFlask)" problem in text adventure games: given a situation, the command parser would often only recognize very specific command formats (like "ignite lantern" but not the more common "lit lantern"), resulting in many premature deaths... In this case, every command will get you eaten by the Grue - except a very specific one. Also notice that the game is only playable once without rerunning the script: this is on purpose for added annoyance - if you have to reference an annoying trope....

Dec, 19th

> Long story short, this is a reference to "The Chicken", a now recurring "meme" during Winter Bash event. [Since this year the chicken wasn't actually found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken) I made up the joke that balpha (who was involved in the preparation of the event) ate it. [Weirdly enough, on this same day balpha posted a chicken emoji on twitter...](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/1075513648796311553)

Dec, 20th

> An Illuminati joke, written in Pig Latin. Since the Tavern crew is often accused to be part of a secret Stack Overflow cabal that lurks in the shadows while controlling the networks... I suggested that one should ask the Parrot to join.

Dec, 21th

> Just a reminder that Dec, 21th was Dalek Remembrance Day.

Dec, 22th

> A short Monopoly themed joke.

Dec, 23th

> A joke about JNat. He is known for using a rotating Megaman gif as his avatar. Because of this, I made a joke about having a mod that replaces Megaman with JNat... Since he *is* Megaman the actual character sprite wouldn't change.

Dec, 24th

> "Add buyable hat loot crates for Winter Bash" has been a joke for years now. So I did a joke involving that.

Dec, 25th

> Just some final goodbye. The linked video is taken from MLP:FIM ending credits sequence.

Comment: +1 for the idea, -1 for requiring patience

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd well... You basically get a joke (and I hope a little smile) for 25 days, starting on Dec, 1st... so... More days, more fun?

Answer (score 24):

I've always been in love with `Humans Since 1982` work , specially `A million Times` Digital clock of Analog clocks 
 : https://www.humanssince1982.com/a-million-times .

So I decided to create the same concept in `ReactJS` . Started from a single analog clock , to a group of clocks , to a group of groups to display the current time as Digital.

The final work looks like :

[image: AnalogDigitalClock]

Here's the Github pages : https://ashrafonline.github.io/AnalogDigitalClock/

And the Github repository : https://github.com/ashrafonline/AnalogDigitalClock

Comment: Beautiful art!.

Comment: Awesome transition effects.

Comment: This is amazing! Minor question: it looks like the transitions always start from 12:00 - is it possible to have them start at the last position of the clock, so there are no "jumps"?

Comment: @hbaderts Thanks . Noted , a small modification could be applied for this . Something related to `animation-fill-mode: forwards` CSS attribute .

Answer (score 19):

The Pythonic answer

```
import time
```

Comment: `import time as swag`?

Comment: [Relevant.](https://xkcd.com/353/)

Answer (score 18):

About time this contest started :D

In honor of a time honored tradition among programmers, namely poor date and time handling, I'll share my latest programming nightmare:

The time (doh!) is 2006, and the horror story plays in a small German company with a new IT employee who is not a programmer, but has been tasked with creating an entire order processing and sample storage system from scratch, all on his own.

Many mistakes were had as this now programmer navigated his way throughout the treacherous waters of Microsoft Access 2003, but none would be so truly horrifying like the following:

### The stage

To set the stage here, the program allows the uploading of files to a remote storage folder. Over the years over 840,000 such files have accumulated. Every file is denoted with its own entry in a relational database. Now, there are two time related pitfalls here: the `uploadDate` is saved and the `lastModifiedDate` of the file.

### Of dread gods and string based date handling

Our new programmer had of course no idea how to handle dates, and all he knew was that the `datetime` SQL Server type did not like his date format much. So, he did what every aspiring programmer has at least considered and briefly pondered before discarding the idea: save the time of upload as a string and the `lastModifiedDate` as part of the filename.

This worked ... just, and was eventually implemented.

### The corruption of cthulhu or technical debt

In the 15 years since then, the program grew and expanded, and every time a new method of uploading files was handled, the programmer did not much care for their previous time formatting, so they made the new methods different. At some point a new column was added to just save timestamps, but due to compatibility concerns with now legacy code that nobody dared touch it was run in parallel with the other systems and essentially just in addition to them.

Finally, both the timestamps and flat datetimes were truncated to the full hour, but since our programmer did not know how to truncate timestamps to the full hour, he just used `timestamp = timestamp / 60` in stead.

The sane programmers among the readers might feel the chorus of tony the pony voices rising now...

The craziest part about that horror story is that replacing this system is what I'm currently working on. Very *time*ly indeed to be doing that 15 years after its inception, don't you all think?

Comment: Answered in 22 minutes, not that I was timing.

Comment: I only now just noticed you have cthulu in your story too.

Answer (score 18):

> There once was a site known as Meta,
>   a prestigious site, a trendsetter!
>   A place to win prizes
>   (which sort of disguises
>   its mission of making Stack better)!
>
> One day in the year's festive season
>   (with little-to-no given reason)
>   Stack deigned to release
>   an upmarket timepiece
>   in exchange for a lyrical pleadin'.
>
> Into the competition came fredley
>   whose limericks were considered quite deadly.
>   In one of his stanzas
>   his mind went bananas:
>   he could see his own future confusedly:
>
> In his mind's eye he witnessed his fate
>   of fantastic watches, no, wait!
>   He got too distracted,
>   his code is impacted!
>   This isn't going to end great...
>
> In the present he's back on S.O.:
>   his program's decided to throw
>   a horrible error,
>   he looks on with terror,
>   its message: Stack Overflow

Comment: I love it....Brilliant!

Answer (score 17):

On Mi Yodeya, over the years, we have built up a novel body of time-related Judaism literature. Fortunately for fans of Judaeo-horology everywhere<sup>1</sup>, one of the United States' two annual government-mandated time-mutilation events frequently occurs around one of Mi Yodeya's favorite times of year: [Purim Torah season](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) (you know, that time in early Spring when the HNQ fills with titles from Mi Yodeya that don't make sense<sup>2</sup>). This coincidence has afforded us the opportunity to produce a vital collection of questions and answers, which I will excerpt and adapt here, in the style of [Mi Yodeya Publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications):

## Daylight Saving Time in Jewish Law

[image: A clock missing an hour, with a smiley and question marks]

### [Daylight Saving Time - forward or backward?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15003/daylight-saving-time-forward-or-backward) (2012)

**[Seth J](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5/seth-j) asked:** [Halachically](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary/597#597) speaking, do I *have to* set my clocks forward one hour in the spring, or can I set them back one hour (this will give me two hours more in my day than everyone setting their clocks forward one hour)?

**[Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex) ruled**: The latter course of action is not recommended. If you are two hours ahead of everyone else, then that will lead to great confusion, so that those will be "bad hours" - and we specifically pray (in Sabbath morning prayers) ויציל נפשותינו מן השעות הרעות, that Hashem should save our souls from the bad hours.

So the proper way is indeed to set them forward one hour. In this way, you will be קונה עולמו בשעה אחת (buying the entire world with a single hour).

**Seth J challenged:** No, I'd be two hours *behind*. Don't you see how great that would be?

**Alex concluded:** Then that would be even worse. Jeremiah (7:24) castigates those who ויהיו לאחור ולא לפנים - are behind rather than ahead.

### [Announcing the clock change in English](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/announcing-the-clock-change-in-english)? (2014)

**[Isaac Moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses) demanded:** It is well-known that the age-old, widespread, and correct practice is to [announce](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/purpose-of-announcing-molad) the [molad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molad) on the Sabbath preceding a new month specifically in the holy language of Yiddish. In contrast to this, in many synagogues I've attended, on the Shabbat preceding a [clock change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), the date, time, import, and humorously supposed implications on Sunday morning services attendance of the clock change are routinely announced in the profane language of <s>***ish</s> [the vernacular](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/should-we-censor-the-term-goy-when-used-in-english-to-mean-gentile), e.g. English. The former comes 11 - 12 times per year, while the latter comes only twice, so the latter is clearly holier. In addition, as the clock changes involve contractions and expansions of time itself, similar to the [spatial distortions](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/mikdash5/120a-mikdash.htm) that radiated from the mishkan, they must be extremely holy.

What <s>possible excuse could there be</s> is the source for making this holy announcement in a profane language?

**[Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio) explained:** This isn't about the Holy Tongue itself; it's about holding close to the original language.  Of course for anything arising from torah this language is Hebrew, so it is proper to announce the molad in that tongue.  (While some might confuse Hebrew and Yiddish, I am surprised that you did.  I therefore conclude that you have begun your Purim celebration early and that this was an accident.  I will try to simplify the rest of this answer to take your current state into account.)

Daylight Saving [sic] Time<sup>3</sup>, on the other hand, does not -- shockingly -- arise from torah.  Why we therefore do it at all is a separate question, beyond the scope of this answer.  But given that we do, we tie its announcement to the language of its enactment, which in the US is English, the language used in the [legislation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1918_Standard_Time_Act).

One could argue that the US legislation is derived from [German practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#History_of_DST_in_the_United_States) and that we should therefore announce it in German, or perhaps even Yiddish.  However, we do not recognize the authority of foreign kings nor bow down to them in any way, so announcing in German would raise issues of [*marit ayin*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary/615#615).

Of course, Jews living in other countries that have clock-alteration laws should use the language of their legal decrees, and if this is a practical matter for you be sure to consult your local timekeeper (which is, I guess, how you got into this mess in the first place, oops).

### [Seeking texts of all prayers associated with the clock change](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69320/seeking-texts-of-all-prayers-associated-with-the-clock-change) (2016)

**Isaac Moses requested**: In previous years, we've discussed the [basic commandment status](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/is-daylight-saving-time-a-mitzvah-deoraitha-or-takkanah-derabanan) of changing clocks around this time of year as well as the [proper language](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/announcing-the-clock-change-in-english) for announcing the change. Given that it's a commandment and that it is invariably announced in the synagogue, I assume that there must be associated blessings and liturgy. Has anyone come across any prescribed prayers, in English, Hebrew, Yiddish, Judaeo-Arabic, vel sim.?

**[Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) invented:** We need to write some liturgy for this:

- **SHa'on! Na, ELOKEINU, SHAo'n-NA!**
- **SHa'on! Na, BOR'EINU, SHAo'n-NA!**
- **SHa'on! Na, ME'ORER YESHENIM, SHAo'n-NA!**
- In the merit of Rebecca, who had to water all the camels *while still daylight*, give us more time!
- In the merit of Joshua, who kept the sun standing so the people could fight ... give us more time!
- In the merit of Nakdimon ben Gurion, who got the debts paid in time ... give us more time!
- In the merit of the manna, that would melt precisely at the hour that the sun, not the shade, was hot -- give us more time!
- In the merit of Rabbi Akiva, who lost his alarm clock [rooster] but accepted that God has a plan ... give us more time!
- In the merit of the Ashkenazim who thought that coffee was kitniyos ... give us more time!
- In the merit of Cain, to whom God granted a non-hour -- *lo sha'ah* -- give us more time!
- In the merit of Pharaoh, who said the Jews should not have a false hour -- *al yish'u bedivrei shaker* -- give us more time!

### [What are we supposed to do about losing an hour of Purim this year?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80329/what-are-we-supposed-to-do-about-losing-an-hour-of-purim-this-year) (2017)

**Isaac Moses fretted:** This year (5777/2017), those of us who live in the US<sup>4</sup> face a special conundrum: we will be moving the clocks forward *on Purim itself*! If I understand this correctly, that means that we're going to lose an hour of Purim, which seems to directly contradict the rule ["When Adar enters, Joy increases"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35180/time-parameters-of-mishenichnas-adar-marbin-bsimcha).

What modifications to the practices of Daylight Saving Time and/or Purim practices are recommended for resolving this conundrum?

**[Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) reassured:** No modifications are needed. The Sages already were aware of this issue and accounting for it was even incorporated in the original enactment of Purim, as it says in the Talmud ([Megillah 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=2&format=pdf)):

> בזמניהם" זמנים הרבה תקנו להם"
>   "In their times" ([Esther 9:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3309.htm#31)) -- multiple times were enacted for it.

It is thus perfectly [Lekhatchila](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/759) to celebrate Purim in multiple time systems.

**Isaac Moses satirized:** The Sages decreed that, in accordance with the rule of "כל הגורע - מוסיף" (["Whoever subtracts must add."](http://boards.fool.com/is-this-really-a-quote-from-the-talmud-26199447.aspx?sort=whole)), whenever we are forced to subtract an hour from Purim night, we must make it up by extending Purim day by an extra hour.

Later authorities recommended that we devote this extra hour to enhancing the true essences of the [four commandments of Purim](https://www.ou.org/holidays/purim/purim_mitzvot/), as follows:

- **Megillah**: Appoint a respected member of the community to stand next to the Reader and, using a stopwatch, strictly ensure that every call of the graggers fulfills the most stringent opinions for minimum duration. Make sure that he is empowered to call for a repeat gragging whenever the last gragging was questionable.
- **Mishteh (Meal)**: Spend your extra hour [pregaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pregaming) heavily, so that you can enter the Mitzva meal with the appropriate confusion between it and the banquet of Achashveirosh.
- **Mishloach Manot (Messenger Gifts)** : Two words: [שכר הליכה](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.12.28.2?with=all&lang=bi) (reimbursement for distance traveled). Ensure that your delivery route requires as many U-turns and backtracks as possible, preferably all within the most busy crossroads in the neighborhood. An app that helps design a maximally-complicated route is available thanks to a collaboration of the [Zomet Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zomet_Institute) and [UPS](https://www.forbes.com/sites/alexkonrad/2013/11/01/meet-orion-software-that-will-save-ups-millions-by-improving-drivers-routes/#71b599b54fc7).
- **Maseichot (Masks)**<sup>5</sup>: This year, ensure that not only every member of your family is dressed up consistently with the theme introduced in your Mishloach Manot, but dress up your pets, car, house, and nearby streetlights as well.

---

<sup>1. At least, everywhere where the relevant authorities have decreed that everyone needs to mess with their clocks twice a year.</sup>

<sup>2. The HNQ regularly features titles from Mi Yodeya that don't make any sense, but that's usually because half the words are some sort of lashon hakodesh. During Purim Torah season, the titles often seem off despite being in English.</sup>

<sup>3. We see here the power of marketing.  Surely nobody believes that any daylight is being *saved*; it is merely being *shifted*.  And that's important, because if you could actually *make* daylight, or save it away for later, you would be into the space of sorcery and you would be in trouble, because only HKBH creates light as we affirm every morning.  So even if they *are* actually saving daylight somehow, they should keep quiet about it to avoid dragging us into their evil magical ways.</sup>

<sup>4. OK, [Most of the US](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/us/arizona-no-dst.html).</sup>

<sup>5. In the times of the Temple, the fourth commandment was *Matanot Le-evyonim - Monetary Gifts to Poor People*. Nowadays, however, common practice is to not spend time on this commandment on Purim, and we observe Maseichot in its stead.</sup>

Comment: This is brilliant. *applause*

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, it's all CC-By-3.0-appropriated from people such as yourself. :)

Comment: I meant the idea of compiling it in the style of our publications. the content is great too, of course. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio "When you've got a hammer ..."

Answer (score 16):

I am Möoz and I wrote this next week.

Comment: I upvoted it last week.

Comment: @NogShine I will have upvoted it by the end of last week.

Comment: I upvoted it just after the votes were counted.

Comment: I upvoted it in all timelines but one.

Comment: Thanos is coming anyway :D

Comment: No, I am Muze! Vote for this Muze!

Comment: @Muze I'm _you_ from the future.

Comment: The future is now.

Comment: 7 days ago I saw this a day before 8 days later

Answer (score 16):

## StackOverClock

---

**Final Result**

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can download both models (v1 and v2) on [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3264845). I have also added a model of just the StackOverflow logo in case someone wants to print it.

---

Well, I finally [found some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag#comment1045449_318910), used some of my (disappointing) skills in 3D design and made something for this contest.

And here it is:

[image]

It's a 3d model of Stack Overflow logo with a (somewhat)clock on top that would be (hopefully!) printable.

A view of it in Simplify3d:

[image]

I still haven't tried to print it, but i will and promise to edit and upload some pics here if it finally gets a decent printing :)

Two more things:

- My initial thought was to make it functional by adding a clock kit on top. But I must first find one that meets my requirements, buy it, and change the design accordingly...
- Upload it to [Thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com) so anyone may download and print it at home.

Both points heavily rely on me fighting my procrastination powers, so I wouldn't bet on me,but who knows... :)

**EDIT 1**

Version 2.0, ready to accomodate an old clock I found at home.

[image]

**Edit 2**

Images of the first printed model. It's half the size the final model would be, and have some printing problems (should have printed it in another orientation) but makes a nice desktop piece :)

[image]

*Name of the project by @JackNavaRow,thanks for the idea!*

Answer (score 14):

What about an animated history of StackOverflow?
[image]
Link: https://bfontaine.net/so.gif

This is a gif showing the evolution of SO’s front page from the beginning to nowadays. I made it using Selenium, Python, Imagemagick and of course the awesome [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/) project. There’s roughly 5 weeks between frames except for some fetch errors (e.g. no CSS) I removed.

The code uses the WayBack Machine’s API to fetch snapshots URLs then opens them in Headless Chrome using Selenium and take a screenshot of each one of them.

Update: I wrote a [blog post](https://bfontaine.net/blog/2018/12/03/make-a-gif-of-a-websites-evolution/) explaining how I made the gif.

Update: also made one for [Google](https://bfontaine.net/google.gif) and one for [Twitter](https://bfontaine.net/twitter.gif).

Answer (score 13):

## Here's a stopwatch . . . for traveling near a black hole.

As you come closer and closer to a massive body, [time slows down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation). Anyone who's seen *Interstellar* may recall how drastic time dilation can be near, say, a black hole. So I made a stopwatch (based on [one written in Python 3 by Jorgen Cederberg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/124894-stopwatch-in-tkinter/)) that ticks at different speeds, representing an observer at a certain distance from a black hole.

You can pick the mass of the black hole, as well as the distance to it. Those are given in solar masses and astronomical units, respectively. Enter your chosen values, click the two "Set" buttons, and you're ready to go! As an example, if you set the mass to 15 solar masses (like the black hole in [Cygnus X-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygnus_X-1)) and set the distance to 0.0000004 astronomical units, time should pass slower by approximately a factor of 2.

Error handling to be added soon, because picking distances less than the Schwarzschild radius will obviously break the program. Other improvements to come, too, hopefully. Let me know if there are any absurd bugs.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import numpy as np

G = 6.674*10**(-11) #Newton's gravitational constant, SI units
c = 3*10**(8)       #Speed of light, m/s
m = 2*10**(30)      #Solar mass, kg
au = 1.5*10**(11)   #Astronomical unit, meters

class StopWatch(Frame):                                                    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.masses = IntVar()
        self.masses.set(0) # solar masses
        self.distance = IntVar()
        self.distance.set(4*10**(7)) # in astronomical units
        self.timestr = StringVar()

        self.start = Button(self.parent, text='Start', command=self.Start)
        self.start.grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        self.stop = Button(self.parent, text='Stop', command=self.Stop)
        self.stop.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        self.reset = Button(self.parent, text='Reset', command=self.Reset)
        self.reset.grid(row=2,column=3, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        self.quit = Button(self.parent, text='Quit', command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.grid(row=2,column=4, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        self.mass_label = Button(self.parent, text='Set mass of black hole:', command=self.ChangeMass)
        self.mass_label.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W+N+S)
        self.mass = Entry(self.parent)
        self.mass.grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=2)
        self.dist_label = Button(self.parent, text='Set distance to black hole:', command=self.ChangeDistance)
        self.dist_label.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2,stick=E+W+N+S)
        self.dist = Entry(self.parent)
        self.dist.grid(row=4,column=3,columnspan=2)
        self.makeWidgets()
    
    def factor(self):
        """The time dilation factor at a given distance from the black hole"""
        if self.distance.get() == 0:
            r = 4*10**(-7)
        else:
            r = float(self.distance.get())
        return np.sqrt(1-2*G*m*float(self.masses.get())/(au*r*c**2))

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """Set up the stopwatch."""
        self.l = Label(self.parent, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self.l.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=4)
    
    def _update(self): 
        """Update the displayed time."""
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)
    
    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths."""
        elap = elap*self.factor()
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))
        
    def Start(self):                                                     
        """Start the stopwatch, if not running."""
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        
    
    def Stop(self):                                    
        """Stop the stopwatch, if running."""
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0
    
    def Reset(self):                                  
        """Reset the stopwatch."""
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
    
    def ChangeMass(self):
        """Set the mass to the value inputted by the user."""
        self.masses.set(self.mass.get())
        
    def ChangeDistance(self):
        """Set the distance to the black hole to the value inputted by the user."""
        self.distance.set(self.dist.get())
        
root = Tk()
app = StopWatch(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Forgive me for asking what must seem a stupid question but why isn't there a run code snippet? I only see the code, not a stopwatch.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As far as I'm aware, [Python isn't supported by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-snippets/info).

Comment: Well, what can I do to see your timepiece? Is there a website I can use instead?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure what your options are; I'll look into it.

Comment: If you're interested in winning the prize, you had better hurry. Time waits for no man...I don't think I am the only person who cannot see your entry; even a screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

I hung up my clock on the wall. However, the clock then suffered a tragic malfunction, causing odd things to happen to time...

To fix this, I set out to build a replacement clock... or at least the shape of one. However, due to the odd time... things ended up a little strange. Here, it's probably best if you watch for yourself (links to YouTube when you click on the image):

[image: YouTube link]

---

I am very bad at video editing, so... blame me for bad things. Apparently, having a great camera doesn't stop you from videoing badly. All shot on my GoPro HERO7 black.

Answer (score 13):

### Sorry it took me such a long time...

So, I had trouble working out what I could do with the theme of time. Once I had an idea it took me a week to try it out. My first attempt failed so I had to spend another full week trying again.

**Without further ado - I grew cress to form the words 'Stack Exchange':**

[image]
<sub>(Click to watch the YouTube video)</sub>

---

## Process Breakdown

#### Failed Attempt 1

So the first one I tried I made in a large pyrex dish (I wasn't the most popular guy when I filled our best dish with compost) and buried the letters underneath the surface of the soil:
[image]

[image]

I mounted a GoPro on a Cymbal stand (because I haven't got a tripod apparently) and set it to take an image every 60 seconds:
[image]

Unfortunately, the cress seeds forced the letters up through the compost which meant you couldn't even tell what the cress had grow into:

[image]

So after 7 days growing this batch, and with the deadline fast approaching, I decided to go back to basics and grow it on kitchen paper instead.

#### Attempt 2

For the second attempt, I used less seeds and ensured that the paper was wet at all times. I know that the good folk from [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) may be upset that the letters aren't that evenly spaced and I'm using an upside-down V for an A and a sideways M for an E but it kind of works.

The final time-lapse consisted of 8,948 images totalling 19.5 GB.

## Some things I learnt:

- Use a more powerful lamp at night
- Too many seeds make the letters raise and twist (check out the video and watch the letter 'C' in 'Stack').
- It's incredibly easy to bump the camera and change the shot.
- If I didn't have a fixed focus camera it would have been easier to frame the shot better and get less table in.

Comment: This is pretty neat. I like that you've included the failed attempt - do you have a video of the first attempt? I'm sure it's a metaphor for something...

Answer (score 12):

`watch` time go faster*:

`watch -n 0.1 --precise date '+%Y-%m-%d\ %T.%N'`

*(New! Improved accuracy thanks to @DennisWilliamson! :)

Comment: add `--precise`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I read the manpage about `--precise` but I can't visually see the difference.  Can you see a difference?

Comment: You're likely to see the hundredths digit change very infrequently with `--precise` in this particular use. See also [this abuse of watch](https://serverfault.com/a/54720/1293).

Comment: Ah!  Now I understand.  The current explanation in the manpage is very confusing.  This should be in the manpage instead:  `--precise: Normally,  watch runs the command *after* interval seconds. This option makes each start of the command begin *on* the interval if possible.`  (based on the link you sent).

Comment: Downvoting in a friendly competition? Really?  That's not very nice. :(

Answer (score 12):

Four years and nine months ago (Feb, 2014), I posted something about time in Code Golf (**[link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20647/3755)**). It was an answer to a challenge for creating an analogue clock program (I am the author of [the question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20646/3755) too).

This is yet more timely because it happened a few years ago and is not bought back via the time-machine.

And, timely it used Java 8, which was the newest version at the time and it also bought new features to the language, some of them that I used.

I'll quote it here entirely:

> ## Java 8
>
> I made a clock that changes its colors accordingly to the hour of day,
>   showing local time. As the time passes, it will slowly change it
>   colors, using brighter colors at day and darker colors at night.
>
> The window is resizable and the clock will resize automatically to
>   whatever size you choose.
>
> Further, if the user adjusts the system clock or if a daylight time
>   change happens, the clock will automatically reflect that.
>
> There are two forms to run it:
>
> 1. Running the `ClockDemo` file, i.e. `java clock.ClockDemo`. This will open a window and you will see the clock there.
> 2. Running the `ClockSave` file, i.e. `java clock.ClockSave filename width height [HH:mm:ss]`. This will just save the clock in a PNG file
>      with the given file name, width and height. The clock will be draw
>      with the given time, or if that is omitted, with current time. For
>      example, if you run it as `java clock.ClockSave clock.png 600 500
>      12:38:24` it will save the clock in a 600x500 image in a `clock.png`
>      file and the clock will be showing 12:38:24 AM. Use hours in the 00-23
>      interval.
>
> ---
>
> ### Screenshots
>
> Here are some screenshots and generated files:
>
> #### 00:36:50 AM:
>
> [image: 00:36:50 AM]
>
> #### 02:38:51 AM:
>
> [image: 02:39:51 AM]
>
> #### 06:42:13 AM:
>
> [image: 06:42:13 AM]
>
> #### 11:15:28 AM:
>
> [image: 11:15:28 AM]
>
> #### 05:02:37 PM:
>
> [image: 05:02:37 PM]
>
> #### 07:11:30 PM:
>
> [image: 07:11:30 PM]
>
> #### 09:29:34 PM:
>
> [image: 09:29:34 PM]
>
> ---
>
> ### Source code
>
> I separated the source in five different files in a package called `clock`.
>
> Also available at [**GitHub**](https://github.com/victorwss/jclock).
>
> #### ClockDemo.java
>
> ```java
> package clock;
>
> import java.awt.EventQueue;
> import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
> import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
> import javax.swing.JFrame;
>
> public class ClockDemo {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         EventQueue.invokeLater(ClockDemo::runIt);
>     }
>
>     private static void runIt() {
>         final JFrame j = new JFrame();
>         j.setTitle("JClock");
>         final JClock clock = new JClock(new CoolPaint());
>
>         j.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
>             @Override
>             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
>                 clock.stop();
>                 j.dispose();
>             }
>         });
>
>         j.add(clock);
>         j.setBounds(20, 20, 600, 500);
>         j.setVisible(true);
>         clock.start();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### ClockSave.java
>
> ```java
> package clock;
>
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.time.LocalTime;
> import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
> import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
>
> public class ClockSave {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>         // Too much arguments.
>         if (args.length < 3 || args.length > 4) {
>             System.out.println("Bad usage: Should be java clock.ClockSave filename width height [HH:mm:ss]");
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // Parse the image size.
>         int h, w;
>         try {
>             w = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
>             h = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
>         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>             System.out.println("Bad usage: Should be java clock.ClockSave filename width height [HH:mm:ss]");
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // Parse the intended time.
>         LocalTime time;
>         if (args.length == 4) {
>             try {
>                 DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
>                 time = LocalTime.parse(args[3], df);
>             } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
>                 System.out.println("Bad usage: Should be java clock.ClockSave filename width height [HH:mm:ss]");
>                 return;
>             }
>         } else {
>             time = LocalTime.now();
>         }
>
>         // Save to an image.
>         try {
>             new CoolPaint().saveClock(w, h, time, args[0]);
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             System.out.println("Error on image output: " + e.getMessage());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### JClock.java
>
> ```java
> package clock;
>
> import java.awt.Graphics;
> import java.awt.Graphics2D;
> import java.time.LocalTime;
> import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
> import javax.swing.JComponent;
>
> public class JClock extends JComponent {
>     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>
>     private final CoolPaint paint;
>     private final Object lock;
>     private Thread updater;
>
>     public JClock(CoolPaint paint) {
>         this.paint = paint;
>         this.lock = new Object();
>     }
>
>     private void runClock() {
>         int lastTime = -1;
>         try {
>             while (isRunning()) {
>                 Thread.sleep(10);
>                 int t = time();
>                 if (t != lastTime) {
>                     lastTime = t;
>                     repaint();
>                 }
>             }
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             // Do nothing, the thread will die naturally.
>         }
>     }
>
>     private int time() {
>         return LocalTime.now().get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
>     }
>
>     private boolean isRunning() {
>         synchronized (lock) {
>             return updater == Thread.currentThread();
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void start() {
>         synchronized (lock) {
>             if (updater != null) return;
>             updater = new Thread(this::runClock);
>             updater.start();
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void stop() {
>         synchronized (lock) {
>             updater = null;
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
>         paint.paintClock(getWidth(), getHeight(), time(), (Graphics2D) g);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### ClockPaint.java
>
> ```java
> package clock;
>
> import java.awt.Graphics2D;
> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.time.LocalTime;
> import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
> import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
>
> public interface ClockPaint {
>
>     public void paintClock(int width, int height, int seconds, Graphics2D g2);
>
>     public default void paintClock(int width, int height, LocalTime time, Graphics2D g2) {
>         paintClock(width, height, time.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY), g2);
>     }
>
>     public default void paintClock(int width, int height, Graphics2D g2) {
>         paintClock(width, height, LocalTime.now(), g2);
>     }
>
>     public default void saveClock(int width, int height, String fileName) throws IOException {
>         saveClock(width, height, LocalTime.now(), fileName);
>     }
>
>     public default void saveClock(int width, int height, LocalTime time, String fileName) throws IOException {
>         saveClock(width, height, time.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY), fileName);
>     }
>
>     public default void saveClock(int width, int height, int seconds, String fileName) throws IOException {
>         BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
>         paintClock(width, height, seconds, (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics());
>         String f = fileName.endsWith(".png") ? fileName : fileName + ".png";
>         ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(f));
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### CoolPaint.java
>
> ```java
> package clock;
>
> import java.awt.BasicStroke;
> import java.awt.Color;
> import java.awt.Font;
> import java.awt.FontMetrics;
> import java.awt.GradientPaint;
> import java.awt.Graphics2D;
> import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
> import java.awt.RenderingHints;
> import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
> import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
>
> public class CoolPaint implements ClockPaint {
>
>     private static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
>     private static final int SECONDS_IN_HALF_HOUR = 30 * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
>     private static final int SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
>     private static final int SECONDS_IN_12_HOURS = 12 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
>
>     private static final int AM_0_00 = 0;
>     private static final int AM_3_00 = 3 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
>     private static final int AM_4_30 = 4 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR + SECONDS_IN_HALF_HOUR;
>     private static final int AM_7_30 = 7 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR + SECONDS_IN_HALF_HOUR;
>     private static final int AM_12_00 = 12 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
>     private static final int PM_4_30 = 16 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR + SECONDS_IN_HALF_HOUR;
>     private static final int PM_7_30 = 19 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR + SECONDS_IN_HALF_HOUR;
>     private static final int PM_9_00 = 21 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
>     private static final int PM_12_00 = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
>
>     private static final Color BLACK = new Color(0, 0, 0);
>     private static final Color DARK_GRAY = new Color(32, 32, 32);
>     private static final Color DARK_BLUE = new Color(0, 0, 128);
>     private static final Color PURPLE = new Color(128, 0, 128);
>     private static final Color CYAN = new Color(0, 255, 255);
>     private static final Color YELLOW = new Color(225, 225, 0);
>     private static final Color PALE_YELLOW = new Color(224, 224, 64);
>     private static final Color RED = new Color(255, 0, 0);
>     private static final Color GREEN = new Color(0, 255, 0);
>     private static final Color LIGHT_BLUE = new Color(128, 128, 255);
>     private static final Color SKY_CYAN = new Color(48, 224, 224);
>
>     private static final Color[] COLOR_CYCLE = {
>         DARK_GRAY, LIGHT_BLUE, RED, PALE_YELLOW, GREEN, SKY_CYAN, LIGHT_BLUE, DARK_GRAY
>     };
>
>     private static final int RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH = PM_12_00 / COLOR_CYCLE.length;
>     private static final String[] ROMAN = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII"};
>
>     private static class Painter {
>         private final int width;
>         private final int height;
>         private final int seconds;
>         private final int radius;
>         private final Graphics2D g2;
>         private final int cx;
>         private final int cy;
>         private final int secondColorIndex;
>         private final int secondsInPeriod;
>         private final Color pointersAndNumbersColor;
>
>         public Painter(int width, int height, int seconds, Graphics2D g2) {
>             this.width = width;
>             this.height = height;
>             this.seconds = seconds;
>             this.radius = Math.min(width / 2, height / 2);
>             this.cx = width / 2;
>             this.cy = height / 2;
>             this.g2 = g2;
>             g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
>             this.secondColorIndex = seconds / RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH;
>             this.secondsInPeriod = seconds % RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH;
>
>             int startIndex = (secondColorIndex + COLOR_CYCLE.length + 5) % COLOR_CYCLE.length;
>             int endIndex = (secondColorIndex + COLOR_CYCLE.length + 6) % COLOR_CYCLE.length;
>             Color color1 = COLOR_CYCLE[startIndex];
>             Color color2 = COLOR_CYCLE[endIndex];
>             this.pointersAndNumbersColor = mixColors(color1, color2, 0, RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH, secondsInPeriod);
>         }
>
>         private int mixColorComponent(int startComponent, int endComponent, double position) {
>             int difference = endComponent - startComponent;
>             return startComponent + (int) (difference * position);
>         }
>
>         private Color mixColors(Color startColor, Color endColor, int startTime, int endTime, int currentTime) {
>             double normalized = (currentTime - startTime) / (double) (endTime - startTime);
>             return new Color(
>                     mixColorComponent(startColor.getRed(), endColor.getRed(), normalized),
>                     mixColorComponent(startColor.getGreen(), endColor.getGreen(), normalized),
>                     mixColorComponent(startColor.getBlue(), endColor.getBlue(), normalized));
>         }
>
>         private Color upperBackgroundColor() {
>             if (seconds < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
>             if (seconds <= AM_3_00) return BLACK;
>             if (seconds <= AM_4_30) return mixColors(BLACK, DARK_BLUE, AM_3_00, AM_4_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= AM_7_30) return mixColors(DARK_BLUE, CYAN, AM_4_30, AM_7_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= AM_12_00) return CYAN;
>             if (seconds <= PM_4_30) return CYAN;
>             if (seconds <= PM_7_30) return mixColors(CYAN, DARK_BLUE, PM_4_30, PM_7_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_9_00) return mixColors(DARK_BLUE, BLACK, PM_7_30, PM_9_00, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_12_00) return BLACK;
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
>         }
>
>         private Color lowerBackgroundColor() {
>             if (seconds < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
>             if (seconds <= AM_3_00) return mixColors(BLACK, DARK_BLUE, AM_0_00, AM_3_00, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= AM_4_30) return mixColors(DARK_BLUE, PURPLE, AM_3_00, AM_4_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= AM_7_30) return mixColors(PURPLE, YELLOW, AM_4_30, AM_7_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= AM_12_00) return mixColors(YELLOW, CYAN, AM_7_30, AM_12_00, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_4_30) return mixColors(CYAN, YELLOW, AM_12_00, PM_4_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_7_30) return mixColors(YELLOW, PURPLE, PM_4_30, PM_7_30, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_9_00) return mixColors(PURPLE, DARK_BLUE, PM_7_30, PM_9_00, seconds);
>             if (seconds <= PM_12_00) return mixColors(DARK_BLUE, BLACK, PM_9_00, PM_12_00, seconds);
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
>         }
>
>         private void paintBackground() {
>             Point2D p1 = new Point2D.Double(width / 2, 0);
>             Point2D p2 = new Point2D.Double(width / 2, height);
>             g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(p1, upperBackgroundColor(), p2, lowerBackgroundColor()));
>             g2.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
>         }
>
>         private RadialGradientPaint colorOnCycle(Point2D center, float radius) {
>             Color baseColor1 = COLOR_CYCLE[(secondColorIndex + COLOR_CYCLE.length - 1) % COLOR_CYCLE.length];
>             Color baseColor2 = COLOR_CYCLE[secondColorIndex];
>             Color baseColor3 = COLOR_CYCLE[(secondColorIndex + COLOR_CYCLE.length + 1) % COLOR_CYCLE.length];
>             Color baseColor4 = COLOR_CYCLE[(secondColorIndex + COLOR_CYCLE.length + 2) % COLOR_CYCLE.length];
>
>             Color start = mixColors(baseColor1, baseColor2, 0, RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH, secondsInPeriod);
>             Color end = mixColors(baseColor3, baseColor4, 0, RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH, secondsInPeriod);
>             float index2 = (RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH - secondsInPeriod) / (float) RADIAL_PERIOD_LENGTH / 2;
>             float index3 = 0.5f + index2;
>             float[] positions = index3 == 1.0 ? new float[] {0.0f, index2, 1.0f}
>                     : new float[] {0.0f, index2, index3, 1.0f};
>             Color[] colors = index3 == 1.0 ? new Color[] {start, baseColor2, end}
>                     : new Color[] {start, baseColor2, baseColor3, end};
>
>             return new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, positions, colors);
>         }
>
>         private void paintClockArea() {
>             Point2D center = new Point2D.Double(width / 2, height / 2);
>             g2.setPaint(colorOnCycle(center, radius));
>             g2.fillOval(width / 2 - radius, height / 2 - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
>         }
>
>         private double pointerRevolutionsToRadians(double angle) {
>             return Math.toRadians((450 + angle * -360) % 360.0);
>         }
>
>         private void paintPointers() {
>             double hAngle = pointerRevolutionsToRadians(seconds % SECONDS_IN_12_HOURS / (double) SECONDS_IN_12_HOURS);
>             double mAngle = pointerRevolutionsToRadians(seconds % SECONDS_IN_HOUR / (double) SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
>             double sAngle = pointerRevolutionsToRadians(seconds % SECONDS_IN_MINUTE / (double) SECONDS_IN_MINUTE);
>
>             g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
>             g2.drawLine(cx, cy, (int) (cx + Math.cos(hAngle) * radius * 0.55), (int) (cy - Math.sin(hAngle) * radius * 0.55));
>             g2.drawLine(cx, cy, (int) (cx + Math.cos(mAngle) * radius * 0.85), (int) (cy - Math.sin(mAngle) * radius * 0.85));
>             g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
>             g2.drawLine(cx, cy, (int) (cx + Math.cos(sAngle) * radius * 0.85), (int) (cy - Math.sin(sAngle) * radius * 0.85));
>         }
>
>         private void paintNumbers() {
>             Font originalFont = g2.getFont();
>             double amplification = (int) Math.max(radius * 0.08, originalFont.getSize()) / (double) originalFont.getSize();
>             AffineTransform at0 = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(amplification, amplification);
>             Font amplifiedFont = originalFont.deriveFont(at0);
>             g2.setFont(amplifiedFont);
>             FontMetrics fm = g2.getFontMetrics();
>
>             for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
>                 double angle = pointerRevolutionsToRadians(i / 12.0);
>                 double textInclination = Math.toRadians(30 * i);
>                 AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(textInclination);
>                 at.scale(amplification, amplification);
>                 Font derivedFont = originalFont.deriveFont(at);
>                 g2.setFont(derivedFont);
>                 int pixelsOffset = fm.stringWidth(ROMAN[i]) / 2;
>                 int xPlot = (int) (cx + Math.cos(angle) * radius * 0.9 - pixelsOffset * Math.cos(textInclination));
>                 int yPlot = (int) (cy - Math.sin(angle) * radius * 0.9 - pixelsOffset * Math.sin(textInclination));
>                 g2.drawString(ROMAN[i], xPlot, yPlot);
>             }
>             g2.setFont(originalFont);
>         }
>
>         private void paintDots() {
>             for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
>                 if (i % 5 == 0) continue;
>                 double angle = pointerRevolutionsToRadians(i / 60.0);
>                 g2.fillRect((int) (cx + Math.cos(angle) * radius * 0.9) - 1, (int) (cy - Math.sin(angle) * radius * 0.9) - 1, 3, 3);
>             }
>         }
>
>         public void paintClock() {
>             paintBackground();
>             paintClockArea();
>
>             g2.setColor(pointersAndNumbersColor);
>             g2.setPaint(pointersAndNumbersColor);
>             paintNumbers();
>             paintDots();
>             paintPointers();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void paintClock(int width, int height, int seconds, Graphics2D g2) {
>         new Painter(width, height, seconds, g2).paintClock();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: +1 for mentioning java

Answer (score 11):

One of the big problems with time travel is navigation.  Even the very *best* time machines do not have the precision of a good Swiss timepiece.  After you land you can, at best, know when you are within 6-8 weeks -- and within 6-8 decades is more likely.  Those entry-level time machines you get at Target?  6-8 centuries -- you're better off staying at home until you can afford the proper tools!

Time travel is inherently uncertain -- so how do you know when you are?  We had a [question on Worldbuilding abut this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/62474/28), which I later [wrote about in our blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-am-i-dbc905e1ce7b), Universe Factory.  Sure, everybody says "use the stars", but do you know how to do that?  Have you ever used a sextant and a set of star charts?  Or are you going to hope for radio signals and that your laptop battery holds out long enough for you to map the sky?  (For long-distance time travel, by the way, you might be able to use the *moon*.  I learn all kinds of neat things on Worldbuilding.)

One thing's for sure, though: even small errors can be very dangerous, depending on when you're traveling to.  A song by Three Weird Sisters, based on a book by Connie Willis, illustrates this well; here's an amateur [recording of me performing it at a science-fiction convention](http://cellio.org/video/GownTooBlue.mp4).

Comment: So this is what 1254 looks like?

Comment: "One of the big problems with time travel is navigation..." I thought you were going to make this whole thing a joke about how left-nav is the missing key to making time travel possible.

Comment: @scohe001 oh, that would have been good!  I was focused more on the *when* and the *6-8 somethings* and missed that opportunity.

Answer (score 9):

A song, you say. I don't do lyrics. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

So I wrote a piano quintet instead.

Whodathunk that would so much *time*, I'd be way *too late* to the party.
But now that it's done I might as well post it anyway.

[image: YouTube video thumbnail]

MIDI synthesized with MuseScore. Sorry guys, but I definitely don't have anywhere enough time left to buy a cello and learn which way to hold it.

Comment: I almost thought you weren't going to do what I was expecting from the beginning, but patience paid off (2:43). :-)

Answer (score 8):

I thought I'd ask SE about this one like last *time*:

[image: Guilty Panda]

But *when* he couldn't help, I didn't have any *second* ideas...

Answer (score 8):

**Here's my freehand Time Machine**:

[image: Time Machine - Freehand]

Answer (score 8):

## So, a little bit about me, Stack Overflow, and *time*...

### • [3rd top all-time `datetime` tag answerer, with over 700 questions answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetime/topusers)

[image: screenshot]

### • [2nd top all-time `timezone` tag answerer, with over 1000 questions answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/topusers)

[image: screeenshot]

### • Helped author and/or curate the tag wikis for [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), [dst](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetime/info), and [date](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/date/info)

### • Authored some of the top rated, canonical answers in this category, including:

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/634824)
- [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/634824)
- [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824)
- [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824)
- [Difference between System.DateTime.Now and System.DateTime.Today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268210/634824)
- [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348822/634824)
- ... and many more

### • Outside of Stack Overflow:

- Contributed to [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) and [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), and champion on the [TC39 JavaScript Temporal proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)
- Authored the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter), [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames), and [GeoTimeZone](https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone) OSS libraries for .NET, and others
- Used my day job to influence Microsoft to [expand the list of available time zones in Windows and .NET](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dst2007/2016/06/02/introducing-new-windows-time-zones/) to cover all persons on the planet
- Went to numerous conference talks to teach other developers about best practices in date and time programming.  My favorites that were recorded were ["How to Have the Best Dates Ever!"](https://youtu.be/jMsqR_paQdA) and ["The Past, Present, and Future of JavaScript Date and Time APIs"](https://youtu.be/aVuor-VAWTI)
- Had this great shirt made, and wore it on stage at [CodeMash](http://www.codemash.org/) while talking about time zones and leap year bugs:
  [image: photo]
- [Live-blogged the world's leap year bugs on February 29th, 2016](https://codeofmatt.com/list-of-2016-leap-day-bugs/)
- Got my blog post, [*On the Timing of Time Zone Changes*](https://codeofmatt.com/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/) included in the guidance issued to the world's governments in [the IANA time zone database documentation](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html)
- Authored ["Date and Time Fundamentals" on Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals)
- Took my girlfriend (now fiancé) to a clock store  (yes, this is relevant) ...
  [image: photo]

But alas, when it boils down to *why* do I do all of these things, it's not for the fancy Internet points, or because I'm some kind of narcissist, but because of something Stack Overflow sums up quite nicely [in my user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson):

[image: Screenshot - Impact: 9.4m people reached]

### So, thank *you*, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

## A quick game using the fastest answers on Stack Exchange

I made a game using quick questions from English.SE, Movies&TV, or SciFi.

- Answer questions:
  [image: how to answer]
- You have 90 seconds to answer as many as you can - but you must answer faster than the actual question was answered!  [image: fast answers]
- All answers are short, usually single word. Either way, don't bother with spaces or punctuation.
- Click <kbd>↵Enter</kbd> to skip a question.
- Keyboard required.

### Click on **Run code snippet** to give it a try:

```css
html,body {height:100%;background:#ddd;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<iframe style="width:100%;height:97%;box-sizing:border-box;border:solid 1px gray;" src="https://kobikobi.gitlab.io/stackoverflowabouttime/"></iframe>
```

[source code](https://gitlab.com/kobikobi/stackoverflowabouttime) | [play without iframe](https://kobikobi.gitlab.io/stackoverflowabouttime/) |
[acknowledgement](https://gitlab.com/kobikobi/stackoverflowabouttime/blob/master/thanks.md)

Comment: Whoa... this is sure winner in "Time Spent vs. Chance to get Swag" category. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Well, I can only hope they won't consider only the votes, that sort of breaks down when you have >30 answers... 

Comment: I'm afraid they will, rules are rules... (but expect compensation in the form of shiny rep, when the time comes. ;))

Comment: A very late answer about fast answers... Have an upvote.

Comment: Oh no! I'm missing an 'e' in  "You've answerd {n} questions!" and I can only fix it in 10 hours...

Answer (score 6):

Once upon a time, on a n-sided<sup>1</sup> polygon world held up by a stack of stacks balanced on the top of a great unicorn<sup>2</sup>, flying around in outer space...

**Chris**: They've been at this for *weeks* now! Surely they must be finished whatever it is they're doing? What *are* they doing, anyway?

**A Tinkering Bell**: Sssh Chris, the Conjuring Magicians have finished redesigning a spell to go back in time for some reason - they didn't tell me what they'd use it for, but they just finished 24 and 52 seconds ago and they're now casting it, so we'll find out soon

**Chris**: Wait a moment, 24 *and* 52 seconds ago, how does that work?

**The Journeyman Geek:** Who knows? It's probably... Oh wait, they've vanished... Just days after leaving us to take care of this place. Ah.

---

*Exactly 365.25 years earlier, in a hot dessert:*

**Shog the ninth:** Tim! It's all your fault again. I *told* you, you said 'dessert' when you should have said 'desert'. *sighs at the typical-ness of the situation* Y'know, this reminds me of the time when I was a young lad...

*interrupting* **Tim:** Yes, that's right, it's always my fault. Maybe if you got some sand when it said 'something yellow' instead of some custard, we'd be over there, next to that massive pyramid, where we wanted to be, instead of next to this river of, well, custard.

**Catija:** Don't worry, it's only a narrow river of custard - we can run over.

*after wasting more time, the group successfully runs across the river of custard*

**Grace:** OK, that wasn't too bad now, was it? All we need to do now is touch the topstone...

*Grace reaches out to point towards the tiny shiny metal tip of the pyramid. In doing so, everything stretches, then* rotates *with a BOOM and flash of eniratco<sup>3</sup>

HELLO. I WASN'T EXPECTING TO SEE ANY OF YOU HERE FOR A FEW CENTURIES.

**Jon:** Oh dear, this wasn't supposed to happen, we must have done something else wrong. Maybe we were supposed to skydive towards the pyramid?

AHH, THE PYRAMID AGAIN WAS IT? NOTHING TO WORRY ABOUT. I'M TOLD THAT IT'S NOT VERY WELL MADE AND OCCASIONALLY CAUSES TIME TO ROTATE. YOU'LL BE HOME IN SIX AND SIMULTANEOUSLY, EIGHT WEEKS, IF TIME REMEMBERS TO RIGHT ITSELF. IT FORGOT LAST TIME, YOU SEE.

**Robert:** ?

YES, YOU HEARD ME RIGHT. IT'S PROBABLY QUANTUM. OR MAYBE RELATIVITY.

---

*Present day, in a (presently) relatively unfashionable arm of the Milky Way, on a planet called Earth:*

**Robert**, *reading a letter*: 'Don't travel back in time, it's not worth it.' signed Robert, 2028. What a strange letter. They've even managed to forge my signature.

---

<sup>1. for all n < [86400](https://www.google.com/search?q=number+of+seconds+in+a+day)</sup>

<sup>2. Postulated to be of the species *unicornis galactica*</sup>

<sup>3. Unlike octarine, eniratco is a very visible colour. Unfortunately, no-one has ever been able to determine anything about it, except that it exists<sup>4</sup></sup>

<sup>4. In theory, at certain times, at least</sup>

Answer (score 6):

[image: A fiery sun rising, with a plane rising above]

I took this soon after I first got my DSLR, and it has remained one of my favourite shots. It evokes a number of emotions each time I look it, and one of those is an awe of Time:

- A fiery sun rising in a wreath of clouds; marking a new day: The passage of the sun is where all timekeeping started.
- A puny little plane rising above it, ferrying around people in a rush: So many people worried about the passage of time.
- Time's own tricks: While I stood mesmerized by the scene, time passed by. By the time I could take a decent shot, the plane was well to the side, whereas I would have liked to see that rising plane right above that rising sun.
- A photo is an instant frozen in time. Ten years, twenty years, fifty years down the line, I would still like to look at my photos and take a trip back in time.
- Above all: It reminds me that some of your favourite photos are not so much about skill or technique, but about being at the right *time* and the right place.

Comment: Great photograph, muru. I'm one of those people who is always taking pictures of sunrises, sunsets, full moons, etc. :D This one is so nice I want to try to paint it!

Comment: @Bread if you do paint it, please do share! Those clouds around the sun would look so so beautiful when painted.

Answer (score 6):

## <s>Time</s> Thyme

[image: Thyme]

Comment: Clever.  You could expand, *Rosemary* **in** thyme.

Answer (score 6):

Argh! It's too late, a hundred particpants have submitted their entries before me. I think I should use a Time Machine and travel back in time and write something for the contest. Speaking of which, this reminds me of my good friend. (Not [Josh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317117/357396), another one).

Once upon a time, there lived a fun-loving programmer who was very fond of vintage artifacts and antiques (For the time being, let's call him Tinker). He had a huge collection of antiques comprising gramophone records, wall clocks, jars, carpets, and needless to say, also watches. He collected a lot of them. He loved visiting antique exhibitions and he traveled to many places in search of them.  Then one day, he came across an exhibition where vintage and antique watches from the late 19th century were being auctioned. He decided to participate and successfully bid for a pocketwatch complete with chain. It had a  weak lume but something was engraved underneath. When observed keenly, the instructions "*Handle with care. This side up*" could be read. Those lines didn't make much sense for Tinker. However, he was happy with his antique pocketwatch.

One evening, Tinker was sitting in his basement (his usual workplace, also plays Mine craft on his phone, keeps his keys and loses) holding his pocket watch. Tinker's 4 year old kid came there jumping in joy (kids are always happy.). He came and sat in his father's lap, played He played with his father. In this process, he pulled out the pocket watch and started playing with it. Tinker was watching it. He was mindful of the caution written on it to handle with care but little one's butter fingers... the watch slipped out of his hands and fell down. Tinker was shocked. He guessed the watch would shatter into pieces given that it is a century old. BUT much to his surprise, there was not even a scratch on the watch. He picked it up on the floor. It's as good as new. He threw it down intentionally this time. No change. If keeping it safe is not handling with care, then what is!?

Tinker observed it with his new glasses. The watch had a coating of [amorphous metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_metal). How on Earth could a hundred year old watch made of  It is a locket watch which can be opened into two halves. Under the clock, there's a tiny hidden chamber. There were some traces of letters. They were unclear when seen with glasses or magnifying glass. What to do next? Looked like some mystery puzzle for him. He watched some good old treasure hunt movies. When seen at specified angle under infrared glasses, tiny letters started appearing.

> *wend to a lodging whither thither art wild ducks and geese
>
>    Mice eating rotten cheese
>
>    Filled with dangerous bugs and (r)ants
>
>    Men like bots and robot like men
>
>    Teams of unicorns and ponies
>
>    taketh ten steps in a row
>
>    thee shalt reacheth a lodging whither everything overflow*

Tinker called his colleague Josh (also my good friend) to help him crack the puzzle. Both set on an adventure. They thought hard what the place could be. They wandered in forests, places where fantasy creatures are believed to be seen. Finally, they reached a special place in the woods. It was a dense forest that moon light couldn't touch the ground. But in the middle of the forest, at a very specific place, they found a flowing stream forming a waterfall from a hill which finally leads to a large pond. This place alone seemed very special apart from the whole forest. It is believed that fantasy creatures visit the place in special times of the year. They reached the pond. Took ten steps towards the waterfall. Voila, it was a secret den. Waterfall and creepers were covering it. They entered the  secret den and were eagerly waiting for something to happen.

> *During the dawn of the twilight,
>
>   at which hour the horologe is between 6-8
>
>   visage the travelling lamp and turn t right
>
>   thou shalt see a light
>
>   alloweth t glow and shine
>
>   doth not overturn, 'r thee shalt multiply into nine*

This time the watch was with Josh. He did as directed. A glow came from the watch. After turning the watch, wormhole opened which sucked them into it. There was a slight overturn and they reached a different dimension *R'lyeh*. It had much advanced civilization and technology. Everything on that dimension is similar like us but the technology was advanced and people are named in differently. Things happening there affect us too. Time passed very slowly there. *1 day = 6-8 weeks* (Unfortunately, our friends were not aware of it). Josh and Tinker visited Quack Overflow office and found out it was their anniversary. They saw different monuments in that dimension. After spending a couple of days there, they tried to turn the watch again and return back by taking help from citizens of R'lyeh. But that didn't work like before. When they checked, THERE WASN'T ONE JOSH BUT NINE. Tinker then understood the warning *Handle with care* on the watch. As the people there are named differently, Josh turned into Shog. There was only place for two to travel through the worm hole. If there was no overturn, the watch would take them back and forth in time. But this overturn made them go to other dimension. So, *Shog the ninth* and Tinker reached Earth safely and other Shogs were stuck in R'lyeh. The outlet opened in <s>Josh</s> Shog's Kitchen. Finally, they reached home safely. Both got new colourful diamonds along with that watch when they reached back home.

But that wasn't the end. The time on the Earth passed quickly than the dimension where both went. Hence, the tasks given to them went on as usual because changing past of someone will affect the future too and viceversa. People who remembered Josh started calling Shog9. The tasks given to Tinker like writing announcements and swag posts  for anniversary were pending as usual. After waiting, that was taken up by another employee JNat. He reached his basement just in time and [posted a comment under swag past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag?cb=1#comment1045444_318910) as if nothing happened:

> *Phew* - posted just in time!

---

So, I shall borrow this time turning watch from Tinker or Shog and go back into time. (Tinker still uses this watch to bring back his lost keys). Then write an answer to this question. See ya till then.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "It has a weak lume" Did you mean "It had a faint/worn out face" (clocks and watches have "faces")?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Lume is short for luminous fluorescent watches which glow in the dark. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lume Weaker lume means the numbers were not glowing when kept at dark.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, I don't mind the edits. The lume was there on an antique watch because the makers of the antique traveled in time and put lume later. That is why there is amorphous metal coating on the watch.

Answer (score 5):

*Time* flies! Let us not forget what [brought us this contest in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival) — Stack Overflow's 10th Anniversary!

### It's about *time* for Stack Overflow to be named *TIME* Magazine's **<s>Person</s> Website of the Year!**

So, introducing Stack Overflow's *TIME* cover ...

[image]

Comment: No free-hand underline?

Answer (score 5):

This is my *second* answer. This *time* I thought I'd take a *minute* to output a few graphs showing what *time* of the month/day/hour/minute people post the most on Stack Overflow.

**Month of the year<sup>1</sup>:**

[image: By Month]

[image: Animated by month per year]

**Day of the month:<sup>2</sup>**

[image]

**Day of the week:<sup>3</sup>**

[image]

**Hour of the day:<sup>4</sup>**

[image]

**Minute of the hour:<sup>5</sup>**

[image]

**Second of the minute:<sup>6</sup>**

[image]

If we take the highest points from all the graphs, we get March 19th at 2:59:08 PM on a Wednesday, which would next occur in 2020.  If we take the lowest points, we get December 31st at 2:07:35 AM on a Sunday, which would next occur in 2023.

You can run this query for any Stack Exchange site you wish [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/): Simply change MONTH to whatever date/time part you wish.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, posts.CreationDate) AS [Month], COUNT(*) AS ct
  FROM posts
  --WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, posts.CreationDate)
  ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH, posts.CreationDate) ASC
```

Remove the `--` before the WHERE if you want to see how your stats compare.

---

<sup>1</sup> I left out 2008 and 2018 in the animated version since there are not 12 months of data available.

<sup>2</sup> I would expect the 31st to have less, but why the 1st?

<sup>3</sup> It looks like some Stack Overflow users take a break on the week-ends.

<sup>4</sup> Who would have known - people still sleep at night; though I'm not sure why we should see this much difference due to time zones.

<sup>5</sup> I can't think of any very logical reason why people post less right after the hour strikes and somewhat after the half-hour either - perhaps they feel it is time to get back to work?

<sup>6</sup> This just looks messy - I guess it's what one should expect?  It's a variation of less than 1%, so we probably can't infer too much.

<sup>7</sup> You can blame the jQuery usage on the Data Stack Exchange team.

Answer (score 5):

To His Coy Asker

with apologies to [Andrew Marvell](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44688)

Had we but world enough and time,
This coyness, asker, were no crime.
I would sit down, and think which [Y](/q/66377/161792)
Thou meanst, and pass my editing eye.
Thou by the Indian Ganges’ side
Shouldst rubies find, then by the tide
Of downvotes wouldst complain. I would
Defend you e'en before the flood,
And you'd refuse — you're no milquetoast —
To edit or improve your post.
My tries to glean your intent 'd grow
Vaster than empires and more slow;
An hundred years should go to raise
The quality of turn of phrase;
Two hundred to adorn each clause
With comma, colon, other pause.
An age at least to every part,
And the last age should show your heart.
For, asker, you deserve this state,
Nor would I care at lower rate.

But at my back I always hear
Closers, deleters, hurrying near;
And yonder all before us lie
Deserts of vast /dev/nullity.
Thy question shall no more be found;
Nor, in its marble vault, shall sound
My emendations; then worms shall try
That long-preserved inclarity,
And your quaint honour turn to dust,
And all my efforts into rust;
The bitbucket's a gracious host,
But none, I think, do there read posts.

Now therefore, while the youthful hue
Sits on thy post like morning dew,
And while thy willing soul transpires
At every pore with instant fires,
Now improve your post while you may,
And now, like querying bird of prey,
Rather at once thy time devour
Than languish in his slow-chapped power.
Or, better, ask it first of all
So it for edits has no call,
And thus avoid voters' rough strife
And Stack Exchange's excising knife:
Thus, though we cannot make our sun
Stand still, yet we will make him run.

Answer (score 5):

[image: you don’t need that watch – when you can ask stackoverflow what time it is]

Comment: And it's not TB because the number of disctinct time in a day are well define! Just a question you want 5 or 6 significant figures for tenth of second? Do we have to handle timezone? Leap second?

Answer (score 4):

## My really not so real story from long long ago

**Disclaimer**: -"इस कहानी के सभी पात्र और घटनाएं काल्पनिक हो सकती हैं, यह किसी भी व्यक्ति, विदेशी, भूत या घटना से संबंधित हो सकती है या नहीं। अगर यह किसी भी व्यक्ति या गैर-व्यक्ति के लिए समान है, तो इसे चमत्कार कहा जाएगा।"

"All the characters and incidents of this story might be imaginary, it may or may not be related to any person, alien, ghost or incident. If it's similar to any person or non-person, then it will be called a miracle."

**Plot:** It was a stormy day when my girlfriend was going on a long drive with her ex-boyfriend turned best friend and I was enjoying tea with hot [Pakora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakora) and then somebody knocked and to my shock it was my girlfriend's ex-boyfriend's girlfriend. Her car broke down near my house and she wanted to make a call as her phone battery was down, she was calling his boyfriend for help but my girlfriend picked the call instead and said he is driving can't pick the call and she cut.

Then an idea struck in my mind on time that my neighbor is an expert in car repair and he can help. So we both went to his house with my polka-dot umbrella. But unluckily he was not there and it was his ex-wife's turn to take care of there kids Inu, Minu and Tinu. She told us to wait till she called ex-husband to check if he can come but then the doorbell rings an to our surprise her ex-byfriedn was there with a cricket bat, Inu and Minu started jumping to see him as he was there cricket coach too and his car also break down and he also came to get help from his ex-girlfriend's ex-husband. But her ex-husband didn't pick the call and we thought to play the game Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock and I was almost winning and the doorbell ring again and this time it was her ex-husband's ex-girlfriedn came to ask for sugar as she wanted to make tea. But they didn't have sugar so she came with me to my house to get sugar and Tinu also came with us to get the ball from my backyard.

I got my polka-dot umbrella and Tinu took his rainbow umbrella and we started towards my house but then she slipped on a banana peel Tinu was eating and she started crying in pain. Luckily doctor stay walking distance so we went there and to our surprise, her ex-husband and his new girlfriend were already having the party with the doctor and his son's boyfriend. He checked her and said it's nothing major just a small sprain, just take some rest and this painkiller. I and Tinu also stayed with her for a time being and then doctor's doorbell ring and it's none other than it was my girlfriend with her ex-boyfriend with a cricket bat.

We all were shocked what's even happening, she was sweating and had anger in her eyes and a cricket bat but on the other hand, her ex-boyfriend was calm, relaxed and smiling. Before we can ask then anything we see Doctor's son is back with his ex-boyfriend and told us all that my neighbor's house is on fire and my girlfriend's ex boyfiredn's girlfriend is stuck there with my neighbor's ex-boyfriend and everyone else escaped already.

Fire brigade comes and the Fire engine driver was none other than doctor's son's ex-boyfriend's brother and also the boyfriend of Inu, Minu and Tinu's babysitter. Inu started crying and he tries to comfort him and others safely evacuate my girlfriend's ex boyfiredn's girlfriend and my neighbor's ex-boyfriend. Suddenly Inu sees the bat in my girlfriend's hand to be the same bat there mother's ex-boyfriend and their coach brings a few minutes back but before he can say anything his father came and repaired car of my girlfriend's ex-boyfriend's girlfriend and then everybody also starts going back to there houses. My girlfriend also decided to stay at my house while his ex-boyfriend left with his girlfriend. I was trying to close the door but a cricket ball was coming between the door and I was not able to close it, I bend to remove it and see Tinu standing opposite to be shouting look behind.................

That was the first part of 10-part short story without any time traveling robots, sparkling vampires, and unicorns.

Thansk for your time.

Answer (score 4):

For a single moment in time, C++ had no questions for me to worry about:

[image: C++ tag page with 0 questions returned]

Alas, the moment was fleeting and all of the questions returned.

Answer (score 4):

### Mulletmobile

Recently I got this car. Yah, it's a 3rd Gen Camaro. Here's a picture of it:

[image]

It's red and sporty. Well, not so sporty right now, 'cause there's no engine in it. It's in various stages of disrepair around the garage. I mean, here's the rods and pistons:

[image]

And then there's the heads:

[image]

Over in the back is the block:

[image]

And the rest of the jumbled mess is out in front of the car itself:

[image]

There's still one part I need in order to get it put all together:

[image]

Yah, that's right ... a [Flux Capacitor](https://www.oreillyauto.com/flux-capacitor?q=flux%20capacitor). I've been waiting for-EVA for O'Reilly's to get it back in stock ... it's been on back order since ... well, since McFly had a Delorean! Yah, the cat's out of the bag ... I'm makin' me a Mulletmobile Time Machine ... you all are jealous now!

Yah, I still need to figure out the whole deal with my car not being stainless steel, but I'll get it ...

Comment: Just 3D-print the flux capacitor...

Answer (score 4):

## It's about *time* I wished Stack Overflow a Happy 10th Birthday!

It's pretty *time*﻿ly that this contest has appeared.  I had just enough *time* to put this together, because I'm salaried and I don't have to punch a *time*﻿card.  Otherwise my *time*﻿r surely would have gone off by now.

Stack Overflow, with its glittering up﻿*time*, has helped countless people, day﻿*time* or night﻿*time* -- any﻿*time*.  It's been a real *time*﻿saver.  Someone has a question, and usually, in a wibbly wobbly *time*﻿y wimey way, it gets answered.

Don't get too sen﻿*time*﻿ntal -- it's the users that *time* and again contribute that make Stack Overflow what it is.

[image: Time Magazine Honors Stack Overflow's 10 Years]

<sub>Now I'm going back to *watch*﻿ing the <kbd>java</kbd> tag.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

**And Now for Something Completely Different**

Here is my entry for this timely event. It's a simple poem-style riddle. Of course, the answer should be quite obvious in this context. Nevertheless, I hope you'll enjoy it!

Can you find all the puns and double meanings?

> The one I obey, my dear commander
>   Keep on running I will not slander
>   For I know you will follow my lead
>   Call me in if you are in need
>
> If one commands the other will follow
>   That's the deal, one has to swallow
>   Either way, I rely on you
>   We kiss goodnight and start anew
>
> Mighty Dictator of all places
>   followed by all human races
>   Watch over all the new born lives
>   earn the fruit of fertile strifes
>
> Endless love, you never disclaim
>   nor would you repel and never blame
>   Unbribable Protector, punish me
>   and I will follow tacitly

---

**Hint**

> Take your time

Answer (score 4):

Your mission should you choose to accept it is to name that movie. There is no time limit, and this message will not self destruct. Two words, separated by the line break.

Starting out obvious:

It passes, flies, crawls. First letter.
Balding chronologist that was a friend to the Great. 9th letter.
Rode the winged horse. 6th letter.
Born out of war, but a bit of a boar. 8th letter.
Bit of a drunk but always the life of the party. 5th letter.

Harold met Harald at Stamford and one man got emasculated. 6th letter.
Was he the old woman or was he the fly? It's Poetic Prose. 4th letter.
Fourth in line of land settled six by six. 6th letter.
The younger of Brother vs Brother. 4th letter.
Mayan midwife. 1st letter.
Chaotic but chromatic saltwater. 5th letter.
Patricide, complex relationship with his mother, first letter of his famous answer.

From that to this is a short leap.

_ _ _ _  /  _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago (**6 years**), I was dreaming to see the StackOverflow way to do Questions and Answers in my mother tongue, which is **Spanish**.

I found Area51 and went to propose it.

[image]

It took a very long time to get enough Spanish speakers to read things in English and fulfill the site requirements to see it start rolling.

[image]

Now it is not only alive and going well. It's the time the people can write programming questions and answers for Spanish speakers and the time to contribute and benefit from the huge knowledge base StackOverflow is called to be in any language.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

time to win some swag
hundred people got here first
now need time machine

Comment: Made it short since ain`t nobody got time to read all these answers >.<

Answer (score 3):

### Time Exchange

[image]

The clocks shown here represent my top SE sites and my routine and how they help.

[image]

10:00 is programming time. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

14:00 is meeting time. [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)

16:00 is (in the code) puzzles-solving time. [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

20:00 is movie time. [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

The worst thing about being Australian, is that once Tuesday comes around, you have to re-live everybody else's Monday. Like, come on, I just did this like yesterday!

**#UTC+10Problems**

Comment: UTC+12 felt your pain 2 hours ago...

Comment: But on the upside you get to use the interwebs to foist your case of the mundayz on to people who would otherwise be having a perfectly good weekend.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm just sitting there trying to come up with an idea for an answer, and then I got busy and forgot, and the contest deadline passed, and I missed out on my chance, as usual.

I both know that's how these things always go.
But good news! This one is about time, meaning that this letter from the future will help me out. I can't tell me who wins the contest, since sending this letter back to myself is a bit of a bootstrap paradox, but at least now I have a shot.

So good luck me!

P.S. DO NOT FORGET TO CLICK THE "POST YOUR ANSWER BUTTON THIS TIME". We only get to use this loophole so many times before the auditors catch on.

P.P.S. Stack exchange is trying to censor my attempts to alter the past by removing the salutation "Dear Me," from the beginning of this letter.

Answer (score 3):

You know how the holiday season is.  Far too busy.  I didn't really have time to put anything together for this contest until after the new year came.  So after the celebrations were done, I got to work building a time machine to go back to when the contest was still open.  It turns out building a time machine to send a person back in time takes more than a day, but I was able to make one that could send a post back in time to enter the contest.

So wish me luck!  Just kidding, I already know how many upvotes I get.

[image: Time is an illusion. Lunch time, doubly so!]

Comment: Tell us, does [Mueller](https://www.politico.com/news/trump-russia-scandal) release the findings of his investigation before the New Year?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd say, but I don't think you can use spoiler tags in comments, so I really shouldn't.

Comment: 121 to 105k in under a month -- that's some serious bounty-collecting!

Answer (score 3):

Ladies and Gentlemen, I am presenting you:

## The StackOverflow Time Machine

This machine allows you to go into the past and see the childhood of StackOverflow.

Easy to **use in 3 simple steps**:

1. Click on **Run Code Snippet**
2. Enter the past date in format **DD/MM/YYYY**. Once valid date is entered, time travel link will be copied into your clipboard.
3. Paste the link in new tab and GO, GO, GO!

Simple!

***Disclaimer: Use it at your own risk. If you or your dear one gets stuck in past using this time-machine, neither StackOverflow nor I will be responsible for your loss***

This is how the time machine looks:

[image]

This code uses https://web.archive.org/ for checking the past snapshot of StackOverflow.

```js
function digitalClock(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var session = "AM";
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    
    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("digital_clock").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("digital_clock").textContent = time;
    
    setTimeout(digitalClock, 1000);
    
}

function getDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth();
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

 // if(dd<10) {
 //     dd = '0'+dd
 // } 

 // if(mm<10) {
 //     mm = '0'+mm
 // } 

  today = monthNames[mm] + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
  document.getElementById("digital_date").innerText = today;
  document.getElementById("digital_date").textContent = today;
  
}

function getDDMMYYYY(dateString)
{
    // First check for the pattern
    if(!/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString))
        return false;

    // Parse the date parts to integers
    var parts = dateString.split("/");
    var day = parts[0];
    var month = parts[1];
    var year = parts[2];
    return [day, month, year];
};


function isValidDate(d, m, y)
{

// Parse the date parts to integers
    var day = parseInt(d, 10);
    var month = parseInt(m, 10);
    var year = parseInt(y, 10);

    // Check the ranges of month and year
    if(year < 1000 || year > 3000 || month == 0 || month > 12)
        return false;

    var monthLength = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];

    // Adjust for leap years
    if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0))
        monthLength[1] = 29;

    // Check the range of the day
    return day > 0 && day <= monthLength[month - 1];
};

function openInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    if (win) {
        //Browser has allowed it to be opened
        win.focus();
    } else {
        //Browser has blocked it
        alert('Please allow popups for this website');
    }
}
  
$(".error").hide();
$(".not_born").hide();
$(".future").hide();
$(".hhhh").hide();
 $("#go").hide();
digitalClock();
getDate();
$("#day_input" ).keyup(function() {
    $(".error").hide();
    $(".not_born").hide();
    $(".future").hide();
    
$(".hhhh").hide();
    
  var date_string = document.getElementById('day_input').value;
  
  var ddMMYYYY = getDDMMYYYY(date_string);
  if (ddMMYYYY === false) {
    $(".error").show();
 $("#go").hide();
    return;
  }
  
  var dd = ddMMYYYY[0],
      mm = ddMMYYYY[1],
      yyyy = ddMMYYYY[2];
  
  var valid_date = isValidDate(dd, mm, yyyy);
  if (valid_date === false) {
       $(".error").show();
 $("#go").hide();
       return;
  }

 // Format number in double digit precision
 dd = ("0" + dd).slice(-2);
 mm = ("0" + mm).slice(-2);

  if (yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd < '2008/09/15') {
  
    $(".not_born").show();
  }
  var today = new Date();
  var to_dd = today.getDate();
  var to_mm = today.getMonth();
  var to_yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd > to_yyyy+'/'+to_mm+'/'+to_dd) {
    $(".future").show();
 $("#go").hide();
 return;
  }
  
$(".hhhh").show();
  var url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/'+ yyyy + ''+ mm+''+dd+'000000/https://stackoverflow.com';
  var copyText = document.getElementById("hidden_input");
  
  copyText.value = url;
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  //console.log(url);
  //openInNewTab(url);
  $("#go").attr("href", url);
  //$("#go").show();
  
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #222426;
}

.current_time, .past_date {
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    font-family: Orbitron;
}
.heading {
    color: #bcbbbb;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.clock {
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;*/
    /*transform: translateX(-10%) translateY(-50%);*/
    color: #f48024;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
}

.question {
    font-size: 15px;
}

input {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.error, .not_born, .future {
    color: #f48024;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.date {
    display: inline-block;
}

.go_button {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    /*background: #bcbbbb;*/
    background: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.small_text {
   font-size: 15px;
   text-align: center;
}

.large_text {
   font-size: 22px;
   text-align: center;
}

.go_button {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="current_time">
    <div class="heading">Current Time: </div>
    <div id="digital_clock" class="clock value"></div>
  </div></br>
  <div class="current_time">
    <div class="heading">Current Date: </div>
    <div id="digital_date" class="clock value"></div>
  </div></br>
  <div class="heading question">
    Are you ready to time travel into the past of "StackOverflow"?
  </div></br>
  <div class="past_date">
    <div class="heading">Select date: </div>
    <div id="digital_clock" class="clock value">
      <div class="date"> 
        <input id="day_input" required pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" name="day" placeholder=" DD/MM/YYYY"/> 
      </div> 
      
    </div>
    <div class="error">Please enter a valid date in format (DD/MM/YYYY).</div>
    <div class="not_born">StackOverflow.com is not born yet. It is expected to born on 15 September, 2008. Please select date accordingly.</div>
    
    <div class="future">Hey! Sorry, but this time-machines doesn't allows to take the glimpse of future.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="past_date hhhh">
    <div class="heading">Time Travel Link: </div>
      <input type="text" value="" id="hidden_input" />
      </div>
    <a class="go_button" id="go"  target="_blank">
      <div class="text_container">
        <div class="small_text">Time Travel</div>
        <div class="large_text">GO</div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Review Queue Problems

[image: we have to go back to September 15, 2008 – in 6 to 8 weeks, those review queues will make the stacks overflow]

Answer (score 3):

Daffy: "Rabbit season!"

Bugs: "Duck season!"

"Rabbit!"

"Duck"

"Rabbit!"  Daffy points to the park-ranger sign.

Sign: "Rabbit season ends Dec 27.  Duck season begins Dec 28."

Bugs points to the same sign.  "Duck season!"

Daffy glances at his phone.  "Wait, what?  Oops!"

Daffy was last seen racing out of the frame at high speed.

Better luck next time, Daffy.

Answer (score 2):

If I had a time machine, I go look at my posts
See how they all hold up after you all turn to ghosts.
But what I am afraid would end up being the case
Is everything I've written is too old for first place
All of my links would end up leading to 404
And I would be updating my posts forevermore.
But the reputation gains would wind up being great.
It would be more than Jon Skeet's mil he had in one eight!

Comment: Can *almost* (but not quite) be sung to the tune of "Time in a Bottle"!!

Answer (score 2):

If you were in Israel when you posted this, I like your style--6:30 is definitely the best time, **hands down**.

I was thinking of posting a video of me eating a clock made of cheese to combine both challenges, but decided it'd probably be too time consuming.

Unfortunately my clocks were still hungry even after all the cheese from last time--they all went back four seconds!

You know, they say that if you listen closely to the the tick-tock of a clock, you may hear a secret message. Of course you'd only be hearing it second hand.

Answer (score 2):

I made a belt out of watches once. It was a complete waste of time.

Comment: "It was a complete _waist_ of time." - FTFY

Answer (score 2):

I wonder how would Time Overflow look like..... hmmmmmmmm..........

---

Time Overflow Logo:

[image]

timeoverflow.net:

[image]
P.S. If you go to timeoverflow.net you might get something like this (perhaps you're just not in the right time):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since StackOverflow is a programming site and the topic is about **time** I thought I'd programm a functional analog *watch* in Javascript:-) And **yes** it's the actual time :)

Originally it display the analog time in the console but the SO console was too *"small"* to display it properly so I created my own little console in HTML to show you.

The program is written in pure Javascript with no additional libraries. 
It uses the [*midpoint circle algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) to draw the circle and [*Bresenham's line algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to draw the pointers.
Further more it applies some basic trigonometry.

Now *watch* this and enjoy ;)

```js
const diameter = 30; // diameter of the watch
const factor = 2.6; // because characters are taller than they are wide
const width = diameter * factor; // grid width
const height = diameter; // grid height
const grid = new Array(diameter); // console grid the watch gets rendered into
const elem = document.getElementById("console");

// helpers for StackOverflow
console.clear = function() {
  elem.innerHTML = "";
}

console.log = function(line) {
  elem.innerHTML += line + "\n";
}

// clear the grid
function clear() {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        grid[y] = [];
        for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            grid[y].push(" ");
        }
    }
}

// render the grid
function render() {
    console.clear();
    for (let line of grid) {
        console.log(line.join(""));
    }
}

// draws a char at x, y, throws an error if out of bounds
function drawCharacter(x, y, char) {
    x = Math.round(x);
    y = Math.round(y);
    const msg = "Illegal arguments: x:" + x + ", y:" + y + ", char:" + char;
    if (y < 0 || grid.length < y) {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
    if (x < 0 || grid[y] === undefined || grid[y].length < x) {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
    if (char.length !== 1) {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }
    grid[y][x] = char;
}

// draw a circle using midpoint circle algorithm
function drawCircle(x0, y0, radius) {
    let x = radius - 1;
    let y = 0;
    let dx = 1;
    let dy = 1;
    let err = dx - (radius << 1);

    while (x >= y) {
        drawCharacter(x0 + x * factor, y0 + y, "+"); // 3 to 5 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 + y * factor, y0 + x, "+"); // 5 to 6 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 - y * factor, y0 + x, "+"); // 6 to 8 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 - x * factor, y0 + y, "+"); // 8 to 9 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 - x * factor, y0 - y, "+"); // 9 to 11 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 - y * factor, y0 - x, "+"); // 11 to 12 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 + y * factor, y0 - x, "+"); // 12 to 2 o'clock
        drawCharacter(x0 + x * factor, y0 - y, "+"); // 2 to 3 o'clock

        if (err <= 0) {
            y++;
            err += dy;
            dy += 2;
        }

        if (err > 0) {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += dx - (radius << 1);
        }

    }

}

// draw a line using Bresenham's line algorithm
function drawLine(xs, ys, xe, ye) {

    function lowLine(xs, ys, xe, ye) {
        let dx = xe - xs;
        let dy = ye - ys;

        let yi = 1;
        if (dy < 0) {
            yi = -1;
            dy = -dy;
        }

        let d = 2 * dy - dx;
        let y = ys;
        for (let x = xs; x <= xe; x = x + 1) {
            drawCharacter(x, y, "+");
            if (d > 0) {
                y = y + yi;
                d = d - 2 * dx;
            }
            d = d + 2 * dy;
        }
    }

    function highLine(xs, ys, xe, ye) {
        let dx = xe - xs;
        let dy = ye - ys;

        let xi = 1;
        if (dx < 0) {
            xi = -1;
            dx = -dx;
        }

        let d = 2 * dx - dy;
        let x = xs;
        for (let y = ys; y <= ye; ++y) {
            drawCharacter(x, y, "+");
            if (d > 0) {
                x = x + xi;
                d = d - 2 * dy;
            }
            d = d + 2 * dx;
        }
    }

    if(Math.abs(ye - ys) < Math.abs(xe - xs)) {
        if(xs > xe) {
            lowLine(xe, ye, xs, ys);
        } else {
            lowLine(xs, ys, xe, ye);
        }
    } else {
        if(ys > ye) {
            highLine(xe, ye, xs, ys);
        } else {
            highLine(xs, ys, xe, ye);
        }
    }

}

// convert degrees to radiens
function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

// calculate the slope based on an angle in degrees
function calculateSlope(angle) {
    angle -= 90;
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle = 360 + angle;
    }
    angle -= 180;
    angle *= -1;
    return Math.tan(toRadians(angle));
}

// calculate the width and height offsets of a line
function calculateLineEndOffsets(slope, len) {
    slope = Math.abs(slope);
    let width = len / Math.sqrt(slope * slope + 1);
    let height = width * slope;
    return [width * factor, height];
}

// draws the hour pointer
function drawHour(hour, x, y, len) {
    let slope = calculateSlope(360 / 12 * hour);
    let dimensions = calculateLineEndOffsets(slope, len);
    let xDir = hour > 6 ? -1 : 1;
    let yDir = hour < 3 || hour > 9 ? -1 : 1;
    drawLine(x, y, x + dimensions[0] * xDir, y + dimensions[1] * yDir);
}

// draws the minute pointer
function drawMin(min, x, y, len) {
    let slope = calculateSlope(360 / 60 * min);
    let dimensions = calculateLineEndOffsets(slope, len);
    let xDir = min > 30 ? -1 : 1;
    let yDir = min < 15 || min > 45 ? -1 : 1;
    drawLine(x, y, x + dimensions[0] * xDir, y + dimensions[1] * yDir);
}

// draws the second pointer
function drawSec(min, x, y, len) {
    let slope = calculateSlope(360 / 60 * min);
    let dimensions = calculateLineEndOffsets(slope, len);
    let xDir = min > 30 ? -1 : 1;
    let yDir = min < 15 || min > 45 ? -1 : 1;
    drawLine(x, y, x + dimensions[0] * xDir, y + dimensions[1] * yDir);
}

// draws all three time pointers
function drawTime(hour, min, sec, x, y, maxLen) {
    if(hour > 11) {
        hour = hour - 12;
    }
    const msg = "Illegal arguments: hour:" + hour + ", min:" + min;
    if (hour < 0 || hour > 11 || min < 0 || min > 59) {
        throw new Error(msg);
    }

    drawHour(hour, x, y, maxLen / 2);
    drawMin(min, x, y, maxLen / 5 * 4);
    drawSec(sec, x, y, maxLen);

}

// get current time and draw it
function work() {
    clear();
    drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, diameter / 2);
    let now = new Date();
    drawTime(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), width / 2, height / 2, diameter / 2 - 1);
    render();
}

// start program
setInterval(work, 1000);
```

```css
#console {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<pre id="console"><pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering how many ***Times*** [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag) was edited, until now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edited only 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

[image: This time of the year ...]

It is kind of funny how well behaved, fast and good-natured children are @ 6:30 am if the way to get to one of these is to be ready, breakfasted, and dressed till 7:15 *this time of the year*. Pity it is not a all-year-round deal :o)

Answer (score 2):

Brushing away the tree roots hanging from the ceiling I realised that the unicorn had stopped.

“I will not go further,” he said in his deep, rich voice, “you know the prophecy. There is only one who will be the hero, who will defeat Him who holds the Powers. There is only one who will pass through. I know not if these will be one man, or two. If you attempt the feat, there is no way back. You may find who you are if you tread the Way of Knowledge.”

The unicorn’s silver horn, glittering faintly in the now near-vanished light, pointed to the other end of the hall, blanketed in thick darkness. I glanced around quickly. I could see very little in the near-dark, but I could see the wall close by was of blank, black stone. I shivered. It was getting cold. I walked forward resolutely.

“I wish you good fortune.” came the unicorn’s voice. I looked back. I could no longer see his glimmering white coat. My nerves were now on edge. I could not know what to expect. Grasping the hilt of my still-sheathed sword, I wondered what my doom would be. Would I fail, and die, like others before me? What if I was the one who lived to make it through? Could I return a failure? I did not come with the hope of living, but to rescue my people from the One who tormented them.

> Time will come, for oppressor to fall,
>   Time to stand forth, the hero undaunted,
>   Time will reveal his name on the wall,
>   Time will be his, till doom accomplished.
>
> Do not be fooled, believing the lie,
>   Stars in the water, instead of the sky.
>
> Once foot is set in the Path of Knowledge there is no turning back. One alone shall survive, one alone shall destroy the evil for ever.

I mulled over the prophecy in my mind. The scholars who had trained me seemed to think that it would be revealed to anyone who walked in the Path of Wisdom whether he was the hero. I would soon find out.

Soon I felt the far end of the hall looming up black above me. I could not see anything, until a thread of blue light caught my eye. I looked, and saw a rectangle made of lines as fine as hair, the size of the door-way at the other end of the hall. I put my hand out, and it only met with more darkness. Yes, it was a doorway. I strode through. As I did so, I felt it close behind me. There was no going back. I drew my sword and walked slowly forward, touching the walls of the narrow passage from time to time to make sure they were still there.

Suddenly the walls ended, and I was in an open space. I stood still, wondering where I was, and what would happen next. Then in the dark I saw lines start to appear. I walked closer. The lines were moving and broadening, creating something. After a few seconds I could see writing and what seemed to be clocks. I watched for some time; the clocks moved at the same pace, but much faster than they ought! The times were also different. Then they suddenly stopped. This is what I saw:

[image: ![Black wall]

The inscription was plain, and in my mother tongue. It read: “Your time is running out. Can you read it?”

> *Time will reveal his name on the wall.*

**What is it?**

Answer (score 2):

Just a timer without scripts :) And you can pause it!

```css
span {
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}

#visible:checked ~ span {
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 15em 0;
}

#pause:checked ~ .t::after {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.t::after {
  content: "0\A 1\A 2\A 3\A 4\A 5\A 6\A 7\A 8\A 9";
  position: relative;
}

.t1s::after  { animation: digits10 10s   steps(10) infinite; }
.t10s::after { animation: digits6  60s   steps(6)  infinite; }
.t1m::after  { animation: digits10 600s  steps(10) infinite; }
.t10m::after { animation: digits6  3600s steps(6)  infinite; }

@keyframes digits10 { 0% { top: 0; } 100% { top: -15.0em; } }
@keyframes digits6  { 0% { top: 0; } 100% { top:  -9.0em; } }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="visible" /><label for="visible"> how it works?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="pause" /><label for="pause"> paused</label>
<br />
<span class="t t10m"></span>
<span class="t t1m"></span>
<span>:</span>
<span class="t t10s"></span>
<span class="t t1s"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

### For my submission:  A poem of epic<sub>mini</sub> proportions to rival the Illiad and the Odessy combined<sub>but not really</sub>

***Sing to me oh Thalia!***  [Muse of comedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalia_(Muse)), grant me a loquacious and jocular…keyboard as I regale the regal residents of this raucous and regimented repository with the tale of a heroic stack’s journey through time.  Our heroic stack is an eccentric, ephemeral yet elegant collection of a [motley crew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAZ60xA9wo) of the mad scientist make.  The hero’s journey has been long and fraught with villains and all kinds of vile and vicious vehemence.

Our journey begins in the back in the barbarous past, in the days of the [iPhone 6 and Galaxy Note 4](https://www.zdnet.com/article/best-10-smartphones-at-the-close-of-2014/).  Nearly five years ago, like the lights of the universe scattered across the void, the internet held a metaphorical mass of glowing and gravitationally grouped gas.  A proposal formed from this primordial ooze:  **Worldbuilding**.  It sprang into being, a dim but glorious and glittering light. A promise of hope and [335 ways](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse) (and counting) to destroy the world.

---

***But alas dear reader!*** The newborn light was ensnared by a cantankerous, capricious and…curvaceous <sub>(also sane and logical but that makes a *suuuuper* boring villain)</sub> [Cartaino.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino) The Dread  Pirate<sup>Space</sup> Robert(s) rode in, clad in his black robes on his black steed, nearly snuffing out the newborn star…er, world…building, whatever, he closed the proposal. This thing has entirely too many metaphors going on at once.

### VILLAINY!

[image: Artist's Rendering]

---

***Do not fear and do not weep!***  For brave (or perhaps obstinate) adventurers rose to right these wrongs.  They dared to challenge the Dread Pirate<sup>Space</sup> Robert(s). Prepared to fight to the death, they would shepherd the [8 pound 6 ounce tiny infant](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0415306/) ...site into the light.  They met on a field tan and blue and an epic, evocative battle unfolded amongst the...lets go back to **stars**. The adventurers and Dread Pirate<sup>Space</sup> Roberts clashed in a [deadly dance of...words.](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/how-exactly-is-worldbuilding-not-a-viable-proposal)

---

***Rejoice and give thanks!***  The light overcame its tribulations and exploded with effulgence.  [In the merry month of May,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merry_Month_of_May_(poem)) the queries began to roll in from users far and wide. 213 brave souls committed to the cause, braving the unknown, leaving the shores of surety and science for the fateful foggy waters of fiction and fantasy [(to be fair we do some science too)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)

---

***Recount, reminisce and remember!***  Then came September, [remember remember the …16th of September](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0434409/)...I guess. Anyway as September came to pass the intrepid adventurers began the daunting, dangerous and often perilous path of, I warn you reader the next bit is terrifying, **BETA**.  Beta was wild and west-y, full of aliens and swords, and aliens with swords.  Maybe a cowboy, I dunno it was a crazy crazy time full of *“what-if’s”* and probably some *“where-fore’s”* maybe even a *“whozit”* or two.  Despite the crazy, a site emerged full of wonder and woe (ok…a lot more woe if we’re honest).

*Quoth the blog:* [“and whatever the heck these awesome people are.”](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)

---

***Brilliance and*** [***Grace!***](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/grace-note)  They came to us little more than a year later.  A year of trials and tribulations and at least one question about [ritual cannibalism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/would-ritual-cannibalism-of-the-dead-lead-to-issues-with-disease) later, Grace spoke to us. From atop of the misty CM mountain cold doth exclaim: [***“Congratulations, Worldbuilding is graduating!”***](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/congratulations-worldbuilding-is-graduating)

***And it was good...***

---

***Dreary day o’ dreary world!***  But things were still amiss in who-ville…er on Worldbuilding. [(I watched How the Grinch Stole Christmas last night)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060345/?ref_=nv_sr_2) The site was a boring blue and white a desolate deserted dreamscape.  A new hero arose for a new time:  [Sir Kurtis of the Beaver.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13448/kurtis-beavers) Like a wizened wooly wizard he took a dash of sci-fi, a pinch of fantasy and a balloon whale and concocted a truly curious potion.  From this miraculous magical act were birthed a robot of regal renown!  The mighty [Slartibotfast, a stoic and steady defender,](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot) and by his side his intrepid ward; [Pandora a wanderer and learner](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?lq=1) exploring all there is to explore.  And thus the [Worldbuilding site design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design) came to be.

***And it was real, real good...***

---

*With apologies to anyone I referenced, the movies etc referenced, the Worldbuilding moderation team, Boris Karloff, the Worldbuilding community, anyone that took the time to read this…sorry you can’t have that time back and the Oxford comma.*

Comment: Seriously who is downvoting these?

Answer (score 1):

Time.  Time is a [tricky thing](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/a-date-with-a-parser), [sometimes](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Exceptional-Date-Formatting).  It shouldn't be.  It advances, at the rate of one second per second.  60 seconds a minute, 60 minutes an hour, 24 hours a day, 365 days a year.  Deceptively simple, it seems.  Not even Microsoft could get it right, back in the day.

Take, for example, the horrors of working with dates in MS Access.  Is it a string?  Access seems to be alright with it.  How about a Date?  Sure, why not?  But that's just basic data types.  Every language has those.  Here's where things go from reasonable to, "...what did I just see?"

See, Access has a Date type, like I mentioned.  It can also be used to instantiate a variable with today's date, ie. `Date()`.  Here's where the fun begins.  Date is *also* a system command that accepts a date.  Can you guess what it does?

[It sets the system time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604988/1197934).  So your code will compile, it'll all look okay, and when you run it...well, let's just hope your sanity is at an all time high that day.

---

There's another quirk of Access related to dates: your computer's regional settings determine how the default date format.  Everybody uses MM/DD/YYY?  No biggie.  You run an (*shudder*) enterprise Access application throughout the world?  Hoo boy.  Hope you don't use dates for anything.  Or for error handling. Or auditing, logging, or any of those other things that you take for granted.  Because now you have MM/DD/YYYY, the more sane DD/MM/YYYY, and I'm guessing everything in between.

---

Time.  It's a funny thing, sometimes.  But it can break the hardiest mind, given strange behaviour.

Comment: Topical, and educational, to boot!  Learn from my experiences!  Run!  Run from the horrors of Access!

Comment: As we all know, the only real date format is the YYYY-MM-DD, everything else is just historical baggage waiting to get thrown out once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from my favorite time-traveling series, I got a screenshot, then--through openly-available image editing resources (MSPaint and [this tool](https://www.vectorizer.io/))--turned it into a watercolor-esque piece or art.

### ORIGINAL

[image]

### MY ENTRY

[image]

Comment: That original image is likely under copyright protection... Watch out for emails from Universal Pictures...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'd call that a win in and of itself

Answer (score 1):

I still [remember it well](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-would-facebook-sysadmins-prevent-the-summoning-of-cthulhu). I got a call from the chief of staff that night, Mr M. Suckermountain.

"We need you to come in right away Chicken".

I had just worked an 18 hour shift, monitoring posts and collecting data about fighting in-laws.

I laid one last egg before brushing my feathers and walking out the front door. Once I arrived at the HQ there was utter chaos, colleagues muttering and shouting. I didn't hear much of it but the main theme was clear, CThulhu was ready to enter the world once more.

Vague flashbacks took me, I didn't want another taste of his immense power, not after the disaster in 1942.

Ideas were racing through my mind, stay calm chicken.. what's the best action to take in this case?

Me and my team knew there weren't a lot of options to choose from.. I'd have to use my Ultra Wing 30000-X to travel back in time and stop the researchers from reaching the forgotten manuscripts.

I called up my friend E. Musk, a valued chicken, telling him to meet at my place and strap up for some action.

Once back in the barn me and my companion put on our time suits and stepped into the 2 capsules used by the 30000.

> 3 .. 2 .. 1 .. ERROR!!!.

Surprised and blinded by the bright red led I had installed I took off my time suit, "Why can nothing ever work in a single try..grr" I muttered.

I stepped out of the capsule and went to check on the device. On checking the output log I saw the following:

> Cluck Cluck Tuck Tuck Cluck Cluck
>
> Cluck Cluck Chuck Chuck Cluck ...

AHA, NullPointerException at `ChickenLaunchSequenceFactoryGeneratorImplementationReally::Run()`. I knew I should've picked anything but Java-Chicken, this JRE is faulty.

One quick hotpatch later I got back into the capsule, put my suit back on and reinitialized the system.

> 3 .. 2 .. 1 .. BBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZT

A bright flash took over my vision and before I knew it I was back at the old ruins, standing eye to eye with the researchers that were looking at me and my friend, completely speechless.

Musk handed me my Cluckaroo-translation-machine and I started explaining to the researchers what they had done by retrieving those manuscripts. Still shocked, I used my Clucka 3.0 with Cluck-OS to show video footage of what happened in '42. They finally started trusting me and promised me they'd never enter these ruins again.

"Well that went better than expected" I said triumphantly to my buddy. He nodded and pointed back to the 30000-X, "lets get back home, I still need some milk before sunset".

SysAdmin Sombrero Chicken saved the day once again.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite crypto secure PRNG :

```
time(NULL);
```

Comment: It's only 32-64 bits of entropy at best.

Answer (score 1):

### I've always heard that Time and Space are two sides of the same coin...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('#coin').on('click', function(){
    var flipResult = Math.random();
    $('#coin').removeClass();
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(flipResult <= 0.5){
        $('#coin').addClass('heads');
        console.log('it\'s Time!');
      }
      else{
        $('#coin').addClass('tails');
        console.log('it\'s Space!');
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
#coin {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#coin div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
          border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 12px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 12px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 12px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.side-a {
  background-color: #dd0000;
}
.side-b {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:50px
}

#coin {
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#coin div {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.side-a {
  z-index: 100;
}
.side-b {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

img.h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img.t {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#coin.heads {
  -webkit-animation: flipHeads 3s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: flipHeads 3s ease-out forwards;
    -o-animation: flipHeads 3s ease-out forwards;
       animation: flipHeads 3s ease-out forwards;
}
#coin.tails {
  -webkit-animation: flipTails 3s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: flipTails 3s ease-out forwards;
    -o-animation: flipTails 3s ease-out forwards;
       animation: flipTails 3s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipHeads {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1800deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1800deg); transform: rotateY(1800deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipTails {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); -moz-transform: rotateY(0); transform: rotateY(0); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(1980deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(1980deg); transform: rotateY(1980deg); }
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="coin">
  <div class="side-a">
    <img class="h" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXCdO.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side-b">
    &blank;
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Click on coin to flip</h1>
```

<sup>Credit for most of the code goes to https://codepen.io/le0864/pen/pbmoVQ</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I created a **magical time estimation tool**.

Next time you need to know [how long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22how+long%22) something will take (for example if you win a nice new watch and want to know when it will arrive):

1. Run this snippet.
2. Click the `How long will it take?` button.
3. Get your answer!

```js
var _0x2195=['getElementById','innerText','classList','remove','hidden','6\x20weeks','7\x20weeks','8\x20weeks','floor','length'];(function(_0x157e03,_0x2139d2){var _0x45fc68=function(_0x385b9f){while(--_0x385b9f){_0x157e03['push'](_0x157e03['shift']());}};_0x45fc68(++_0x2139d2);}(_0x2195,0xb9));var _0x5ebf=function(_0x4366b4,_0x1c1e6d){_0x4366b4=_0x4366b4-0x0;var _0x49332d=_0x2195[_0x4366b4];return _0x49332d;};const times=[_0x5ebf('0x0'),_0x5ebf('0x1'),_0x5ebf('0x2')];function newTime(){var _0x5a92e6=times[Math[_0x5ebf('0x3')](Math['random']()*times[_0x5ebf('0x4')])];const _0x2af59a=document[_0x5ebf('0x5')]('time');_0x2af59a[_0x5ebf('0x6')]=_0x5a92e6;_0x2af59a[_0x5ebf('0x7')][_0x5ebf('0x8')](_0x5ebf('0x9'));}
```

```css
#time{border-left-width:thin;}div{font-size:48px;}div{text-align:center;}#time{border-bottom-width:thin;}div{margin-left:18.75pt;}div{margin-bottom:18.75pt;}#time{border-right-width:thin;}div{margin-right:18.75pt;}div{margin-top:18.75pt;}button{font-size:24px;}#time{border-top-width:thin;}button{padding-left:.3125pc;}button{padding-bottom:.3125pc;}#time{border-left-style:solid;}#time{border-bottom-style:solid;}button{padding-right:.3125pc;}button{padding-top:.3125pc;}button{border-radius:10px;}#time{border-right-style:solid;}#time{border-top-style:solid;}#time{border-left-color:red;}#time{border-bottom-color:red;}#time{border-right-color:red;}#time{border-top-color:red;}#time{border-image:none;}#time{border-radius:50%;}#time{overflow:hidden;}[class~=hidden]{display:none;}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="newTime();">How long will it take?</button></div><div id="time" class="hidden"></div>
```

This might also come in handy next time you need to estimate how long it'll take to write some code, but just make sure you keep [Hofstadter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law) in mind.

Comment: This isn't at all accurate. As a developer myself, I never *estimate* anything will take *6-8 weeks*. I always guess, "Meh. A few hours. Tops." and then get pushed into crunch mode three days later. Can you add *real-life* possibilities as well?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I've filed your feature request and will work hard to include it in version 2.0. Let me just estimate how long that will take...

Answer (score 1):

A Flash clock (I created this 5 years ago when Flash wasn't almost dead, and when I was 14)

@>>> https://github.com/iBug/FlashGadgets/tree/master/Clock

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBug/FlashGadgets/master/Clock/Clock.swf", "myContent", "640", "480", "8.0.0");</script>
<div id="myContent">
<p>Did you enable Flash? Alternatively, you can download the demo <a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBug/FlashGadgets/master/Clock/Clock.swf">here</a> and the source project (Flash 8) <a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBug/FlashGadgets/master/Clock/Clock.fla">here</a>.</p>
</div>
```

> [image]

You can find the project [here](https://github.com/iBug/FlashGadgets/tree/master/Clock).

```
var hr = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("hr",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
var min = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("min",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
var sec = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("sec",_root.getNextHighestDepth());

hr.lineStyle(10,0x0000FF);
hr.lineTo(0,-100);
min.lineStyle(7,0xFF0000);
min.lineTo(0,-160);
sec.lineStyle(5,0x00FF00);
sec.lineTo(0,-200);

hr._x = Stage.width/2;
hr._y = Stage.height/2;
min._x = Stage.width/2;
min._y = Stage.height/2;
sec._x = Stage.width/2;
sec._y = Stage.height/2;

_root.onEnterFrame = function(){
    var time:Date = new Date();
    sec._rotation = time.getSeconds()*6;
    min._rotation = time.getMinutes()*6+time.getSeconds()*0.1;
    hr._rotation = time.getHours()*30+time.getMinutes()*0.5+time.getSeconds()/120;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Build a time-machine (ok, it doesn’t *need* to be functional).

Here you go, a fully functional time machine and ...

[image]

... SEE, IT WORKS!

[image]

Comment: Not original, unless you work for Apple.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase the late, great, Lewis Carroll:

```
The time has come,' the Atwood said,
      To talk of many things:
Of waffles — and unicorns — and plural tags —
      Of upvotes — and flags —
And parsing HTML with regex —
      And whether Skeet is short for Skynet.'
```

Answer (score 1):

### They say: Time and Tide wait for none

Let's see whether it waits (or not)

<sup>**Disclaimer:** Original Code from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318929/244062.), which is eventually from [this snippet](https://codepen.io/jrg/pen/Cjrzx). However, the concept of this answer and the modifications are mine.</sup>

<sup>- Original code functionality: A watch, simple watch, displaying time</sup>

<sup>- My Modifications: To make it stop for "None" (pun intended)</sup>

**Instruction Manual:**

1. Run the code.
2. Move the cursor over the watch dial, it should change to "NONE".
3. Let's see whether time "waits" for the *"NONE"*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function watch() {
  // Get the time
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getHours() * 3600 +
         now.getMinutes() * 60 +
         now.getSeconds() * 1 +
         now.getMilliseconds() / 1000;

  // Change the time into degrees
  var hours = time / 60 / 12 * 6;
  var minutes = time / 60 * 6;
  var seconds = time * 6;
  var date = now.getDate();

  // Modify classes
  $('.hour').css('transform', 'rotate(' + hours + 'deg)');
  $('.minute').css('transform', 'rotate(' + minutes + 'deg)');
  $('.second').css('transform', 'rotate(' + seconds + 'deg)');
  $('.date').html(date);
 }
  
 var myVar = setInterval(watch, 50);
  
   $('.watch').on('mouseenter', function(){
      clearInterval(myVar);
   });

   $('.watch').on('mouseleave', function(){
      myVar = setInterval(watch, 50);
   });

});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background: #eee;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/* Website Header */
.header {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #999;
 margin: 50px;
}

/* Watch Container */
.watch-container {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

/* Watch */
.watch {
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
  cursor: url("https://i.postimg.cc/RV6fLt4T/cursor-yellow.png"), auto;
}

/* Watch Face */
.watch-face {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #3F484A; /* Dial colour */
 border: 10px solid silver; /* Face border */
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 
 /* Watch Face Outline */
 .watch-face-outline {}

 .watch-face-outline-point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #777;
  left: 145px;
  top: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 126px;
  transform-origin: 50% 126px;
 }

 .point-12 { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
 .point-1 { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); transform: rotate(30deg); }
 .point-2 { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); transform: rotate(60deg); }
 .point-3 { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform: rotate(90deg); }
 .point-4 { -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg); transform: rotate(120deg); }
 .point-5 { -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); transform: rotate(150deg); }
 .point-6 { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform: rotate(180deg); }
 .point-7 { -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg); transform: rotate(210deg); }
 .point-8 { -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg); transform: rotate(240deg); }
 .point-9 { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform: rotate(270deg); }
 .point-10 { -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg); transform: rotate(300deg); }
 .point-11 { -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg); transform: rotate(330deg); }

 /* Watch Face Date */
 .watch-face-date {
    position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  top: 138px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 27px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 300;
 }

 /* Watch Face Center */
 .watch-face-centre {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 144px;
  left: 144px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
 }

 .watch-face-centre-inner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #fa9f22;
 }

 /* Watch Face Hands */
 .watch-face-hands {}

 .watch-face-hand {
  position: absolute;
 }

 .watch-face-hand.hour {
  width: 4px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 90px;
  left: 148px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(306deg);
  transform: rotate(306deg);
 }

 .watch-face-hand.minute {
  width: 4px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 148px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
  transform: rotate(50deg);
 }
 
 .watch-face-hand.second {
  width: 2px;
  height: 145px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 149px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fa9f22;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 130px;
  transform-origin: 50% 130px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }

/* Watch Crown */
.watch-crown {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 15px;
 height: 26px;
 top: -163px;
 left: 295px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #999;
 border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Watch Straps */
.watch-strap-top {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 120px;
 height: 150px;
 left: 90px;
 bottom: -20px;
 background: #785734;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.watch-strap-bottom {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 120px;
 height: 150px;
 left: 90px;
 bottom: 20px;
 background: #785734;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 120px;
 text-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Website Footer */
.footer {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #999;
 margin: 50px;
}

.footer a {
 color: #999;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  Pure CSS Watch
 </div>

 <div class="watch-container">
  <div class="watch-strap-top"></div>

  <div class="watch">
   <div class="watch-face">
    <div class="watch-face-outline">
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-12"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-1"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-2"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-3"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-4"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-5"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-6"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-7"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-8"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-9"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-10"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-outline-point point-11"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="watch-face-date date"></div>

    <div class="watch-face-centre">
     <div class="watch-face-centre-inner"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="watch-face-hands">
     <div class="watch-face-hand hour"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-hand minute"></div>
     <div class="watch-face-hand second"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="watch-crown"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="watch-strap-bottom">James</div>
 </div>

 <div class="footer">
  &copy; 2018 <a href="http://jgrimshaw.com">James Grimshaw</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: @ArtOfCode This is copied from codepen and all public pens are MIT licensed, according to the website. I did not see any explicit license text...so I guess the default licensing terms are applicable...Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Let me find that for you..sure.

Comment: @ArtOfCode [I am referring to this one](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/private-pens/#private-licence).

Comment: @ArtOfCode No problem..and thanks for asking..I'll leave the comment with the link for others with same doubt. :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Done in *no time*, as you can see...
Will be improved within 6/8 weeks :D (or when I have time)

Answer (score 1):

Did someone just say *Time Machine* and *LEGO*?
This looks like a job for ..... ***Black Thunder*** !

[image: LEGO time machine]
**(The LEGO-Time Machine)**

<sup>*Made with LeoCAD
Rendered with Photoshop*</sup>

Comment: Again, on thread, together!

Comment: Time machine improved. Its matter of time. As the time passes, things improve,

Answer (score 1):

GO AHEAD, RUN ME

... And yes, it is all supposed to be exactly like that, especially the error message. ;-)

```js
      var a = [
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0VPaCUyMFllYWghJTNDJTJGcCUzRQ==",
                "SW4lMjBGcmFuY2UlMkMlMjBhJTIwYm9yZWQlMjBtYW4lMjByZWFkJTIwb2YlMjBhJTIwYnVnJTIwcmVsZWFzZWQlMjBpbiUyMGFuJTIwb25saW5lJTIwZ2FtZQ==",
                "QnklMjBjaGFuY2UlMjBoaXMlMjBnaXJsZnJpZW5kJTIwY2FtZSUyMGFjcm9zcyUyMGhpcyUyMGxhcHB5JTIwaXQlMjBzb29uJTIwd2VudCUyMHVwJTIwaW4lMjBmbGFtZXM=",
                "QXQlMjBob21lJTIwdGhlcmUlMjBhcmUlMjBzZXZlbnRlZW4teWVhci1vbGQlMjBib3lzJTIwYW5kJTIwdGhlaXIlMjBpZGVhJTIwb2YlMjBmdW4=",
                "SXMlMjBiZWluZyUyMGluJTIwYSUyMGdhbmclMjBjYWxsZWQlMjAnVGhlJTIwRGlzY2lwbGVzJw==",
                "U21hc2hpbmclMjB0aGUlMjBzdGFjayUyMGFuZCUyMHBva2luZyclMjB0aGUlMjBtYWNoaW5lJTIwUk9N",
                "VGltZSUyMC4uLi4=",
                "JTIwJTIwJTIwLi4uLiUyMFRpbWVz",
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtc2l6ZSUzQTU0JyUzRSVGMCU5RiU5NSU5MiUzQ3AlM0U=",
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtc2l6ZSUzQTc0JyUzRSUyMC4uLiUyMCVGMCU5RiU5NSU5MiUyMC4uLi4lMjAlM0MlMkZwJTNF",
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtc3R5bGUlM0ElMjBpdGFsaWMnJTNFLi4uJTIwVGltZSUyMGZsaWVzJTIwLi4uLi4uLi4uJUYwJTlGJTk1JThBJUVGJUI4JThGJTIwLiVGMCU5RiU5NSU5Mi4uJTIwJUYwJTlGJTk1JThBJUVGJUI4JThGJTIwLiVGMCU5RiU5NSU5Mi4uJUYwJTlGJTk1JThBJUVGJUI4JThGJTIwLiVGMCU5RiU5NSU5Mi4lMjAlMjAlRjAlOUYlOTUlOEElRUYlQjglOEYlMjAlMjAuLi4uLiUyMHdoZW4lMjB5b3UlMjBhcmUlMjBwcm9jcmFzdGluYXRpbmclMjAlMjAuLi4uJTIwVGhpcyUyMGhhcyUyMGJlZW4lMjBhJTIwJTIwZm9yJTIwdGhlJTIwbHVseiUyMHByb2R1Y3Rpb24lMjAuLi4lMjAlM0MlMkZwJTNF",
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtc2l6ZSUzQTU0cHQnJTNFJUYwJTlGJTk1JTkyJTNDcCUzRQ==",
                "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtc2l6ZSUzQTc0cHQnJTNFJUYwJTlGJTk1JTkyJTNDcCUzRQ==",
            "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0VBJTIwU2VhLW0lQzMlQjglQzMlQjhzZSUyMG9uY2UlMjBiaXQlMjBteSUyMHNpc3Rlci4uLiUyME5vJTIwcmVhbGxpISUyMCUyMCUzQyUyRnAlM0U=",
            "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0VTaGUlMjB3YXMlMjBLYXJ2aW5nJTIwaGVyJTIwaW5pdGlhbHMlMjBvbiUyMHRoZSUyMHNlYS1tJUMzJUI4JUMzJUI4c2UlMjB3aXRoJTIwdGhlJTIwc2hhcnBlbmVkJTIwZW5kJTIwb2YlMjBhbiUyMGludGVyc3BhY2UlMjB0JUMzJUI4JUMzJUI4dGhicnVzaCUzQ3AlM0U=",
            "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0UuLi4lMjBnaXZlbiUyMGhlciUyMGJ5JTIwU3ZlbmdlJTIwLSUyMGhlciUyMGJyb3RoZXItaW4tbGF3JTIwLSUyMGFuJTIwT3NsbyUyMGRlbnRpc3QlMjBhbmQlMjBzdGFyJTIwb2YlMjBtYW55JTIwTm9yd2VnaWFuJTIwbSVDMyVCOHZpZXMlM0ElM0MlMkZwJTNF",
            "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0UnVGhlJTIwSCVDMyVCOHQlMjBIYW5kcyUyMG9mJTIwYW4lMjBPc2xvJTIwRGVudGlzdCclMkMlMjAnRmlsbGluZ3MlMjBvZiUyMFBhc3Npb24nJTJDJTIwJ1RoZSUyMEh1Z2UlMjBNJUMzJUI4bGFycyUyMG9mJTIwSG9yc3QlMjBOb3JkZmluayclMjAlM0MlMkZwJTNF",
            "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0UuLi4lMjBXZSUyMGFwb2xvZ2lzZSUyMGZvciUyMHRoZSUyMGZhdWx0JTIwaW4lMjB0aGUlMjBzdWJ0aXRsZXMuJTIwVGhvc2UlMjByZXNwb25zaWJsZSUyMGhhdmUlMjBiZWVuJTIwc2Fja2VkLiUyMCUzQyUyRnAlM0U=",
            
                  "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0VCYWQlMjBEb2xwaGluISUzQyUyRnAlM0U=",
                  
                  "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0UuLi4lMjBTbyUyME1VQ0glMjB0aW1lJTIwISUzQyUyRnAlM0U=",
                  "JTNDcCUyMHN0eWxlJTNEJ2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0JTNBJTIwYm9sZCclM0UuLi4lMjBoYXMlMjBiZWVuJTIwd2FzdGVkJTIwJTIwISUzQyUyRnAlM0U="
               
            ];
            var b="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";
var i = 1;
var node = document.createElement('style');
node.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(atob(b));
document.body.appendChild(node);
for (let l of a)
{
    var t = decodeURIComponent(atob(l));
    var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.classList.add("box");
     p.style.top=Math.floor(Math.random()*150)+"px";
    p.innerHTML = t
    document.body.appendChild(p);

}
function dropLine() {
    p = document.body.children[i];
    i = i + 1;
    p.classList.add("go");
    window.setTimeout(dropLine, 5000);
}
dropLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If I see the clock, I find time in human terminology.
If I see life around me, I find there is no time just now.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Most people think time is like a river that flows swiftly and surely
>   in one direction. But I have seen the face of time and can tell you,
>   they are wrong. Time is an ocean in a storm. You may wonder who I am
>   and why I say this. Come, and I shall tell you a tale like none you
>   have ever heard...
>   *`Said A Prince`**(Guess who)***

```js
var date = new Date();
  
var hour = date.getHours();
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var second = date.getSeconds();

setHour();
setMinute();
setSecond();

setInterval(function() {
  date = new Date();
  
  hour = date.getHours();
  minute = date.getMinutes();
  second = date.getSeconds();
  
  $("span").removeClass("active");
  
  setHour();
  setMinute();
  setSecond();
}, 1000)

function setHour() {
  var tmpHour = hour;
  var i;
  
  for (i = 16; i >= 1; i -= i/2) {
    tmpHour = checkTime(tmpHour, i, "h");
  }
}

function setMinute() {
  var tmpMinute = minute;
  var i;
  
  for (i = 32; i >= 1; i -= i/2) {
    tmpMinute = checkTime(tmpMinute, i, "m");
  }
}

function setSecond() {
  var tmpSecond = second;
  var i;
  
  for (i = 32; i >= 1; i -= i/2) {
    tmpSecond = checkTime(tmpSecond, i, "s");
  }
}

function checkTime(tmp, number, time) {
  if (tmp - number >= 0) {
    $("." + time + "." + number + "").addClass("active");
    tmp -= number;
  }

  return tmp;
}

var card = $(".card");

$(document).on("mousemove",function(e) {  
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #00b6ff;
}

.div-m {
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.h {
  font-size: 34.5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.s {
  font-size: 39.5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

body {
  background: #edf2f4;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", georgia, serif;
}

.card {
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}
.card:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card .card-content {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card h1 {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: right;
}
.card p {
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  display: block;
}
.card p.related {
  transform: translateZ(80px);
  font-style: italic;
}
.card a {
  color: #69c6b8;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://upscore.ch/repo/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <h1 class="div-h">
      <span class="h 16"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
      <span class="h 8"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
      <span class="h 4"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
      <span class="h 2"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
      <span class="h 1"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span>
    </h1><h1 class="div-m">
      <span class="m 32"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="m 16"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="m 8"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="m 4"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="m 2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="m 1"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    </h1><h1 class="div-s">
      <span class="s 32"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
      <span class="s 16"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
      <span class="s 8"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
      <span class="s 4"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
      <span class="s 2"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
      <span class="s 1"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tick a tock!!! Tick tock! tick tock!

Answer (score 1):

Being in a timezone ahead of most people in the world +10 hours ahead (UTC+10) I am able to bring you news from the future.

[image]

Comment: Aussie eh?  still 2 hours after all the Kiwis :-P

Comment: @Criggie aye true! The kiwis rule. Beautiful place, awesome people and they're ahead of time :)

Answer (score 1):

Thought of it just before today's office meeting. :)

**Q: When should teams have ["all-hands meeting"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-all-hands-meeting)?**

A: At 12:00:00, sharp!!

<sup>**In the daytime</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I give you https://www.strava.com/clubs/181338/recent_activity  which is the Bicycles.SE  tracker for rides on Strava - shows right now that user:

```
Kirill k102
Yesterday at 17:39
"Herrshaft - Les 12 vertiges"
rode 16.08 km  in 58 m 46m 35s
```

And a good time was had by all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I was a little *short* of time. I was thinking what to do. It had to have a dog. It had to be about time. I was trying to build a doghouse time machine, but that's not what I ended up with

I didn't really notice any physical lego entries despite all this time, and I thought back to my time in secondary school where we had a cool clock tower. I grabbed whatever lego I had on hand, all black, since I didn't have time to dig up the rest and...

[image]

Its a doghouse clock tower. Its not much good at night, but how often does a dog need to tell the time at night?

Answer (score 1):

**A little slime rhyme**

```
Once upon a time
a little slime
started crawling around
and when it ate
it ate everything it found
and it grew up from the ground

It had no feelings
moved around under the ceilings
hunting from above
people
soon became its big love
eating them together with clove

And when it ate more
you could hear a roar
like a hungry beast
catching people
for a feast
it guzzled them til the least

Now it was so big
that people who saw it started to jig
everyone was screaming
but the slime
it was dreaming
of eternal redeeming

It ate so much 
soon there didn't exist such
that it could eat
until now
everything had been a treat
its size nothing could beat

And it started to starve
eating everything it could carve
but it didn't think
of the fact
that it was starting to shrink
and now there was not even anything to drink

Now when it was too late
aware of its fate
the slime just shrank
no one
but itself to thank
alone in its own rank

Once upon a time
a little slime
started crawling around
something to eat
it never more found
and it faded from the ground
```

*...with an undertone of the time we are currently living in.*

Comment: That's an "A for the effort", cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

**FameMedia Studios Enterprises LLC** proudly presents:

***"A brief story of time"***

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQqKnt07OGI

I finally made a YouTube video to fill the range of proposed submission formats. *And because I am a movie maker on the Hollywood level (as you will see).*

Please be sure to enable subtitles in order to understand everything. *I love my microphone.*

I hope, you find the time to watch my whole blockbuster and I hope you like it.

[image: A cat that steals your time by being sweet...]

Answer (score 1):

```html
__---~~~~--__                      __--~~~~---__
`\---~~~~~~~~\\                    //~~~~~~~~---/'  
  \/~~~~~~~~~\||                  ||/~~~~~~~~~\/ 
              `\\                //'
                `\\            //'
                  ||          ||      Hey Doc!
        ______--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~--______              
   ___ // _-~                        ~-_ \\ ___  
  `\__)\/~                              ~\/(__/'          
   _--`-___      | DEC | 04 | 1995 |    ___-'--_        
  /~     `\ ~~~~~~~~------------~~~~~~~~ /'     ~\        
 /|        `\                          /'        |\     
| `\   ______`\_         DMC        _/'______   /' |          
|   `\_~-_____\ ~-________________-~ /_____-~_/'   |  
`.     ~-__________________________________-~     .'       
`.      [_______/------|~~|------\_______]      .'
 `\--___((____)(________\/________)(____))___--/'           
  |>>>>>>||                            ||<<<<<<|
  `\<<<<</'                            `\>>>>>/' 



    __________________   __________________
.-/|                  \ /                  |\-.
||||                   |                   ||||
||||                   |       ~~*~~       ||||
||||    --==*==--      |     Javascript    ||||
||||                   |        the        ||||
||||                   |     Good Parts    ||||
||||                   |     --==*==--     ||||
||||                   |                   ||||
||||                   |                   ||||
||||                   |                   ||||
||||                   |                   ||||
||||__________________ | __________________||||
||/===================\|/===================\||
`--------------------~___~-------------------''
```

Answer (score 1):

[Based on widespread rumors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog), it is believed that the following function might be hidden somewhere in the vast plains of StackOverflow’s release system sourcecode:

```
function pushUpdate() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
            pushLive();
            console.log("Done!"); 
     }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 6) * 604800000);
}
```

What if, that sourcecode was put in there by ancient aliens? And what if it was made to protect us from the horrific terror that might come from instant updates and according gratefullness?

[image: ancient aliens]

Answer (score 1):

@SztupY's [Stack Overflow Wear OS Watch Face](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319326/178816) was really cool, although it required two things that wont work for me: the Wear OS Watch, and an app.

All I have is my iWatch (which I an enamored with). But I wanted a Stack Overflow face on it! So, I set out to see if it was possible. And it is! Yay, so stoked. I love Stack Overflow stuff. Even aside from this swag, I might just use this in general.

And you can too! This is a very easy process. All you need is your iPhone, an iWatch, and to be able to copy an image from imgur. Simple, right?

So there are several options I made for whichever type of alignment you might want for the image. The only text on the iWatch for this type of face is white, thus the images are all the logo with a black background. I had to travel back in time to change the path their SVG took in order to make them.

There is a...

- small logo only: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzXfI.jpg
- medium logo only: https://imgur.com/9JM1wAz
- large logo only: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQxIL.jpg
- Stack Overflow logo + name

  - top aligned: https://imgur.com/m6JqmN7
  - mid aligned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyAAa.jpg
  - bottom aligned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VqFy.jpg

All you need to do is...

- Copy one of those images to your phone.
  Just navigate to the imgur page with your phone's browser, then press and hold on the image, then select "Save Image".
- Then, open the watch app. Click on the "Face Gallery" tab at the bottom.
- Scroll to the "Photos" section. Click "Favorites".
- Click "Custom", "Choose Photos...". Select the Image from above you saved.
- Notice now that the preview is showing your Stack Overflow watch face.
- Select the Time Position (options are Top or Bottom). Select the bonus "Complications" for the watch face.
- Click "ADD" by the preview. Move your wrist to check the Stack Overflow time!

And just like that, you have a Stack Overflow iWatch face :D

[image]

So far, I think the top aligned logo + name is my favorite.

Comment: Lots of time spent of this one, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

### A small game

This is an attempt to recreate a scene from the movie Men In Black. There is a scene in which they fall from the pillar near the rocket and using time machine, they switch the region before touching ground.

**Note: Here, you're falling from sky and you've to survive by switching the regions before the counter at top right side reaches 100. You can simply click anywhere on the game area to switch region. This is a never ending game.**

> Note that we can't refund the time you're spending on this game.

```js
/*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75Sk.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3U7g.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/B833i.png
  */
alert("Game Starts in 10 seconds");
var next=1, img = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75Sk.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3U7g.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/B833i.png'],clicked=false;

function change(){
  document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.background = "url('"+img[next]+"')";
  next == 2? next=0 : next++;
}
function play(){
  document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.zoom = '100%';
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.zoom = (parseInt(document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.zoom) +1)+"%";
    
    document.querySelector('.position').innerHTML= parseInt((parseInt(document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.zoom)-100)/4);
    
    if(clicked){
        clicked=false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        change();
        play();
     }
     if(parseInt(document.querySelector('.fixed-div').style.zoom)>=500){
        alert("Go home!! You're dead");
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
  },100);
}
document.querySelector('.fixed-div').addEventListener('click',function(){clicked=true;});
setTimeout(play,10000);
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.fixed-div{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r75Sk.png');
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-position:center;
}
.position{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:90%;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:17;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-div"></div>
<div class="position">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its **time** for the *Summer smash*, well better known as *[Winter bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com)*!

If you are wondering what the odd little snowflake is in the top bar or are just new to SE, then you are in for some fun.

SE has a history every year around this *time* in December they start this event (called the winter bash) where users get "hats" for doing normal things across the network. Things such as a first post the gets at least 3 votes, or vote 150 times.

There are always *time* based hats.

Hats such as this years' [Glasses With A Number On Top](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/glasses-with-a-number-on-top). Be sure you are here in *time* for the winter solstice, and Christmas too. But do not worry *time* zones actually are a [help here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/278094), you get 26 hours. Now that is some extra *time*.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through these answers, I am finding myself struggling to focus on what it is the answer is talking about. So I decided it would be *time* to fix that... I present to you:

[image: Watch Design]

(Note the freehand red circle showing which part is the watch)

This watch would easily allow anyone to see exactly what time one is talking about, as shown by the freehand red circles over the hour and the minute, something that many people have *over time* become accustomed to.

It would also deter any pesky close votes that may try and hinder the telling of the time, as the red circles, in my opinion, are a *very* satisfactory MCVE.

Some facts about this watch:

- It uses jQuery to update the hands
- From my estimates, it would take around 6 to 8 weeks to make
- Every now and again, the hands will accidentally form into a giant S
- Sometimes, the watch will get up and start teaching about the time, occasionally yelling so loud that people's ears bleed (DHMIS reference)
- The watch is able to help burniation processes

But yeah, that's all I have *time* for, so happy 10th birthday, Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

## How to build a time machine

There are 2 steps to build a time machine:

1. Find instructions on how to build a time machine
2. Follow those instructions

Answer (score 1):

You Built a Time Machine Out of a ***JSFiddle Account***?

[image]

Of course I did! You can see my JSONp Ajax demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/fo7ndg0b/

Answer (score 0):

A timely joke:

**Q: Why did the old man throw his watch out of the window?**

*A: Because, he was bored and he wanted to see the time "fly"*.

---

Addition:

Since we already had the [ASCII-art for Big Ben](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318917/244062), why not ASCII art of the [probable swag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJL25.jpg), already?

```````````
                                                                      `:;;;;;;;;:::::::::,,`                                                     
                                                            `..`    ;'''''''''''''''''''++++++`                                                  
                                                         ,+''''''';'''''''''''''''''''+++++++++;  .:'''';`                                       
                                                       ,+++++''++''''+'''''''''''''''++++###+#'''''''+++++'                                      
                                                      '++++++++#'+''++''++''+'''''''+++#####+''''''+++++++++`                                    
                                                     ++++++++##'+++++++++++++++''+'++######+''''''+++++++++++`                                   
                                                    ++++++++##'++++++++++++++++'+'++#####+++'''''++++++++++++'                                   
                                                   ++++++++##++++++++++++++++++''++#####++'''''++++++++++++++';                                  
                                                  ++++++++##++++++++++++++++++'+'+######+'+++''+++++++++++++++'.                                 
                                                 '+++++++###++++++++++++++++++++++####+++++++++++++++++++++++++'                                 
                                                ,+++++++##+++++++++++++++++++++'+#####+++++++++++++++++++##+++++,                                
                                               ;++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'+##+''''+++++++++++++########++'                                
                                             `++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'++++++++#########+++.                               
                                             +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++###########++'                               
                                            :++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#############++`                              
                                            ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++##############++;                              
                                           +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++###############+'                              
                                          `++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++################++.                             
                                          ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++##################+;                             
                                         .++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++##################+'                             
                                       ` ++++++++++++++#############+++++++++++++++++++++++++++####################+.                            
                                     '+'#++######################################++++++++++++++####################+;                            
                                    +++################################################++#+++'#####################+'                            
                                   ++++@#############################@####################+++++'####################+`                           
                                  ,++++@@########@###@@###@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#@@#########+++++++###################+:                           
                                  ++++#@@@##@#####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@+++++++++##################+;                           
                                 '++++#@@@@@@#@@@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@+++++++++###################+.                          
                                `+++++#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#++++++++'###################+;                          
                                +++++##@@@@@@@@#@@#+;:::::::::::::'+##@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@++++++++++###################+'`                         
                               ;+++++#####@##@#;:::::::::::::::::::::::'+#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@++++++++++###################+';                         
                               ++++++##### ,::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::::::::'+#@@@@@@@@@@@++++++++++###################+++';,.                     
                              '+++++#####;:::::;;;;'+++++####+++';;;;;:::::::++@@@@@@@@#+++++++++++###################+++++++';,                 
                             `++++++###::::;;;;++######+##``;######++';;;;:::::'+`     ++++++++++++###################+##@#+++++:                
                             +++++++#:::;;;'+############``` ###+#######+;;;:::::++,   #++++++++++'###################+##@#+++++'                
                            `++++++::::;;+##+###+#+###.`#````'`;###########';;;::::#+: ++++++++++++#######################+++++++                
                            +++++;:::;;+#+###+########;`:+``#``##############';;:::::##++++++++++++######################++++++++                
                           `++++:::;;+####+#++#+#+####+``;#'``.+###############';;::::+++++++++++++######################++++++++                
                           +++;::;;+##,`#+++###';######...``` ####;'############+';::::;#+++++++++++####################+#+++++++`               
                          `++:::;'#+##``###+##+':#################`###############+;;::::#++++++++++####################+++++++++.               
                          ++::;;###`'##`:##+#+#####+';;;;;;;;;'+######`+########`;##;;::::++++++++++@@@@@@@@@@###########++++++++:               
                         `+::;'###```##; ######';;;'''''++++''';;;;'######,+###:`+###';;:::+++++++++@@@@@@@@@@@##@@########++++++;               
                         '::;+#####'`#+#;+##';;'''+###########++##+';;'###`####`,#####+;;:::'+++++++#@@@@@@@@@@@#@#######++#+++++'               
                        .::;#####++#`,####;'''+#######@@@#############';;#####``#######+;;:::'#+++++######################+#++++#+               
                       .:;;#####+###'###;'''######@@@@#####':+;:++######+;;##'`#########+;;:::'++++++#####################+#+++#++               
                      `:;;#+#+++++####;;''#####@@@+###'+++';:+;.++++'+++##+;'#############;;:::+++++'########################++#++               
                     `:;;###+#####+#+;''#####@@@##++++:';::;;+'.+;';:;++;++#';###.:#######+;;:::++++'##########################+++               
                     ::;#+#########;''+####@@@@+#++;;'++++,:'+'.++++;:+++++++#;'#;#########+;;:::+''+##########################+++`              
                    ;;;###+++'++##;''####@@'###;';++++####.:''',+##++++;:;;:+++;;###########+;::::+'''@@#########@@###########++#+,              
                   ::;+###+##`##+;'+@##@@@##;#++++#####+++`,';;:++#####+++:++;'++;##.`#######';:::;+''###@######@@@###########++#+:              
                  .:;++#+++++##'''+##@@@+@#,::++###+++++++`,'::;++++++###++++.,'++;#+#########;;:::++''@@#@####@@@@@#@########+#++;              
                  :;;++#++++##'''####@@@@#+''.++++++++++++.,',:'++++++++###+`:;++++;###########;;:::+'''#@@####@@@@@@@@#########++;              
                 :;;##+++#++#'''###@@@@##:++`,:+++++++++++.,'.,'+++++++++++';.;++:++;##,;######';:::;+''#@@#####@@@@@@#########++#'              
                .:;#;`.+#+##+''####@@###'+##;;`++++++++###,.'`,'##+++++++++.,+++;++++;#,########;;:::++''@######@@@@@@#########+##'              
                :;'#`;` #+#+''###@@@@#;++##++`,'+++#######:.+`,'#####+++++.;,'+#+;'':''#########+;;:::+''+########@@@#########++#+'              
               ,;;#.;++`:##;'###@@#@#'++##+++,;++#########..+`,'########++,,;++##+;;++;##########;;:::+'''#######################++`             
               :;++.`,+.##;'+###@@@;'++#+++++++#;########################++.++++##+;+++:#:`#######;;:::+''+#####################+++`             
              :;;+:+:` ;#'''###@@@#+++#++++++#'+,:######################:;#++++++##+::'+'#########';:::+'''#####################+#+.             
              :;++``#+;##;'###@@+#+++#++++++##:+'+#####################'#':#++++++##+,++;#####:``##;;:::+'+####################++#+,             
             :;;#'```;+#;'+###@@@;++#++++++####'########################+::###+++++##+;;+;##,``.###;;:::+'+'######@@###########+#++,             
             :;++++#`.#+''###@@@#++#++++++################################+####+++++#++;+;#+`,#####+;:::''+'#####@@@#@#########+#++`             
            ,;;+++++#+#;'###@####+##+++++#######################################+++++#+:++;#########;;:::+''+####@@@##@#########++;              
            ;;+++++++#'''##@@#+'`'++++++#############:##########################+++++##+++:#########';:::+++'####@@@##@@########+'`              
           `;;#++++++#;'###@@@#.:`,++++#############::;##+#######################+++++#+:`;;##+######;:::'+++####@@@@@@@#######++,               
           :;;++++++#'''#@@@@@#+`:,.'+#############:';:;;#';#;'#:#+;##############++++;`;:.;#`.######;;:::+++'###@@@@@@########+;                
           ;;+++++++#;'###@@+++++`.,'+:############++:'#+'+;#;##++''###############+.,,:.';++########';:::#++'####@@@@#########+`                
          `;;#+++++#+''###@@@++#++::++#,####+#####+#+:'#+:#'#+;##:#'#############+.:,',;;+++;########+;;::+++++################:                 
          :;;++++`;#;'+##@@@#'+#++++#''####+,`#+####+'##+#+++#'+''';###########+.:,,,#'++++;:#########;;::;+++'###############'                  
          ;;+++++#+#;'##@@+##+##+++++':####`,,.'####+++#########+##+########++.,,,,++#++##+'++,`@#####;;:::++++##############+:                  
          ;;#+++++++''#@@@@@;+#++++########`,,,,:#+#####################+#++.,,,,:+'#++++#+:''########;;:::#+++##############+`                  
         .;;++++++#''#@#@@@#+##++++####+####`,,,,.###+##################++.,,.,,##;##++++#+:;:########';:::#++++#############+`                  
         :;'++++++#;'###@@@++#++++#########+#`,,,,`###++############++++.,,..,'+@####++++##';;########+;:::++++'###########++',                  
         ;;+++++++#;'###@+';+#++++########+#+#`,,...'#+#########++++#+.,,..,,+########++++#+''#:.######;;::'++++@#######@@#++':                  
         ;;++++++++''##@@@#'##++++###########+#`,...,:##++#+#####+#+.,,...,'+#########++++#+;+#:'######;;::'++++########@##++';                  
         ;;#+++++#''+##@@@#+#++++############++#`,...,,#++++.###++.,,...,,'###########++++#+:++########;;::;++++########@##++''                  
        `;;++++++#;'###@@@++#++++#####+##+#+###+#`,...,.+#+:`###...:....'#############++++#+:+'########;;:;;++++########@##++''                  
        .;;+.```+#;'###@@+;+#++++###############++`,...,:'+`'#,....'.,.+##############++++#+;+'########;;:;;++#+###########++''`                 
        ,;;#`.``'#;'###@@#++#++++####++++#++####+++`,..,;,;`+`.....:.'################++++##'+;+`######;;:;;######+'#####@#++'',                 
        :;'#:+,;+#;'###@@#+++++++####++#+++++###++++`,.`:;,,'......:#########+#########+++##'';########;;:;;#@####++'####@##++':                 
        :;'+`.;,+#;'###@#+```````..++###+#+##++++#+++```,.`;`....,#####################++++#++;########;;:;;#####++++#@@@@##+++:                 
        :;'+``+,+#;'##@@+';::::,,,,++#+##########+#+++`...,,....+###################''++++++++;########;;;;'#####+#+++@@@@@#+++;                 
        ;;'++++++#;'##@@##:,...````####+######+++###++:...,...;####################'``````````'#````.##;;:;'@######+++#@##@@#++'                 
        ;;'++++++#;'##@@@#+#++++#+#####++###++###+++++....,;.+:####################;.,,,,,,,,,'+`````##;;:;'@######+++@@##@@#++'`                
        ;;'++++++#;'##@@+'+##+++####+++##+####++++++#......:,.,####################+::,,...```+########;;:;'@@#####+'+#@###@##++,                
        :;'++++++#;'##@@@#+##+++########++#######+##',,..++````####+##################++++++++#########;;:;'@######+++@####@@#++:                
        :;'++++++#;'###@@#'##++++#####+++#####++++##+#+#`##:,.``######################++++#++'#########;;:;+@####+#++#######@##+;                
        :;;++++++#;'##@@@#;+#++++#######################,#############################++++#+::#`.#####+;;;;+@######++#######@##+'                
        ,;;++++++#;'###@'';+#++++##++#++#++++#####++###;+#############################++++#+':########';;;;#@######+'########@#+'                
        .;;++++++#;'###@@#;+#++++##+########+#########+`+#############################++++#++;########;;;;;########++########@#+'                
        `;;+++++`#''+##@@#++#++++######++++##+#####+##+:#############################++++#+;++########;;;;;#######++#########@#+'                
        `;;#+++++++;+##@@@#+##+++####+#+##+#########++:##############################++++#+:;#`:######;;;;;#+##@@##############+'                
         ;;+++++++#;'##@@+#'+#++++##+++++############+`+#############################++++#++:##+#####+;;;;'++#+@@###############'                
         ;;'++++++#;'###@@#;+#++++#,:###+############+;#############################++++##;++########';;;;#++++@################'                
         :;;++++++#';+##@@#++#+++++,++#+++########+++,##############################++++#+,;#########;;;;:#++++#################'                
         .;;+++++++#;'##@@#;++++,,+++:###+########';;.;'#'++++++################+,#+++++#++:#:#######;;;;;#++++#################'                
          ;;+++++++#;'##@@@#++'`:,'+,++#+#########+''';'#'::;''';+#############',:#++++#+,++#`######';;:;++++++#############+##+:                
          ;;'++++++#;;+##@@#+.,:.`'+#############+#+,##;':::;#################+#+#+`:+##++:#########;;;;:#++++##############+#+,                 
          :;;+++++#+#;'##@@#`;,`'++++#++++######++++.+#+'++':##################+;+,,`:'++'+########+;;;;:#++++##############'.                   
          `;;#++++`,#;;+##@+'`'+#++++####++#++###+#++############################+`:,:`:+:#;#######';;;;'+++++##############:                    
           ;;'++``;,##;'##@@#+++#+++++####+#++###++.##############++############+++..,,`:+#`'######;;;;:#++++@##############,                    
           :;;+..;+#:#;;+##@##++##++++++#+#########,###############+###########+++++'`:,:#########';;;;;++++'#@############+.                    
           `;;+':# `;++;'##@@'+;+##+++++###++##+##++##########+###############+++++##+,,#+,#######;;:;;#++++###############+`                    
            ;;;+``.+++#;;+##@@#+;+#++++++###:+++++.+###############+#########+++++##+++;#```;`###';;;;:++++'###############+                     
            ,;;#+:+++++#;'##@@#++++#+++++++',;#++#:##################+#+##+#+++++##+:,:##`#'``###;;;;;#++++################'                     
             ;;'+++++++#';'##@@++;++#+++++++''+++'#################+#;,:#++++++++#+;+;### #+``;#';;;;:#+++'################'                     
             :;;#+++++++#:;+##@@++:+##++++,++:#+#.+######+##########''#:#+++++++#+'++'###`;`+##+;;;;:#++++#################;                     
              ;;;++++++++#:;##@@#++:+##+++.,++###:######+#++#########:+++++++++#+'+;;#####`.###;;;;;:++++'#################:                     
              :;;++++++++++;'##@@#'+:++#+`:`++++'#######`,;+####++###++:.++++##+'++:##########+;;;;:#++++#################+.                     
               ;;;++++++;.+';'##@@#++:++;:,;++++.+#####+`,;+#######+++':,+++##+:++:###########;;:;:'++++'#################+`                     
               ,;;'+#+++++++';'##@@#+'++`,,+++++;+#+++++`,'++++++++++++`,,+#++,+;:###########';;;;:#++++##################+                      
                ;;;#+++++++++';'##@@'++,;`'##++'++#+++++.,'++++++++++++':,+++'++:###########';;;;:#+++++##################'                      
                `;;;##+++++++#';;##@@#+,:;++###+++++++++.,'+++++++++++#+`,,++:';#,.########+;;;;;'+++++###################;                      
                 ,;;;#++++++++++;;#####:.++;+++###++++++,.'+++++++++###+';.++;'###;########;;;;;:#+++++###################:                      
                  ;;;'+#+++++++++:;+##@#+++++:+++#####++,.'++++#####+++++ ,::+############;;;;;:#++++'###################+.                      
                   ;;;++#++++++`#+;;;##@#+;+++::'++++##+:.+#####++++;:'++;:;#############;;;;;:#+++++@###################+`                      
                   :;;;+##+++++'`;++:;'##@#+++++++;:'+++:`++++++':::+++'':+#############;;;;;;++++++#####################'                       
                    ';;;+#++++++#`.+#'::'####++++;+++;+';`++:'+++++:++':'#'############;;;;;;+#+++++#####################;                       
                    #;;;;++#+++:``'+++#':;'####++'+++++';`++;+++++++':+#+``###########;;;;;;+#+++++######################:                       
                    '+';;;'#+#``;+#++#+##+::;'+##+++++++;`++;++++':;+##``+#+########+;;;;;;+#++++'######################+.                       
                    `##';;;'##`+++++#+#+###+';::;;+++++++++++;::;+#####,`; `.######';;;;;;+#+++++#######################+`                       
                     ###';;;;##++++##++##+`####++;;:::::::;;'+##########`,#:`#####';;;;;'###+++++#######################'                        
                     +###+;;;;+###++######'###################:;##########+``###+;;;;;;'####++++########################;                        
                     .####+;;;;'##################,`  .########;#########``:###';;;;;;'####+++++@#@####################+:                        
                      ######;;;;;+################.`#####################+###';;;;;;;+#####+++++@######################+.                        
                      +######';;;;;+##############````+####################+;;;;;;;'#######++++########################+                         
                      .########;;;;;;+############``#.`##################';;;;;;;'+########++++########################'                         
                       #######@#+;;;;;;'##########``+``###############+;;;;;;;;;'#########+++++########################:                         
                       +######@@##';;;;;;;'+#######:,,+############+;;;;;;;;;;'###########++++########################+.                         
                       .######@@##';+;;;;;;;;;'+###############+';;;;;;;;;;;'#############++++########################+`                         
                        ##########'  :+';;;;;;;;;;;;;;'''';';;;;;;;;;;;;;'+###############+++'########################'                          
                        +#########+    .++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;'+##################++++#######################+:                          
                        `#########+`....``,#+';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;'+######@###.`########++++########################+.                          
                         ######@@########@@@@@###+'';;;;;;;;;'++#######@@@@#,   `########++++########################+                           
                         :#####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#@@@@@###############@@@@@@'.       ########++++########################;                           
                          #####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#'########+++########################+,                           
                          +####@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@########+++@#@#####################+`                           
                          .####@@##@#@##@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#######++++@@@#####################'                            
                           ####@############@###@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#######++++########################:                            
                           ,###@################@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#######+++########################+`                            
                            ###########################@####@#@@#@##@@@@@@#@@#@#@@######++'########################+                             
                             +##@###############################################@@######+++########################;                             
                               ,+################################################@#####+++########################+.                             
                                 ################################################@#####++'########################+                              
                                 ;#####################################################+++#######################+;                              
                                 `###############################################################################+.                              
                                  ###################################################+##########################+'                               
                                  ###################################################+##########################+;                               
                                  :#############################################################################+`                               
                                  `#################################################+##########################+'                                
                                   ###################################################+########################+,                                
                                   '###############################################+##+#######################++                                 
                                    ################################################++########################+;                                 
                                    `###############################################+##+#####################++`                                 
                                     ;##############################################+##+#####################+'                                  
                                      #################################################+####################++.                                  
                                      ########@#########################################+###################+'                                   
                                      .#######@#########################################+##################++,                                   
                                       ########@######################################+#+################+++'                                    
                                       ,#######@#########################@###############+################++,                                    
                                        ########@########################################+##############++++                                     
                                        .################################################++#############+++.                                     
                                         +#######@########################################++++######++++++'                                      
                                          ########@#######################################++++++++###+++++                                       
                                          .##############################################+#++++++++++++++,                                       
                                           ;#############################################+#++++++++++++++                                        
                                            ;###############################################++++++++++++                                         
                                             :#########+##################################++#++++++++++`                                         
                                              `+++++++##++################################++++++++++++,                                          
                                                `;+++++++++#########################++#####++++++++++:                                           
                                                          '++++++++++++++++##########++++##+++++++++,                                            
                                                           `'++++++++++++++++#########+++++++++++++`                                             
                                                              `,;''++++++++++++######+:  .;+++++'.                                               
                                                                         ``.,:;''+';.
```````````

Comment: You should totally drop copying me and try jQuery :P Looks like yours came out a decent bit better than mine though.

Comment: @Chair I'm just "inspired" by your answer, that's it. Moreover just to say, the first version of your answer is better than the second one. :)

Comment: The world took a hit with automated ASCII art production. No love or style any more, [except here](https://asciiart.website//)

Comment: @Chair I took your suggestion and [made this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319041/244062). It is worthy? Mostly re-used code, started jQuery yesterday. :)

Answer (score 0):

> It’s time for the holidays. Are you tired of the same old holiday season? Me, too! So I invented a holiday just for us: **Question and Answer Time**. If you like it, you can celebrate all year long! See [Weasel Stomping Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k76IGLi6jWI) by Weird Al Yankovic for sing along music.

```
**Question and Answer Time**

Unicorns are filled with code.
I won a cheese board. Lightens my load.
Don’t you know it’s Question and Answer Time?

Turn your thinking lightbulb on.
Answer questions until dawn.
Here we are at Question and Answer Time!

All programming girls and boys
ask their questions. Lots of noise!
You’ll know how to do your part
when you supply an answer or break their hearts.

So join me now and have a laugh.
Think of Question and Answer Times past - 
a tradition that deserves its cheese and wine.

Hey, everyone! It’s Question and Answer Time!
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle this from a different perspective.

For some time now I've been working on a DB-like service that lets you query the state at any point in time. I mean, it keeps the whole history of each and every object. Currently there's only one implementation, based on event sourcing with MongoDB, but there's more to come.

I suppose it's sorta advertisement for my pet project, but it's still related to the topic, so here goes: let me introduce you to [Vent](https://github.com/filipmalczak/vent).

Answer (score 0):

I had just posted [this very timely code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176647/convert-an-excel-date-code-to-a-date?noredirect=1#comment425344_176647) when I noticed this post in the *Featured on Meta* side bar. Look there for details and make sure to read the comments too for background info.

[image: Excel nonsense]

Answer (score 0):

A low-hanging fruit, perhaps.

Sung to [Pink Floyd - Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwYX52BP2Sk):

> Closing away the questions that make up a dull day
>   Fritter and waste the votes in an offhand way.
>   Kicking around on mediocrity in your top tag
>   Waiting for someone or something to show you the way.
>   Tired of sitting on the front page staying still to see new posts.
>   You are young and rep is high and there is posts to close today.
>   And then one day you find ten years have got behind you.
>   No one told you how to ask, you missed the starting guide.
>   So you ask and you ask to catch up with the Jon but he's rising
>   Rising up to come up below you again.
>   The Skeet is the same in a relative way but you're no closer,
>   Shorter of rep and one day closer to ban.
>   Every post is getting longer never seem to find the time.
>   Posts that either come to naught or dozen pages of scribbled lines
>   Hanging on in loud desperation is the Meta way
>   The time is gone, the site is over,
>   Thought I'd something more to say.
>   Flag
>   Flag again
>   I like to flag stuff
>   When I can
>   When I go flag
>   Cold and tired
>   It's good to be marked helpful
>   Beside the rubbish
>   Far away
>   Across the site
>   Tolling of the review queue
>   Calls the faithful to keyboards
>   To see the badly written Q&A's

Answer (score 0):

Time is a difficult concept, sometimes a confusing concept, especially in **Javascript**.

For example, someone thought it was a good idea to make months start with a 0.

```
new Date(2018, 6) //Fri Jun 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

The Date constructor also allows you to pass the timezone! This sounds excellent except when it doesn't recognise it and will just default to the Local time without any sort of error.

```
new Date('July 20, 2018 12:00:00 (CET)') // Sun Jul 20 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

So you can parse dates different ways and Javascript really tries it's best to manage it for example:

```
new Date(2018,11,90) // Thu Feb 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

As you can see the above we are passing 90 days in! But of course it allows us to do that without any error...

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I read this post immediately after writing [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57515/755) about "time-traveling" airline flight schedules (where aircraft land earlier in the local time of their arrival city than they departed in the local time of their departure city.)

For those of you who want to time travel, the short version is this:

If you want to travel a few minutes back in time, then either buy a short West-bound flight that crosses a time zone boundary. If you want to travel hours back in time, purchase an East-bound flight that crosses the International Date Line, such as a flight from East Asia, Australia, or New Zealand to North America or Hawaii.

Answer (score 0):

How can you have any discussion about time without

```
Chronos! Master of all time! [lightning sound]
```

[image]

Full episode here: https://dai.ly/x3d7oj1

Answer (score 0):

**T**ick tick, the seconds of a clock

**I**nternally circadian

**M**oving forward

**E**ndless

Comment: Was that supposed to be a haiku? :D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Look Joel… we can’t go back to September 15, 2008 – just because that’s the lask time you’ve seen your watch.]

Answer (score 0):

There is a need for a new unit of time. I propose that this unit of time be named an **overflow**.

Definition: The interval between thinking "I can't figure out what's wrong with this PostgreSQL command. Let's check StackOverflow" and "Huh. So that's how you can perform matrix math from a Windows Command prompt."

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's about time for me to tell this story. Here I go:

The time has come, it's finally time, to kill that dumb old man.
The one whose seen it all, but surely never makes a plan.
That wizened father, Father Time, he always limits me,
I'm late to everything, and it is all his fault you see.

I don my sword, sharp enough to stop time,
Oh by my word, he'll pay for his crime.
I'll run it through him, and then when I'm done,
I'll cut his beard off, and that's just for fun.

I head over to the mountain, where 'tis known that he is found,
But first I swim the Endless Lake, and make it safe and sound.
I check my watch, it seems a mere one hundred years have passed,
Now I'm at the foot of the Eternal Mountain at long last.

I scale the sheerest cliff I've seen in my entire life,
I think that I'll be late for dinner, will someone tell my wife?
The stones are worn, the jags eroded, as I climb the side,
And I am old, with sword I'm loaded, unebbing as the tide.

I ring the bell, a secretary answers at the door.
I take a quick glance at my watch, it's only five past four.
"I'm here at last!", I bravely cry, "to kill that stupid oaf.
If he's at dinner tell him he's enjoying his last loaf."

"You're late.", she says, "He leaves at four, and now he's gone on break.
I hope to time, that there was not, too much for you at stake."
"Confound the man!", I'm crying tears, I'm foiled yet once more.
"I can't begin to tell you all the things I had in store."

"You poor old man.", she says to me, "you can't kill Father Time."
"But wait!", I say, "Epiphany, I cert'nly can kill time!
To prove it to you I will write a silly little rhyme!"

So here I am, I wrote a poem, just to relay my tale,
I think you'll find, my story's only, just beyond the pale.
I failed at killing Father Time, but I have murdered time,
I hope that you've enjoyed reading my neverending rhyme.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a riddle:

***I can be Sand, I can also be the Sun, I can be a Bird also...what am I?***

Answer:

> Variants of Watch (For time measurement)

Details:

> **1. Sand - Sand Watch** 
>  [image: SandWatch.gif] 
>  **2. Sun - Sun Dial** 
>  [image: Sundial.gif] 
>  **3. Bird - Cuckoo Clock** 
>  [image: cuckooclock.gif]

Answer (score 0):

### Ok guys, enough is enough! I am going to start this and it will only stop after I win the prize!

[image]

Comment: Flagged for terroristic threats! ( j/k <3 )

Answer (score -1):

## A meta-haiku on a meta-site.

```
This is a haiku.
Its sha one never changes,
Every time, the same.
```

Comment: I was reading this counting the syllables. It is a haiku indeed. 5-7-5. You got a down vote but I think this is a valid entry for it is a poem about time. Maybe the downvoter just didn't know about haiku? Here, have my upvote

Comment: I'm not sure it can qualify as a haiku - where is the reference to season, etc

Answer (score -1):

remember that one time that someone posted a very subjective and primarily opinion based answer to a question that already had a ton of good ones, yet he somehow still got up-voted anyway?

Good times. I liked that guy, he was pretty cool.

Comment: No, I don't seem to remember that.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a lot of people trying to build their machines of time, I always thought it was just to close my eyes.

And "close your eyes" is not close your eyes.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Yeah! you guessed it right, I am a (lazy) web developer :P

Answer (score -2):

Misquoting Martin Luther King Jr,

"Now is the *time*, I was declared the winner".

Answer (score -12):

[image]