# One watch, two watches, three watches.. If I get three will someone get none?

Tags: support, swag, contest

"Two time's a charm"... but "two watches's an error".

Apparently DHL has just started getting ready for shipment of the watches from the [December swag contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag). Some users already got a mail from them...

... but some got TWO.

It doesn't appear to be just a dupe message - the two mails do indeed have different item numbers and waybill codes. This seems to indicate that there was an error at some point and some users are being sent two watches instead of one.

I will be honest: I don't really dislike the idea of a second watch. There are so many uses for it: give it to a friend, keep it under a glass dome as a collector item, wear a watch on both <strike>hooves</strike> arms... But a part of me is fearing that due to the same error someone may receive zero watches instead.

I also realize that probably by now it could be anti-economical to try to fix the error, but I think something will have to be done in the case some users are left without their prize.

I am therefore posting this message to warn the staff. I have considered using the contact mail too, but I am somehow assuming this may be the fastest option right now.

---

**Recap:**

- some users are apparently being sent two watches
- if this doesn't create any problem, I doubt any of them will take the second free watch as a personal offense
- you may have to do something if some winners are left without a watch.

---

**EDIT** - *Just received a third mail, different waybill code as usual.*

Comment: It seems that it's because of your amazing location in profile ...

Comment: Somebody could start a stuff give-away...

Comment: Lookin' into it...

Comment: I also got two confirmations.  I figured there were some wires crossed somewhere, but it never occurred to me that someone might be going without that shouldn't be.

Comment: The same happened to me. Two confirmations. Plus, according to DHL the package should arrive at 10PM today while I am living in Germany. Furthermore, the DHL page states that the shipment has not even been picked up by DHL yet. Hurry up guys! It's 6 hours left to get from Massachusets to Berlin! :D

Comment: One watch, two watches, ..., 32767 watches, -32768 watches, -32767 watches, ..., -2 watches, -1 watch, no watch

Comment: @fameman Same here, except I didn't get a second message. Still status not picked up by DHL.

Comment: Mail number three just arrived, again a different waybill code.

Comment: And same here. Three mails, three different waybill codes, all in "Shipment not yet picked up by DHL" status.

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ user: "What time is it?" [watch bursts into flames]

Comment: Hmmm... estimated delivery... seems like DHL itself could need some Timex watches as well. ^^

Comment: I just got my watch but I didn't get any message about it shipping. How were you told, did you get a moderator message telling you you should "watch yourself"? Also, if the messages got mixed up and anyone has my address, you need to know that I have a giant S and I'm ready to defend myself.

Comment: @Laurel I also just got my watch yesterday out of the blue with no shipping message. Are you in the US? Apparently [that's expected behavior out here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7574737#7574737).

Comment: @scohe001 Yep, I'm in the US.

Comment: I signed up for shipping notifications and received one 1 hour ago. Now I just need to handle the customs duty for the E.U.

Comment: @Laurel We normally use FedEx within the US, which does not send automated notifications to the recipient by default. We use DHL for international packages, which does send those notifications if they have contact information available.

Comment: I just woke up to an SMS notification, saying that the package with the third waybill number I was sent will arrive Friday. Nothing on the other two yet.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell *Watch* out, you might be running out of *time* to recieve the package :D

Comment: Should we update @jnat with a "I got mine okay" somehow, and somewhere ?

Comment: @Criggie The closest thing you could probably do is adding a reply with a photo of the watch [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324603/time-for-a-thank-you). My only advice should you decide to is to be very aware of the "humbug factor" - that post has already attracted some downvotes and  has been closed / reopened in the past: I'm not sure your answer would live a different destiny.

Comment: I have received a single mail from JNat on Jan 31 about form filling till now :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I checked with our vendor, and they weren't able to figure out why the multiple messages were sent by DHL... They did assure me, however, that **only one watch per-user was sent, and that all users in the list should be getting their watches.**

They also mentioned that DHL is rather verbose in terms of notifications, so you can prolly expect more emails from 'em any time there's a status update on your package — which *can* be useful, in particular if it's held up in customs, or something like that... **Oh! if DHL/Customs reach out to you about any payments, our vendor said you can tell Customs that "all duties & taxes are being billed back to Stack's DHL account."**

Comment: I also received three shipment notifications in February, but all of them still have status "Shipment not yet picked up by DHL". Is there something wrong or do I just have to be patient and wait for a second batch of watches to ship? Sorry to bug you about this & thanks a lot.

Comment: There isn't going to be any second batch of watches shipping, @hbaderts; can you reach out to me via email with your details and more info?

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: JNat just replied and posted some feedback about the "incident". I will still leave this reply for historical reference but please refer to his reply instead for more up-to-date information.**

---

<strike>Some days later, I haven't received any update on the problem, neither from Stack Exchange nor from DHL.</strike>

That said, just yesterday the tracking status for the last message I received was updated, and it appears now that the package is in transit. The first two messages instead still report a status of "not yet picked up".

Because of this, I would say it is safe to assume that the first messages can safely be ignored for now. While the original cause of the problem hasn't been disclosed, so far there is no evidence that would suggest multiple watches are being sent to the same person.

Obviously, I will update this post if I gain any new insight into the incident.

Comment: I know "me too" comments are frowned upon - but likewise - I have the initial 2 tracking numbers still and there's no change in status. The third, I got my watch ;)