# Time for a "thank you"!

Tags: discussion, time, swag, thanks

Thank you, Stack Exchange and JNat for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag) that arrived in the mail today just in *time* for my trip tomorrow!

[image]

Despite *watching* [all the spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322152/more-than-15k-bottles-of-viagra-from-kenya-asking-110-people-for-money-seriou) from Stack Exchange users and [also from DHL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324473/one-watch-two-watches-three-watches-if-i-get-three-will-someone-get-none), this is a wonderful gift, and I want to take the *time* to say, "Thank you".

Comment: I see what you did with your keyboard there ;P

Comment: ... this is closed, [this one is open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321019/thank-you-for-my-cheese-overflow-board). Weird. Voting to reopen this too.

Comment: Thanks [go here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist people didn't get this one. Voted to reopen too.

Comment: @Rob I think that swag contests are rare enough that we can tolerate a single post even now and then that for once express gratefulness towards the staff, but fell free to vote for closing again if this gets reopened.

Comment: Wow! I like it tooooo!

Comment: @SPArchaeologist That's the advantage of a written record, it can be reread as many times as necessary. I won't be voting to close. I didn't have a reason to vote that the other five people were incorrect.

Comment: Received mine as well today, looks good https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxatp.jpg

Comment: These watches are made to be branded, so I have been dying to see what it would look like. (They come in different colours, and I couldn't see the MSE logo fitting with the orange. It seems they have gone for the SO logo instead, which matches with the colour scheme)

Answer (score 3):

I also got mine yesterday. Here is a GIF:

[image: SO watch]

This watch is amazing because it can:

- Tell you time
- Tell you time in darkness
- Tell you time without noise
- Tell you time in water

Comment: Sorry about the hour-hand in the dark night glow picture. It took me some time to manage to get a good shot but I didn't noticed that the hour-hand got behind the minute-hand.

Answer (score 2):

### Hooray! Now I can tell the time!

The watch I normally wear had to be sent away to be repaired but this one arrived right on time (*groan, sorry*) to be my second (*groan*) watch! I just wanted to take a minute (*groan*) to say thanks as this is a seriously cool bit of swag and a genuinely useful item!

It must have taken hours (*groan*) to organise the contest and the swag so thanks to JNat and everyone else involved :)

<sub>A bit of a coincidence that I took this picture while the hour hand was between 6 - 8!</sub>

[image]