# Multiple watch invoices

Tags: support, swag, contest

Continuing on from the [great multiple watch shipment saga](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324473/one-watch-two-watches-three-watches-if-i-get-three-will-someone-get-none) I also received 3 separate waybill numbers however additionally I was sent 2 SMS messages each wanting me to pay £17 import duty. Each SMS lists one of the waybill numbers I've been emailed.

I have just received my watch and the waybill number it has is the third one, i.e the one that has no invoice associated with it.

What should I do about the two £17 invoices? Seaching for them on DHL's system indicates they do exist and are against my name.

Comment: The answer to [One watch, two watches, three watches.. If I get three will someone get none?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324473/one-watch-two-watches-three-watches-if-i-get-three-will-someone-get-none) says that "if DHL/Customs reach out to you about any payments, our vendor said you can tell Customs that 'all duties & taxes are being billed back to Stack's DHL account.'".

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog not a duplicate. This question is about invoices, does the OP have to pay for the other two or not?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I edited my comment to indicate where this is answered there.

Comment: This is about whether this specific issue has happened to anyone else. Clearly I can contact DHL but if everyone is being billed actual money with their no-watch waybills then perhaps Stack Exchange should contact DHL themselves and sort the billing situation out.

Comment: If you only received one watch, why would you pay for more than one? I don't see this as being different than being given an invoice for something you never got at all—and not paying for it. (On the other hand, if you *did* receive more than one watch, I would expect you would pay for each of them if so billed.)

Comment: I received one watch but was billed for two other watches I did not receive. I don't want some invalid debt chasing me years later though.