# Am I trusted or not?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, protected-questions, association-bonus

A few minutes ago I registered on Meta. I received 100 rep points because you trust me on other sites.

> *You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network*

I just wanted to answer a question which is protected by the Community. But for me it's not allowed because I do not have more than 10 rep.

[image]

So does Stack Exchange trust me or not?

Comment: I don't know if I trust you, but I just unprotected said post again ;-)

Comment: Note that, literally speaking, the wording of the bonus message is *we trust you* ***on other sites***. It doesn't actually indicate that you are trusted on the particular site in question. Just that you've received a bonus.

Comment: Considering the specific case here, I might suggest reframing this question to ask how to get the protection removed in special cases like this contest. Something like "I'd like to participate in this event but the question is protected, what should I do?"

Comment: The association bonus does not count for answering protected questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, we trust you.

This is a technical issue which others [already asked to change/fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318026/make-unprotection-disqualify-questions-from-further-auto-protection).

For future readers: better ways to ask for unprotecting a question (when justified) are:

- Comment on the question and ping a moderator or 15k rep user if such is present. Note that here on Meta, 5 rep is enough to comment anywhere.
- Flag the question with custom message, asking to unprotect. For this you'll need 15 rep.
- Ask to unprotect in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), where many high rep users are active. This requires 20 rep.

Those with association bonus can do any of the above.