# Remove UI restriction against unprotecting questions less than 24 hours old

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, protected-questions

It's [that time of the year again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine); no, I don't mean April Fools, I mean a question with a lot of posts by users who are new to Meta. These posts are explicitly open to new users. Like the contests last winter, these questions cause [protect/unprotect wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/321399/revisions?page=6) between Community ♦ and other users. One primary driver of these wars is that the relevant checks occur [whenever any new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323334/why-did-community-auto-protect-this-question-when-an-answer-from-a-high-rep-user) posts or deletes an answer: for instance, in the revision history linked earlier, it was getting protected every time *any* answer from a new user was being posted, since the check for five answers from new users posted in the last 24 hours was being run every time a new user posted an answer, and since the check was passing every time, it would be protected.

I'd like to help here as well; I have the [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) to protect and unprotect questions, but the buttons for doing so only show up 24 hours after the question has been posted. The former part makes some sense; we don't want users to preemptively protect questions where that isn't necessary. However, the latter part doesn't really make much sense.

I suggest that the *unprotecting* button is also available within in the first 24 hours (possibly only if Community ♦ auto-protected the question, but cases where an elected/appointed ♦ moderator protects a question within 24 hours are rare<sup>[citation needed]</sup> so feel free to choose the option which is easiest to implement).

---

This feature request is taking an interesting turn of events. As can be seen in [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/326036/revisions), the question is now only 21 hours old and I'm able to run [a script](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7636812#7636812) to unprotect the question. It works by issuing a POST call to `/questions/unprotect` (once every minute), which means in the 24 hour period after posting the question, *only the link in the UI is disabled*; the one-day-old check isn't carried out server-side. I don't think it's particularly open to abuse, but still...

Comment: I've seen mods on SU [immediately protect](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8363/why-was-this-question-immediately-protected-without-any-previous-activity) questions about topics that tend to be used by spammers as spam seeds.

Comment: OT: I think you can build a Java program and run it on a server 24/7 so you don't have to keep your browser open.

Comment: @MetaBugWizard I've considered that, but even logging in (without logging myself out on other browsers) is hard. The script already runs in a browser on a server which is 24/7 online, which is fine for this purpose.

Comment: You run a *browser* (with JS support) on a server? Sounds refreshing.

Comment: More convenient than a [server in a browser](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualization-browser.html) ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the backend allow protecting questions less than 24 hours old (provided they have an answer from a new user)?

Comment: Not sure, and I don't have an example ready where I can test this ... the answer below came a few hours too late for this.

Comment: @Sonic it didn't work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55471756/4751173).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been implemented at some point.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338806/what-new-things-can-be-done-to-increase-participation-in-mse) was asked just one hour ago, and was just protected by Community due to spam answers from new users. The "unprotect" button now *does* seem to show for me:

> [image: Unprotect button showing up on question asked 1 hour ago]

I tried clicking the button to unprotect it, and it indeed went through and it was unprotected. (Which makes sense, since the check was never enforced server-side, only client-side due to the lack of the button.)