# Disable auto-protection for meta questions

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta, protected-questions

I just saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326108/316226) and one line jumped out at me:

> I mean a question with a lot of posts by users who are new to Meta. These posts are explicitly open to new users.

A [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318026/316226) was made last year to have unprotecting a question disable it from further auto-protection to avoid the protect/unprotect wars that happen between Community ♦ and other users. There was a [proposed change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319106/316226) to the feature request to disable auto-protection entirely on questions with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)tag. JNat [responded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318026/make-unprotection-disqualify-questions-from-further-auto-protection#comment1045955_319106) to some comments on that post pointing out that changing the feature might be good, but optimizing for edge cases isn't.

> The sandbox and the contest are not the intended uses for our format, @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog — not discarding that changing the behavior of the feature might be a good idea, it certainly isn't one to optimize it for two edge cases. – JNat♦ Nov 29 '18 at 16:32

If meta posts are supposed to explicitly be open to new users, I propose that we disable auto-protection from all questions on MSE and the per-site metas.

Answer (score 4):

> If meta posts are supposed to explicitly be open to new users

They're not; only a few of them are, most notably announcements and contests (often recongizable by the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag). Otherwise, having users posting non-answers is just as much as a problem here as it is on other sites, so the auto-protection feature works as designed. Actually, many of these 'open to everybody' posts have seen an increased number of very low quality / not an answers in the past two months. Luckily, we have enough regulars here to keep the Low Quality Posts review queue in check.