# How can I access the Formatting Sandbox if I have less than 10 reputation here?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, meta

According to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions), I can use [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) to test compositions of messages.  However, it requires 10 reputation points.  I got 100 points automatically, but it doesn't seem to help.  I'm assuming that the problem is due to reputation points, but am not sure.  What I observe is that there is no field to enter an answer, even after the last posted answer.

How else can I test message composition?  Is my lack of access to the formatting sandbox above due to reputation points?

My intent was to test messages with LaTeX equations.  The notation is not universally recognized across all Stack Exchanges.

I also noticed that some test messages in the formatting sandbox were downvoted.  Wondering if there is any protection for the posters, as the thread is meant for test messages.

Comment: You can't use the Sandbox on this site for MathJax because it's not supported here, you need to use a [different site where it is supported](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=MathJax+sandbox), ***but*** you can also use a site's question or answer editor where MathJax will work exactly as it's to be displayed - or you can file a bug if it's not the same.

Comment: Thanks!  I learned a lot researching as a follow-up to your comment. [This page of SEs supporting MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) is helpful. Also realizing that this site here is a meta-site across all SEs, but that each SE also has a meta site, e.g,. *NameOfSE*.meta.stackexchange.com. Some of the more specific meta-sites have their own sandboxes.

Comment: user2153235, you are welcome. There is [**much more** than MathJax available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844/282094), some sites also have [custom fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307865/282094).

Comment: Again, thanks.  I think for the moment, I'll try to focus on one new thing at a time, since I had a research aim when I started.  But that reference will undoubtedly come in handy when the need arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox is supposed to be open to all users.

Occasionally, it may end up getting protected because it meets the automatic protection criteria outlined in our [FAQ on protection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/377214). These are designed to stem answers from new users in case there are too many of them at a given time or that get deleted, to reduce moderation workload on popular questions asked on the main site. However, they are not ideal for meta sandboxes like these, which are supposed to be open to all users but end up triggering the check simply due to their nature.

Also, as the FAQ page there says, the association bonus doesn't count towards the required reputation, as it checks for participation *on the site itself* rather than just on the network in general.

I've gone ahead and unprotected the question, so you can participate in it. There exists [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318026/make-unprotection-disqualify-questions-from-further-auto-protection) to prevent automatic protection if the question is later unprotected.

If anyone else runs into this issue in the future, and you have the association bonus reputation, please flag the question requesting unprotection instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I've never actually kept track of whether the bonus points are specific to a given SE, and I still need to do more searching to figure this out.  But I now understand that they don't contribute toward the 10 points needed to respond to protected questions.